# Por que criar um objeto usando a superclasse?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Dado o seguinte código:

```
public class Musico {

    public void tocaInstrumento() {
        // faz algo
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Baterista extends Musico {

    public void giraBaqueta() {
        // faz algo
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Violonista extends Musico {

    public void trocaCordas() {
    }
}
```

Eu posso me valer do polimorfismo para fazer o seguinte:

```
    Musico musico1 = new Violonista();
    Musico musico2 = new Baterista();

    musico1 = musico2;
```

Porém, eu não consigo enxergar os métodos da subclasse:

```
    musico1.trocaCordas(); //ERRO DE COMPILAÇÃO!
```

Se eu utilizar:

```
Violonista musico1 = new Violonista();
```

Não seria melhor? Qual a vantagem em utilizar tipo Musico para referenciar um objeto de uma subclasse? Seria simplesmente a possibilidade de eu conseguir atribuir `musico1 = musico2;`, por exemplo? Ou há outras vantagens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu exemplo não se trata exatamente de "criar" um objeto usando a superclasse, e sim de criar um objeto usando uma subclasse e manipulá-lo por meio da superclasse.

Para explicar de uma forma mais simples, vou partir do seguinte código:

```java
Musico musico1 = new Violonista();
Musico musico2 = new Baterista();
```

O que você fez ali foi basicamente declarar duas variáveis *do tipo* `Musico` (as variáveis `musico1` e `musico2`) e inicializá-las com conteúdo que são *instâncias de classes filhas* (herdadas) de `Musico` (respectivamente instâncias de `Violonista` e `Baterista`). Isso é justamente o caráter do *polimorfismo* (etimologia: poli [muitos] + morfos [forma] = [qualidade ou estado do que pode assumir diferentes formas](http://houaiss.uol.com.br/busca?palavra=polimorfismo))

Também como já responderam apropriadamente, o polimorfismo é o que permite você adicionar instâncias de diferentes objetos em uma mesma lista (`ArrayList<Musico>`, por exemplo), uma vez que essa característica da orientação a objetos permite manipular os objetos de forma "abstrata" (isto é, sem conhecer detalhes específicos da implementação ou de qual instância realmente se encontra guardada na variável).

O erro de compilação decorre do fato de que o compilador não tem como saber qual classe você instanciou, pois o tipo da variável é `Músico`. Você pode, entretanto, tentar fazer um [type casting](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/java/typecast-instanceof.php):

```java
((Violonista) musico1).trocaCordas();
```

Basicamente você está dizendo ao compilador para tratar o conteúdo variável `musico1` como uma instância da classe `Violonista`. Se esse conteúdo *realmente* for uma instância dessa classe, tudo funcionará como esperado, mas se não for você terá um erro em tempo de execução. Pra garantir que não está fazendo bobagens, você pode verificar se a a instância é, de fato, herdada daquela classe:

```java
if(musico1 instanceof Violonista)
    ((Violonista) musico1).trocaCordas();
```

Eu sei que provavelmente estou chovendo no molhado com todas essas explicações (porque você já teve respostas realmente muito boas), mas eu queria finalmente oferecer um exemplo em que há uma real vantagem em se utilizar esse tipo de manipulação por meio da classe pai/abstrata.

Considere, por exemplo, que você é o criador/desenvolvedor do Sistema Operacional Windows. É claro que você deseja que outros desenvolvedores criem aplicações para o seu SO. Imagine que eu sou o desenvolvedor do MS Word. De minha parte, eu desejo que o meu software seja capaz de imprimir texto na impressora do cliente. Mas, o problema é que o cliente pode ter diferentes tipos de impressoras, e novos tipos podem ser criados após o lançamento do meu software. Como proceder?

Suponha que você, desenvolvedor do SO, disponha de uma interface para impressoras, em que basicamente você criou e publicou uma classe abstrata (ou seja, um tipo) chamda `Impressora`. Tal classe tem apenas um método:

```java
public abstract class Impressora {
    public void imprimir(String sTexto);
}
```

O "abstract" está ali apenas para dizer que essa classe não serve para ser instanciada, apenas para ser herdada. Enfim, agora suponha que o fabricante da impressora XPTO, sabendo da interface publicamente disponível feita por você, crie seu próprio driver de impressão, em que ele herda a sua class `Impressora`, por exemplo, da seguinte forma:

```java
import IMPRESSORA.DO.SISTEMA.OPERACIONAL;

public class ImpressoraXPTO extends Impressora {
    public void imprimir(String sTexto) {
        . . .
        // Faz a impressão específica da impressora XPTO
        . . .
    }
}
```

Dai, eu, desenvolvedor do MS Word, preciso solicitar a impressão dos textos criados no meu software. Igualmente, sabendo que existe algo publicamente disponível criado por você eu simplesmente reutilizo o que o SO já prove, por exemplo de uma forma similar a isso:

```java
import IMPRESSORA.DO.SISTEMA.OPERACIONAL;

public class MSWord {

    public void imprimirArquivo(String sTexto)
    {
        // Suponha que exista uma função do sistema operacional que
        // devolva a instância da impressora padrão 
        // (sem importar se é uma XPTO, uma HP, uma Epson, uma George Foreman, etc).
        Impressora oImpressora = SO.getImpressoraPadrao();

        // Como todas têm o método `imprimir` (por herdar de `Impressora`), eu posso 
        // chamá-lo sem me preocupar com os detalhes de como cada impressora
        // realmente trabalha!
        oImpressora.imprimir(sTexto);
    }
}
```

Nesse simples exemplo dá pra ter uma ideia da vantagem de se trabalhar com a abstração e o polimorfismo. Primeiramente, você pode desacoplar o uso da implementação; isto é, quem utiliza o seu código pode "trabalhar na abstração", significando que pode utilizar os métodos e propriedades básicas que todas as heranças terão. Em segundo lugar, facilita a extensão, pois é muito fácil e prático adicionar novas classes específicas (no exemplo, novas impressoras - contanto que herdem da interface padrão `Impressora` - serão garantidamente utilizávels no meu MS Word no seu sistema operacional sem que esse software precise ser alterado).

No caso do seu exemplo, a sua classe pai/abstrata é `Musico` e as classes de real interesse são as que herdam dela: `Violonista` e `Baterista`. A herança faz muito sentido quando as classes compartilham algo, sejam atributos (variáveis) ou comportamentos (métodos). No seu exemplo, a única coisa que um violonista e um baterista compartilham é o comportamento de "tocar instrumento" (por meio do método `tocaInstrumento` herdado).

Idealmente esse método precisa ser reimplementado nas classes filhas para que cada tipo de músico toque de forma apropriada (o violonista troca [vc não quis dizer "toca"?] as cordas, e o baterista gira a baqueta). Quando alguma outra parte do seu código manipular os "músicos" (isso mesmo, de forma abstrata), irá "solicitar" a eles que toquem o instrumento (isto é, invocarão o método tocaInstrumento), mas cada tipo de músico (cada objeto) irá fazê-lo de forma específica, conforme sua própria implementação. O fato é que quem manipula os "musicos" (alguém citou um palco em exemplos, mas poderia ser o simulador de orquestra) não precisa saber exatamente o que cada um faz.

Comment: Como citado em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5337/4156 eu já conhecia as vantagens da herança e polimorfismo, a dúvida era realmente específica no que diz respeito em o porquê de utilizar a superclasse (no seu exemplo, uma interface) ao invés de usar direto a subclasse. Sua resposta é quase um artigo! Parabéns!

Comment: Porém, me faz surgir outra dúvida. Faz todo sentido utilizar, como no seu exemplo, `Impressora oImpressora = SO.getImpressoraPadrao()`, pois você não sabe qual impressora específica o método retornará, pode vir qualquer uma, mas eu sei que sempre será subclasse de `Impressora`. Porém, haveria razão para alguém deliberadamente escrever um código `Impressora oImpressora = new ImpressoraXPTO()` ?

Comment: Sim, há. No exemplo da impressora o próprio sistema operacional faria isso quando o usuário selecionasse XPTO como impressora padrão. No final das contas, *alguém tem que instanciar* o objeto específico. Aliás, facilitar esse processo é um dos principais motivadores de padrões de projeto como Abstract Factor (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Factory) e Factory Method (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method).

Comment: Agora, se você tem apenas um uso local de uma classe específica (mas que herda de outra para "ganhar" atributos e métodos já existentes), faz mais sentido mesmo você manipular a instância em sua própria classe. Quero dizer, ai a abstração e o polimorfismo não têm tanta relevância como a herança em si.

Comment: Excelente explicação, @LuizVieira, +1 =)

Comment: Encontrei esse link que pode ser útil para um melhor entendimento: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n

Answer (score 5):

Acho que entendi sua pergunta, você quer uma razão para instanciar

```
Musico musico1 = new Violonista();
```

ao invés de

```
Violonista musico1 = new Violonista();
```

Qualquer método que aceitar um `Musico` vai aceitar seu objeto `Violonista`, tanto nos parâmetros como no retorno, e inclusive você pode sim adicionar seu `Violonista` a uma lista de `Musico` Acho que vemos mais esta construção por razões didáticas.

Acredito que você já sabia das características e  vantagens da herança e do polimorfismo, e que basicamente a única dúvida era usar o `Musico`ou o `Violonista` ao declarar sua variável. Estou correto?

Se for isso, não vejo razão para utilizar a primeira opção. Por favor me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

(Agora, criar um campo numa classe como `Musico` ao invés de `Violonista`  faria muita diferença)

Comment: Acho que você tem razão. A pergunta era sobre que caso seria necessário instanciar dessa forma e de fato não há vantagem. O cast pode ser feito a qualquer momento e um método que recebe Musico como parâmetro vai aceitar qualquer filho.

Answer (score 3):

As vantagens de usar abstração são as mesmas do [polimorfismo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo), que do meu ponto de vista a principal consiste na criação de rotinas genéricas que não precisam saber dos tipos específicos. Isso permite a você criar novas variações dos tipos de dados sem alterar os algoritmos existentes.

Talvez você esteja com dificuldades porque você está pensando nos detalhes das classes e não numa rotina que pode abstrair os conceitos.

Imagine que uma `CasaDeShow` vai receber uma banda composta por vários músicos. Essa casa somente precisa pedir para eles tocarem os instrumentos, ela não quer saber os detalhes de cada um deles. Aqui o uso da abstração cai perfeitamente.

Por outro lado, se tivéssemos uma oficina de conserto de instrumentos, aí sim deveria haver uma seção específica para cada tipo de músico e instrumento, com tratamento individual para as particularidades de cada um. Isso lembra bastante a sobrecarga de métodos.

Enfim, a maioria dos conceitos relacionados a Orientação à Objetos possui alguma relação com a realidade, mas às vezes temos de nos esforçar para pensar de forma abstrata.

Comment: entendi a questão de poder criar rotinas genéricas que não precisem saber dos tipos específicos. Mas eu poderia perfeitamente passar um argumento do tipo Baterista para um método que só recebe tipo Musico, pois Baterista **é** um Musico.

Comment: @dellasavia Isso mesmo. A questão não é que você *sempre* deve trabalhar com tipos abstratos, pois também não vejo vantagem nisso. Mas quanto mais você conseguir trabalhar com as abstrações, menos código repetido você vai ter.

Answer (score 3):

Calma, vamos por partes.

### Por que dá erro de compilação?

Em primeiro lugar, você não consegue acessar `trocaCordas`, porque o musico1 passa a ser um baterista quando você coloca `musico1 = musico2`.

### Quais as vantagens da herança?

Segundo, existem muitas vantagens em se utilizar uma superclasse. A primeira é que **todas** as classes filhas vão herdar os métodos `public` e `protected` do pai. No caso de exemplo que você utilizou, tanto `Baterista`, quanto `Violinista` possuem o método `tocaInstrumento`. Isso significa que, quando você quiser editar o método `tocaInstrumento`, você **NÃO** precisa editar ele várias vezes, mas apenas uma, de forma que o `Violinista` e o `Baterista` receberão as alterações. Essa e outras propriedades podem ser vistas nessa [aula sobre heranças](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/heranca-reescrita-e-polimorfismo/#7-1-repetindo-codigo).

### Qual a vantagem de utilizar a classe pai para definir objetos?

Essa pergunta parte mais de quando você precisa de algo genérico, vamos imaginar que você queira salvar uma banda. Sabemos que a banda não é composta só por bateristas ou violinistas, mas sim por músicos, então nós teríamos que minha banda é uma lista de `Musico`.

```
ArrayList<Musico> banda = new ArrayList<Musico>();
```

e dentro dessa lista eu terei cada tipo de músico:

```
banda.add(new Violinista());
banda.add(new Baterista());
```

a vantagem disso é que, quando eu precisar realizar uma ação de `Musico` eu posso iterar somente em um `for`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < banda.size(); i++){
  banda.get(i).tocaInstrumento();
}
```

ou

```
for(Musico musico: banda){
  musico.tocaInstrumento();
}
```

Isso foi só uma introdução das vantagens de uma característica básica de Orientação a Objetos, mais informações podem ser encontradas [aqui](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/orientacao-a-objetos-basica/).

Comment: eu entendi, mas veja: Se eu criar o objeto Violonista musico1 = new Violonista(); eu também vou conseguir inserir musico1 numa lista que só aceite objetivos do tipo Musico, pois musico1 **é** um Violonista e Violonista **é** um Musico. Ainda não vejo vantagem alguma de usar o supertipo para se criar a referência.

Comment: Sim, mas se você criar um `ArrayList<Violinista>`, na sua lista banda, só terão violinistas, enquanto um `ArrayList<Musico>` permite **qualquer** tipo de músico. Isso é usado quando você **não sabe** qual será o filho que será referenciado. Um exemplo é o `ArrayList`, outro exemplo poderia ser, por exemplo, se um usuário for escolher que tipo de músico ele é, você não saberá, diante mão, o que ele escolherá, logo você não poderá referenciar um tipo de músico específico. Ficou mais claro o que eu quero dizer?

Answer (score 2):

Há outras vantagens. A diferença é implícita e, se você olhar bem, é quase óbvia: Um `Musico` pode ser um `Baterista` ou um `Violonista`, mas um `Baterista` não pode ser um `Violonista` e vice versa.

Porque isso seria útil? Quando você não precisa de um `Baterista` ou `Violinista` em específico, você precisa de qualquer `Musico`.

Vamos supor isso com um exemplo: uma Banda. Como poderíamos expressar isso? Bem, pode ser como uma classe:

```
class Banda {
  private Vocalista vocalista;
  private Guitarrista guitarrista;
  private Baterista baterista;
  private Violonista violonista;

  // encapsulamento, construtores e afins...
}
```

Ok, isso funciona. Mas temos um problema: E se a banda tem dois guitarristas? Ou se ela não tem um violonista?

Podemos resolver isso assim:

```
class Banda {
  private Vector<Musico> musicos;

  // encapsulamento, construtores e afins

  public void tocarMusica() {
    for (Musico musico : musicos) musico.tocaInstrumento();
  }
}
```

Desse modo, não importa se uma banda tem mais ou menos músicos de cada tipo, pois ela aceita qualquer número de músicos, e todos podem tocar seu instrumento.

Comment: mesmo que eu crie o objeto Violonista musico1 = new Violonista(); eu conseguirei perfeitamente inserí-lo nesse vetor. Então, qual a vantagem de usar o supertipo para se criar a referência?

Comment: Olha no `for`. Você está criando uma lista de `Musico`s, e não de `Violonista`s. Essa é a vantagem: Poder ser tanto um como outro.

Comment: eu entendi, mas a minha dúvida é na forma de criação do objeto e não no acesso a ele. Tanto faz eu criar `Musico musico1 = new Violonista()` ou `Violonista musico1 = new Violonista()`. Em ambas as formas, eu conseguirei mandar `musico1` para um `for` que só aceite Musico.

Comment: Sim. A única diferença é no acesso. Não vejo uma vantagem na criação.

Answer (score 2):

Sim há outras vantagens para utilizar polimorfismo em seu código. Ou, nas suas palavras, referenciar objetos por sua superclasse.

Duas, por exemplo:

### Substituir `if`s por polimorfismo

Vamos supor que, no seu exemplo de músicos, você queira criar uma página Web para exibir os detalhes de cada um deles. Caso o músico seja um baterista, você deseja exibir uma imagem (avatar) de uma bateria. Caso seja um guitarrista, uma guitarra; violinista, violino, e assim sucessivamente.

Então, em uma primeira versão, você escreve:

```
public void exibirAvatar(PaginaWeb pagina, Musico musico) {
  String imagem;
  if (musico instanceof Baterista) {
    imagem = "/img/bateria.jpg";
  } else if (musico instanceof Guitarrista) {
    imagem = "/img/guitarra.jpg";
  } else if (musico instanceof Violinista) {
    imagem = "/img/violino.jpg";
  } else {
    imagem = "/img/imagem-padrao.jpg";
  }
  pagina.exibirAvatar(imagem);
}
```

Acho que todos já escrevemos algum tipo de código parecido com este.

O problema é que, por vezes, esquecemos que código não é estático, isto é, esquecemos que:

1. Código vai precisar de manutenção;
2. Você poderá ter que fazer a manutenção do seu próprio código;
3. Outra pessoa poderá ter que fazer a manutenção do código que você escreveu; e
4. Você poderá ter que fazer a manutenção de um código escrito por outra pessoa.

De maneira mais prática: e se mais para frente, for necessário adicionar Baixistas, vocalistas, saxofonistas, etc? Neste caso, inclusive, seria melhor ter pensado em outra modelagem para as classes, mas isto não vem ao caso agora.

Aí, em uma segunda versão, você altera seu código inicial. Mas, na pressa, e utilizando CTRL-C, CTRL-V (uso todos os dias, que fique claro):

```
public void exibirAvatar(PaginaWeb pagina, Musico musico) {
  String imagem;
  if (musico instanceof Baterista) {
    imagem = "/img/bateria.jpg";
  } else if (musico instanceof Guitarrista) {
    imagem = "/img/guitarra.jpg";
  } else if (musico instanceof Violinista) {
    imagem = "/img/violino.jpg";
  } else if (musico instanceof Baixista) {
    imagem = "/img/guitarra.jpg";
  } else if (musico instanceof Saxofonista) {
    imagem = "/img/saxofone.jpg";
  } else {
    imagem = "/img/imagem-padrao.jpg";
  }
  pagina.exibirAvatar(imagem);
}
```

Baixista já está com a imagem incorreta... Uma solução alternativa, utilizando polimorfismo, é 'mover' os `if`s para cada uma das subclasses:

```
public void exibirAvatar(PaginaWeb pagina, Musico musico) {
  String imagem = musico.getImagem();
  pagina.exibirAvatar(imagem);
} 

public class Baterista extends Musico {
  public String getImagem() {
    return "/img/bateria.jpg";
  }
}

public class Guitarrista extends Musico {
  public String getImagem() {
    return "/img/guitarra.jpg";
  }
}

// etc
```

Substituindo, assim, uma série de `if`s encadeados por polimorfismo.

### Utilizar implementações falsas/alternativas em testes

Este é um exemplo que costumo dar a quem trabalha comigo. Suponha que você esteja desenvolvendo um sistema para enviar mensagens SMS quando algum evento ocorra. Por exemplo, quando um servidor na sua rede cai, você quer notificar todos os sysadmins.

Para facilitar o exemplo, vamos supor que a sua operadora de telefonia provê uma biblioteca em que, para enviar mensagens SMS, basta saber o número do celular e o conteúdo da mensagem.

Em uma primeira versão, você escreve:

```
public interface Notificador {
  void notificar(PossuiCelular pessoa, String mensagem);
}

public class NotificadorProducao implements Notificador {

  private final OperadoraTelefonia operadora; // biblioteca da sua operadora

  public NotificadorSysadmin(OperadoraTelefonia operadora) {
    this.operadora = operadora;
  }

  public void notificar(PossuiCelular pessoa, String mensagem) {
    String celular = pessoar.getCelular();
    operadora.enviarSms(celular, mensagem);
  }

}
```

e aí, onde periodicamente verifica-se efetivamente o status dos servidores:

```
public class VerificadorStatusServidor {

  private final Sysadmins sysadmins;
  private final Servidores servidores;
  private final Notificador notificador;

  public NotificadorSysadmin(Sysadmins sysadmins,
                             Servidores servidores, 
                             Notificador notificador) {
    this.sysadmins = sysadmins;
    this.servidores = servidores;
    this.notificador = notificador;
  }

  public void check() {
    for (Servidor servidor : servidores.getTodos()) {
      if (servidor.naoResponde()) {
        notificarSysadmins(servidor);
      }
    }
  }

  private void notificarSysadmins(Servidor servidor) {
    for (Sysadmin admin : sysadmins.getTodos()) {
      notificador.notificar(admin, "Servidor " + servidor.getNome() + " não responde");
    }
  }

}
```

Como boa prática, você escreveu um teste para isto (e utilizou TDD inclusive).

```
public void sysadmin_deve_ser_notificado() {
  Sysadmins admins = new Sysadmins();
  admins.add(new Sysadmin("A", "555-0000"));
  admins.add(new Sysadmin("B", "555-1111"));
  admins.add(new Sysadmin("C", "555-2222"));

  Servidores servidores = new Servidores();
  servidores.add(new Servidor("1", "online"));
  servidores.add(new Servidor("2", "offline"));
  servidores.add(new Servidor("3", "offline"));

  Notificador notificador = new NotificadorSysadmin(new OperadoraTelefonia());

  VerificadorStatusServidor verificador = new VerificadorStatusServidor(admins, servidores, notificador);

  verificador.check();

  // assertivas
}
```

Todos os testes passam e todos ficam felizes.

A única questão é que, um mês depois, o gerente de seu projeto pergunta:

"Nossa conta de telefonia teve um aumento de 1200%!!!!!!!!!!! Quem ligou trocentas vezes para os sysadmins?"

E a verdade é que ninguém ligou, apenas o servidor de integração que rodou os testes a cada commit. E cada vez que o teste acima rodou, enviou um **SMS real**, com **custo real** de telefonia para os sysadmins.

A solução, neste caso, é utilizar implementações falsas. Substituir o `Notificador` **real** por um para ambiente de testes. Ou seja, no código do teste acima, substituir

```
Notificador notificador = new NotificadorSysadmin(new OperadoraTelefonia());
```

por

```
Notificador notificador = new NotificadorFalso();
```

Sendo que `NotificadorFalso` é:

```
public class NotificadorFalso implements Notificador {

  private List<Notificacao> notificacoes = new ArrayList<Notificacao>();

  public void notificar(PossuiCelular pessoa, String mensagem) {
    Notificacao n = new Notificacao(pessoa, mensagem);
    notificacoes.add(n);
  }

}
```

Assim, acessando a lista de `notificacoes` do seu NotificadorFalso, você ainda é capaz de verificar se o seu `VerificadorStatusServidor` funciona corretamente, sem ter os custos **reais** de envio de SMS.

Inclusive é possível simular casos em que a comunicação SMS falha, por exemplo:

```
public class NotificadorComErroSMS implements Notificador {
  public void notificar(PossuiCelular pessoa, String mensagem) {
    throw new ExcecaoDeComunicacaoSms();
  }
}
```

Por fim, notar que é o tipo de coisa que fazemos várias vezes ao dia e, por vezes, não notamos:

```
 Set<String> nomesDistintos = new HashSet<String>();
 // oops, quero percorrer com nomes ordenados
 Set<String> nomesDistintos = new TreeSet<String>();
 // oops, quero percorrer na ordem que foram inseridos
 Set<String> nomesDistintos = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

Comment: Eu sou adepto das explicações seguidas de exemplos reais. Acho que é uma excelente abordagem didática e facilita muito o entendimento. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A vantagem, no seu caso, da utilização do tipo `Musico` é a possibilidade de usar métodos que tratam das características que `Violinista` e `Baterista` possuem em comum.
Por outro lado, a não utilização implicaria na duplicidade de código para tratar particularmente Violinista e Baterista.
Você não consegue usar os métodos de `Violinista` em uma variável do tipo `Musico` porque neste momento, a variável do tipo músico pode ser tanto `Baterista`, `Flautista`, etc..., então não dá para chamar, por exemplo, `Musico.trocaCordas()` sendo que este poderia ser do tipo `Baterista`.
Digamos portanto que, se `Musico` possuir o método `AbrirPartitura`, este método poderá ser chamado diretamente, tanto em `Violisita.AbrirPartirura()`, `Baterista.AbrirPartitura()`, `Flautista.AbrirPartitura()` e `Musico.AbrirPartitura` (sendo que músico pode ser qualquer classe que herda de Musico).

Answer (score 1):

Em Design de Software devemos sempre previlegiar as abstrações em detrimento das classes concretas para diminuir o Acoplamento e a dependência entre os diversos colaboradores do sistema. Ou seja devemos procurar promover Acoplamento Fraco entre os objetos que colaboram para executar um serviço ou funcionalidade.

O Acoplamento forte ocorre quando uma classe dependente contém uma referencia direta para uma classe concreta, que fornece o comportamento desejado. A dependência não pode ser substituída, sem a necessidade de uma mudança na classe dependente.

O fraco acoplamento ocorre quando a classe dependente contém referencia para uma interface, que pode, ser implementada por uma ou várias classes concretas.

A Interface determina um "contrato" especifico com uma lista definida de métodos e / ou atributos que as classes concretas devem implementar.

Qualquer classe que implementa a interface pode satisfazer a dependência e uma alteração em sua implementação não vai gerar propagação de alteração nas outras classes concretas, ou seja, esta abordagem promove a extensibilidade no design do software, a um custo muito baixo.

Quanto mais fazemos referencia a classes concretas no nosso código, mais **Aumentamos o Acoplamento** e perdemos a capacidade de fazer manutenção a baixo custo. Por este motivo Acoplamento Alto diminui a qualidade do software e deve ser evitado.

Veja imagem ilustrativa de baixo acoplamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]