# Quando e por que devemos usar polimorfismo?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, polimorfismo

Quando e por que devemos usar o polimorfismo no Java, pois até agora só usei isso pra fazer várias janelas baseadas em um modelo.

O polimorfismo do jeito que eu estou aplicando é melhor que fazer uma janela independente da outra?

Comment: Alguns Links que podem te ajudar : 1. [Apostila Caelum sobre Orientação a objetos](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/heranca-reescrita-e-polimorfismo/#7-2-reescrita-de-metodo) 2. [Polimorfismo - Post Blog JavaProgressivo](http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2012/10/Polimorfismo-em-Java--o-que-e-pra-que-serve-como-e-onde-usar.html)

Comment: Relacionadas: [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/3117) e [Por que criar um objeto usando a superclasse?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5290/3117)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Polimorfismo é quando se usa herança, interface ou classe abstrata, de forma que uma classe é de mais de um "tipo" ao mesmo tempo.

Exemplo: Se você tem uma classe "Dog" que é herdada da classe "Animal", as instâncias da classe "Dog" serão ao mesmo tempo um Dog e um Animal.

Isso não costuma ser tão aplicado a modelagem de dados , mas pode ser usado em para resolver problemas de arquitetura de *software*.

Exemplo: Você tem um programa em que pode salvar/exportar dados tanto em XML como em ZIP, à escolha do usuário. Neste caso "XML" e "ZIP" podem ser classes que assinam uma interface "Arquivo" que diz que eles têm que ter um método "ler" e outro "salvar". Quando você for chamar o método "salvar", você só sabe que ele é um Arquivo, mas não sabe se ele é do tipo XML ou ZIP.

Algo parecido pode ser usado caso você queira que o seu programa funcione tanto em MySQL quanto em Postgres, por exemplo.

Enfim, vai também da sua criatividade.

Comment: Então é tudo uma questão de preferência e necessidade?

Comment: @gcarvalho97 Sim, as suas necessidades é que vão indicar quando que é apropriado utilizá-lo.

Comment: O que foi dito aqui é explicação de herança e não de polimorfismo. Muito menos responde o que foi perguntado. Não entendi a aceitação (é até um direto do AP), menos ainda tantos votos em uma resposta que no fundo está errada (pelo menos nesse contexto).

Comment: "Vai da sua criatividade"?!?! Se você está programando em OO, provavelmente está usando polimorfismo sem saber. De forma breve, é o mecanismo que permite classes herdeiras sobreescreverem implementações das classes herdadas. O exemplo sobre interfaces e classes, relação com heranças está OK, mas os conceitos são duas coisas distintas. Não existe espaço pra "criatividade" na definição de polimorfismo.

Answer (score 19):

Vou responder o que dá, até porque a resposta que existe não explica o que foi de fato perguntado. Não é possível dizer se está fazendo corretamente alguma coisa sem ver o que está fazendo.

O que aparentemente está fazendo com as janelas é apenas a herança. Isso [gera uma subclasse e um subtipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101). O polimorfismo pode ocorrer junto, mas nada indica que isso ocorre no exemplo.

Em Java a forma principal de usar polimorfismo é através da herança.

## Definição

[Polimorfismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) é a substituição de um tipo por outro que se adéque ao que se pretende fazer. Através da herança é garantido que a adequação ocorra, pelo menos tecnicamente, não dá para garantir conceitualmente.

Então se tem uma classe que é um modelo de janela e as janelas concretas são herdadas dela, há herança e provavelmente polimorfismo em várias situações. Mas é importante notar que são mecanismos diferentes. Tanto que o polimorfismo pode se dar de outras formas e a herança não exige ser polimórfica.

Algumas pessoas acham que polimorfismo é algo vinculado à OOP. Até é em uma direção, [não há OOP sem polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101), mas há polimorfismo sem OOP.

## Exemplo

Para entender o polimorfismo pense em um método que escreveu que recebe `JanelaModelo` e lá dentro esse objeto faça algumas coisas, por exemplo chame `adicionarWidget()`.

Considere que por alguma razão na `JanelaPrincipal` precisou mudar a implementação. Quando a implementação não é mudada o polimorfismo não importa.

Agora você chamará esse método, mas passará um objeto do tipo `JanelaPrincipal`, que obviamente herdou de `JanelaModelo`. Como há herança isso será aceito, tudo o que esse método pode usar em um tipo certamente está presente no outro, dada a herança.

Qual método `adicionarWidget()` será chamado? O existente em `JanelaModelo` ou o existente em `JanelaPrincipal`?

Se não existisse o polimorfismo será chamado o da `JanelaModelo` e adicionará *widgets* onde não deve. Com o polimorfismo há uma substituição e quem será chamado é o método de `JanelaPrincipal`, mesmo que originalmente esse método tenha sido pensado para trabalhar com `JanelaModelo`. Assim tudo funcionará como o esperado.

- [Exemplo prático explicando quando ocorre polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89311/101).
- [Exemplo em C# de polimorfismo ocorrendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96502/101).

## Quando usar?

Na prática, nesses casos descritos no exemplo, sempre que tiver uma herança e sobreposição de um método na classe derivada.

Note que o Java faz polimorfismo por padrão. A não ser que declare um método como `final` ele é virtual e por isso o polimorfismo (a substituição) ocorrerá sempre que houver um método igual na classe derivada. Então de certa forma está usando mesmo sem perceber. Talvez por isso muita gente confunda herança com polimorfismo.

Quando se cria uma interface o polimorfismo sempre ocorrerá. E é [desejável usar interfaces sempre que possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

Nesse caso cria-se um método (ou outra situação que se espera um tipo de objeto) que receberá a interface. Como interfaces são abstratas, jamais será passado um objeto baseado nela, apenas um objeto que será subtipo dela, ou seja, que implementa algo determinado nela. E o método na classe que a implementa certamente terá uma implementação, enquanto a interface certamente não terá, há sobrescrita. Por isso o polimorfismo certamente ocorrerá.

[Java 8 tem interfaces que fazem subclasse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101), é um pouco diferente, mas não vamos complicar.

Frequentemente há abusos do uso de polimorfismo, especialmente em Java. Nem sempre dá para fazer polimorfismo, ou mesmo herança, e tudo funcionar como o esperado. Há até o [princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) que trata desse assunto.

Nas suas janelas está usando polimorfismo e nem percebendo. Não está fazendo com intenção.

Um [exemplo real sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101).

[Outro bom exemplo prático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142596/101).

## Por que usar?

Para facilitar a generalização de algoritmos e estruturas de dados.

Imagine que sem ela teria que ter um método que recebe `JanelaPrincipal`, outro método que faz exatamente a mesma coisa e muda só que ele recebe `JanelaCliente`, outro para `JanelaProduto`, e assim por diante. Seria um absurdo. O polimorfismo permite usar um só método que se vira para escolher o código correto a usar.

## Mecanismo

Algumas linguagens fazem isso de forma diferente, uma delas é o compilador identificar a diferença de tipo e gerar uma nova versão do código usado específico para aquele tipo. [Isso tem vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101).

Java usa uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e tem apenas um código único. Ou seja, quando precisar chamar um método polimórfico em vez dele fazer a chamada direta, ele olha em uma tabela virtual (*vtable*) quem deve ser chamado. Quando você passa um objeto de um tipo, a tabela vinculada a esse tipo é acessada. Por causa dessa indireção (tem dois passos para chamar o método certo) há uma quase insignificante perda de performance.

Mais detalhes podem ser vistos em [Polimorfismo em linguagem procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

Para entender [como pode funcionar de forma não polimórfica (C#)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).