# O que é uma classe, atributos e métodos virtual?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, terminologia, método

O que é uma classe, atributo e método virtual?

```
public virtual class nomeclasse { 

    public virtual int id { get;set; }

    public virtual void metodo() { }

}
```

Qual diferença?

Quando usar?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Primeiramente, no C# não é possível utilizar a palavra chave `virtual` diretamente na classe. É possível usar, sim, `abstract` para indicar uma classe abstrata.

Também no mundo .Net, geralmente se chama de propriedade o que você chamou de atributo, sendo que atributo no .Net significa outra coisa... isso gera um certo grau de confusão.

Partindo disso, podemos dizer que a palavra chave `virtual` marca os métodos e propriedades que podem ser extendidos por uma sub-classe, ou seja, que permite ter o comportamento alterado através de um `override`. Assim sendo, ao criar uma subclasse, é possível tornar ela mais específica, mas sem ter de reimplementar toda a classe, pois é possível alterar o comportamento pontualmente.

Exemplo:

```
public class PessoaBase
{
    public virtual string QuemEVoce()
    {
        return "Não sei quem sou!";
    }
}

public class PessoaMiguel : PessoaBase
{
    public override string QuemEVoce()
    {
        return "Eu sou Miguel!";
    }
}
```

Note que eu extendi a classe `PessoaBase` alterando o seu comportamento... no que ela respondia "Não sei quem sou!", eu alterei o comportamento na nova classe de forma que responda "Eu sou Miguel!".

O mais importante nisso tudo é que ambas as classes podem ser tratadas da mesma forma, pois ambas são de fato do tipo `PessoaBase`. Isso quer dizer que, através de uma variável do tipo `PessoaBase` eu consigo operar tanto um objeto do tipo `PessoaBase` como também uma do tipo `PessoaMiguel`:

```
List<PessoaBase> pessoas = new List<PessoaBase>
{
    { new PessoaBase() },
    { new PessoaMiguel() },
};

foreach (var pessoa in pessoas)
{
    Console.Write(pessoa.QuemEVoce());
}
```

Comment: Estranhei quando li, `virtual class`, tava vendo se era possível e qual seria o comportamento, mas você já respondeu. Já que não faria muito sentido o conceito de `virtual` em uma `class`. +1

Comment: Acho que confundi class virtual com partial, rsrsrs também não sei a diferença entre partial, quanto a métodos, eu entendi, ficou claro, mas necessariamente precisa ser virtual para eu sobreescrever?

Comment: @Rod: não necessariamente... para dar `override`, o membro na classe de base deve possuir um desses modificadores: `abstract`, `virtual` ou `override`... sendo que no último caso, a classe de base já deu `override` na base da base.

Comment: Ficou claro, obrigado

Comment: @Rod: quanto ao `partial`... é só uma forma de separar o código de uma classe em dois blocos, podendo estar em arquivos distintos. É geralmente usado para código gerado por ferramenta, na qual a ferramenta gera a classe com `partial` para que o programador possa adicionar mais código nesta mesma classe de dentro de outro arquivo... sendo assim, se a ferramente gerar o arquivo novamente, o código do programador não será afetado. Não recomendo utilizar classes parciais para organização de código... se você vir algo do tipo sendo feito, então tem algo cheirando mal.

Comment: Ótima exemplificação de como funciona a palavra chave virtual.

Answer (score 6):

**Classe** é uma estrutura/modelo que representa um objeto/propósito do mundo real.

Exemplos:

```
class Veiculo {...}
class Animal {...}
class Pessoa {...}
```

**Atributos** são características que a classe possui.

Exemplo - Uma pessoa tem nome, data de nascimento, CPF, RG, estado civil, etc...:

```
class Pessoa {
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public Date DataNascimento { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Métodos** são ações que a classe pode fazer.

Exemplo - Na classe pessoa, podemos ter uma ação Andar(), Dormir(), etc. Se tratando de programação, podemos ter métodos como Salvar(), Excluir(), GetById(), etc.

```
public class Pessoa {
   ...
   public void Andar(int qtdePassos);
   public boolean Salvar(Pessoa pessoa);
   ...
}
```

Existem vários atributos o qual podemos associar a um atributo, método e classe.

No caso do atributo **"VIRTUAL"** ele diz que o método pode ser sobrescrito na classe descendente (que herda da classe principal), ou seja, permite usar o código da classe principal ou então ignorar re-escrevendo o código na classe herdada.

Existem outros atributos como o "abstract" que diz que a implementação será feita na classe herdada e não na principal; "static" diz que o método/classe não necessita de uma instancia criada para acessa-la; dentre outras...

Uma boa referencia é:
http://andrielleazevedo.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/conceitos-basicos-de-poo-programacao-orientada-a-objetos-para-c-parte-1/

Answer (score 4):

**CLASSE:** Uma classe é uma construção que permite que você crie seus próprios tipos personalizados, agrupando variáveis de outros tipos, métodos e eventos. Uma classe é como um modelo. Define os dados e comportamento de um tipo. Se a classe não é declarada como estática (STATIC), o código do cliente pode ser usado por meio da criação de objetos de ou de instâncias de que são atribuídas a uma variável. A variável permanece na memória até que todas as referências a ela saiam de escopo. Nesse momento, o CLR seleciona marca a variável como elegível para ser descartada. Se a classe é declarada estático (STATIC), apenas uma cópia existe em memória e o código do cliente só pode acessá-la por meio da classe propriamente dita, não por uma instância variável. Para obter mais informações, consulte Classes estáticas e membros de classe estáticos.

EX:

```
public class Person
{
    // Field
    public string name;

    // Constructor that takes no arguments.
    public Person()
    {
        name = "unknown";
    }

    // Constructor that takes one argument.
    public Person(string nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    }

    // Method
    public void SetName(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }
}
class TestPerson
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Call the constructor that has no parameters.
        Person person1 = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine(person1.name);

        person1.SetName("John Smith");
        Console.WriteLine(person1.name);

        // Call the constructor that has one parameter.
        Person person2 = new Person("Sarah Jones");
        Console.WriteLine(person2.name);

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
// Output:
// unknown
// John Smith
// Sarah Jones
```

**MÉTODO:** Um método é um bloco de código que contém uma série de instruções. Um programa faz com que as instruções sejam executados chamando o método e especificando todos os argumentos necessários do método. Em C#, todas instruções são executadas por métodos. O método Main é o ponto de entrada para cada aplicativo C# e ele é chamado pelo CLR (Common Languege Runtime) quando o programa é iniciado.
Métodos são declarados em um classe ou struct , especificando - se o nível de acesso como public ou private, modificadores opcionais, como abstract ou sealed, o valor de retorno, o nome do método. Essas partes são junto a assinatura de método.

```
abstract class Motorcycle
{
    // Anyone can call this.
    public void StartEngine() {/* Method statements here */ }

    // Only derived classes can call this.
    protected void AddGas(int gallons) { /* Method statements here */ }

    // Derived classes can override the base class implementation.
    public virtual int Drive(int miles, int speed) { /* Method statements here */ return 1; }

    // Derived classes must implement this.
    public abstract double GetTopSpeed(); 
}
```

**ATRIBUTOS:** Os atributos fornecem um método eficiente de associar metadados ou informações declarativas ao código (assemblies, types, métodos, propriedades e assim por diante).
Atributos fornecem um método poderoso de associar metadados ou informações declarativas, com código (assemblies, tipos, métodos, propriedades e assim por diante).
Depois que um atributo estiver associado a uma entidade do programa, o atributo pode ser consultado em tempo de execução usando uma técnica chamada reflection. Para obter mais informações, consulte Reflexo (guia de programação C#) .
Atributos têm as seguintes propriedades:
Atributos adicionam metadados para o seu programa. Metadados são informações sobre os tipos definidos em um programa.
Todos os assemblies .NET contêm um conjunto de metadados que descrevem os tipos e seus membros. Você pode adicionar atributos personalizados para especificar qualquer informação adicional necessária. Para obter mais informações, consulte, Criando atributos personalizados (C# e Visual Basic).
Você pode aplicar um ou mais atributos à assemblies, módulos ou elementos pequenos do programas como classes e propriedades.
Atributos podem aceitar argumentos da mesma forma que métodos e propriedades.
Seu programa pode examinar os metadados em outros programas ou seus próprios metadados por meio de reflexão. Para obter mais informações, consulte Acessando atributos com reflexo (C# programação guia).

**Usando atributos**

Atributos podem ser aplicados a maioria dos elementos de código, embora um atributo específico possa restringir os tipos de elementos ao qual ele é pode ser aplicado. No C#, especifica-se um atributo colocando o seu nome entre colchetes ([]) acima da declaração da entidade à qual ele pode ser aplicado. No Visual Basic, um atributo deve ser usado entre colchetes angulares (< >). Ele deve aparecer imediatamente antes do elemento ao qual ele é aplicado, na mesma linha.
Neste exemplo, o SerializableAttribute atributo é usado para aplicar uma característica específica a uma classe:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SampleClass
{
    // Objects of this type can be serialized.
}
```

**Usos comuns para atributos**
A lista a seguir inclui alguns dos usos comuns de atributos no código:

- A marcação de métodos usando a WebMethod atributo nos serviços Web para indicar que o método deve ser acessível através do protocolo SOAP . Para obter mais informações, consulte WebMethodAttribute.
  -Descrever como os parâmetros dométodo realizar marshalingquando interoperar com código nativo . Para obter mais informações, consulte MarshalAsAttribute.
  -Descrever as propriedades COM classes, métodos e interfaces.
  Chamada de código não gerenciado com o DllImportAttribute classe.
  -Descrever o seu assembly em termos de versão, título, descrição ou marca registrada.
  -Descrever quais membros de uma classe para serializar para persistência.
  -Descrevendo como mapa entre membros de classe e nós XML paraserializaçãode XML.
  -Descrever os requisitos de segurança para métodos.
  -Especificando as características usado para reforçar a segurança.
  -Controlando otimizações pelo compilador Just-In-Time (JIT) para que o código permanece fácil de depurar.
  -Obtendo informações sobre o chamador para um método.

Dei uma resumida, todos os links estão aqui:
[Metodo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms173114.aspx),[Atributo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/z0w1kczw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1),
[Classe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/x9afc042.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi responder porque há várias confusões nas outras respostas.

Vamos começar entender [o que é uma classe e como ela se diferencia de um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). **Classe** é só um modelo, não necessariamente para representar um objeto do mundo real. E mesmo quando ele tem ligações com o mundo real, ele não é o mesmo que o objeto do mundo real como alguns costumam dizer.

**Atributo** é um termo errado em C# e praticamente todas as linguagens de programação. Já dei mais detalhes em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

O termo até existe em C# e outras linguagens, mas não para o que as pessoas costumam explicar e como está em algumas respostas aqui. Uma das respostas quase acertou, mas o que le chama de atributo é, na verdade, o [atributo personalizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119024/101).

Mas ele não é característica que uma classe possui, ele é característica que membros dos tipos possuem. O que a pergunta fala na verdade chama-se **campo**. Um campo tem algumas características para serem declaradas, esses são atributos dele, alguns especificados na linguagem e pode-se usar os tais *custom attributes* também.

Então `public` é um atributo (de visibilidade) de um campo ou outro membro. `string` é um atributo (de tipo) do membro, `id` é um atributo (de nome) de uma [propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101) que não é nem campo, nem método, é um [padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101) chamado [*getter/setter*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) que faz um ou dois métodos acessar ou modificar um estado na classe ou no objeto com uma sintaxe de campo.

Campo e propriedade são coisas distintas e nenhum deles é um atributo. É muito comum que uma propriedade esteja diretamente vinculada a um campo. Uma propriedade pode ser virtual, até porque ela é um par de métodos.

Usar o padrão sem uma propriedade em C#, como mostrado em uma resposta, não costuma ser adequado.

Também [já respondi sobre **método virtual**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158579/101). Curiosamente lá falando da diferença entre `virtual` e `abstract` que deveria ser usado na classe da pergunta (um método pode ser `abstract` também.

Para entender sobre o uso do `virtual` precisa entender sobre [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) e [herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101).

Vou dar um exemplo um pouco melhor sobre como ele funciona (exemplos artificiais costumam ensinar o mecanismo bem, mas o conceito de forma errada), e de forma moderna:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<Pessoa> pessoas = new() {{ new() }, { new PessoaFisica { Nome = "Rod" }}};
foreach (var pessoa in pessoas) WriteLine(pessoa.EuSou());
                    
public class Pessoa { //não usei abstract para facilitar o exemplo
    protected int id; //campo
    public virtual string EuSou() => "Não sei quem sou!"; //método virtual
}

public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; init; } //propriedade
    public override string EuSou() => $"Eu sou {Nome}!"; //método virtual sobrescrito
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pzstTE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WSKQT7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Virtual.cs).

Por fim, em comentário o AP tem dúvida sobre [`partial`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77528/101).

Vai te interessar sobre o uso: [Pra que usar de private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165476/101).

Aproveite para ver o [padrão de nomenclatura de C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101) nos nomes.

Aprenda os termos corretos para não treinar e perpetuar o erro. Muitas pessoas aprendem errado, inclusive eu aprendi várias e ainda devo saber algumas coisas erradas, e de tanto praticar o erro elas não conseguem admitir que sempre estiveram erradas. Quando eu aprendo o certo eu começo usá-lo. Errar é humano, insistir no erro é teimosia, pra ser elegante.

Seguiu todos os *links*? Depois não reclama de aprender errado ;)