# Erro ao adicionar valor do While no List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, lista, genéricos

Estou tentando adicionar o valor de um resulto do meu `while`, para depois carregá-lo no meu `GridView`. Mas estou com um problema para adicionar o valor ao meu `List<>`. Não aceita adicionar `prob1.vTotal` em `lstTotal`.

```
namespace AvalicaoPratica.View
{
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<_Problema1> lstTotal = new List<_Problema1>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       _Problema1 prob1 = new _Problema1();
       while (prob1.Cont <= 64)
       {
           prob1.Vtotal = prob1.Vtotal + prob1.Graos;
           prob1.Graos = prob1.Graos * 2;
           prob1.Cont += 1;
       }

       lstTotal.Add(prob1.Vtotal);

       GridView1.DataSource = lstTotal;
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
   }
 }
```

Minha class

```
 public class _Problema1
{
    private int vtotal = 0;

    public int Vtotal
    {
        get { return vtotal; }
        set { vtotal = value; }
    }
    private int cont;

    public int Cont
    {
        get { return cont; }
        set { cont = value; }
    }
    private int graos = 1;

    public int Graos
    {
        get { return graos; }
        set { graos = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefira postar o código como texto, fica mais fácil para as pessoas trabalharem com ele. E qual é o problema?  Ele não aceita adicionar `prob1.vTotal` em `lstTotal`?

Comment: Sim, o problema é esse.

Comment: E qual é a composição de `_Problema1`? `prob1.vTotal`é um tipo numérico, um `int`, `Decimal` ou algo assim, certo?

Comment: _Problema1 é minha class, onde definir minhas 3 variáveis como do tipo int.

Comment: Eu sei mas precisaria saber qual é a composição dela para lhe ajudar.

Comment: Pronto, postei o código da minha class.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18378/discussion-between-paulo-vinicius-matos-and-bigown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lstTotal` é do tipo `List<_Problema1>` portanto você só pode adicionar elementos nesta lista que sejam deste tipo. `prob1.Vtotal` não é do tipo `_Problema1`. Ou você deve adicionar algum dado que seja do tipo `_Problema1` ou deve fazer `lstTotal` ser uma lista que recebe o mesmo tipo de `prob1.Vtotal`. Provavelmente o que você quer é:

```
namespace AvalicaoPratica.View {
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page {
        List<_Problema1> lstTotal = new List<_Problema1>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            _Problema1 prob1 = new _Problema1();
            while (prob1.Cont <= 64) {
                prob1.Vtotal += prob1.Graos;
                prob1.Graos *= 2;
                prob1.Cont++;
            }
            lstTotal.Add(prob1); //<== a mudança mais importante aqui
            GridView1.DataSource = lstTotal;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Processing.cs).

Neste caso o `GridView1` está recebendo uma lista de `_Probblema1` e ele deve estar preparado para isto. Não sei se é o seu desejo receber isto, se não for vai ter que adaptar para o que quer receber. Talvez você queira mostrar só o valor total no `GridView1`, ok aí é só montar ele para mostrar só isto e ignorar os demais dados. Se quiser insistir em ter apenas o valor total, nenhum problema, mas aí a sua lista terá que ser especificada para receber o tipo `int` e não `_Problema1`.

Mas provavelmente o código deve ter outros problemas, é esquisito fazer isto. Mas pode haver um bom motivo oculto que não dê para perceber olhando só este trecho.

---

Como nota adicional, você não segue nenhum padrão de nomenclatura, principalmente não segue nada comumente recomendado. Pode parecer bobagem mas isto dificulta entender e dar manutenção em código. Dê uma lida [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101). Ela é grande mas ajuda bastante organizar código.

Comment: Eu cheguei a fazer dessa forma, mas não carregou nada no meu GridView.

Comment: Eu resolvi o problema que você descreveu. Antes nem compilava. Agora você está com outro problema e com as informações passadas não tem como resolver. Sugiro postar outra pergunta passando os dados relevantes para que dê para entender o que o seu `GridView1` faz.