# Erro genérico de referência de objeto

Tags: c#, .net, nullpointerexception

> System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Esse erro esta dando no seguinte trecho de código:

```
Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();
ArquivoVersao versao = new ArquivoVersao();
versao.XNOME = "teste";
var list = new List<ArquivoVersao>();
list.Add(versao);
arquivo.ArquivoVersoes = list;
//arquivoVersoes é uma lista de Versoes
```

Classe Arquivo:

```
public class Arquivo
{
    public string ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string XARQUIVO { get; set; }
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public string EXTENSAO { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool IS_STREAM { get; set; }
    public string ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string DIRETORIO_GUID { get; set; }
    public TipoDeArquivo TipoDeArquivo { get; set; }
    public List<ArquivoVersao> ArquivoVersoes { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Arquivo Versão:

```
public class ArquivoVersao
{
        public string XNOME { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Por que você está tentando converter a lista para um Array, sendo que a propriedade ArquivoVersoes é uma Lista?

Comment: @Laerte Estou escrevendo uma resposta justamente começando por isto. Não sei se isto está gerando o erro ou se falta mais trechos onde realmente ocorre o problema. Não dá para perceber anda com o que foi postado.

Comment: porque simplesmente nao consigo adicionar, usando ArquivoVersoes.add, pois estou usando um WebService, esse Arquivo e ArquivoVersao são serviços.Na verdade declaro assim MeuServico.Arquivo arquivo = MeuServico.Arquivo()

Comment: o erro ta dando aqui: arquivo.ArquivoVersoes = list.ToArray();

Comment: E o que acontece quando usa apenas `arquivo.ArquivoVersoes = list;`?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cliente.MeuService.ArquivoVersao>' to 'Cliente.MeuService.ArquivoVersao[]

Comment: Não, este erro tem que acontecer quando você usar o `.ToArray()`. O que acontece quando você não o usa?

Comment: quando nao usa, acontece isso, quando usa nao tem erro

Comment: eu tbm nao entendi o porque disso, ja que ArquivoVersoes ja é lista

Comment: Então está funcionando quando tira o `.ToArray()` que tinha inicialmente. Esse erro `System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.` não acontece neste trecho de código? Eu teste e está funcionando como deveria: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Qt4RA

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20903/discussion-between-war-lock-and-bigown).

Comment: Substitua o "arquivo.ArquivoVersoes = list;" por "arquivo.ArquivoVersoes.AddRange(list);"

Comment: Mateus não encontra esse Addrange.

Comment: Estranho...
E se você atribuir como "arquivo.ArquivoVersoes.Add(list)"?

Comment: O trecho que você colocou não possui problemas, você identificou a parte do código errada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De imediato vejo um problema no uso do `.ToArray()`. Se você tem uma variável que é uma lista e vai guardar em outra variável que também é uma lista do mesmo tipo não tem porque converter a lista em *array*.

O código apresentado na versão atual da pergunta (antes tinha o `.ToArray()`) não contém o erro declarado:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();
        ArquivoVersao versao = new ArquivoVersao();
        versao.XNOME = "teste";
        var list = new List<ArquivoVersao>();
        list.Add(versao);
        arquivo.ArquivoVersoes = list;
        //arquivoVersoes é uma lista de Versoes
    }
}

public class Arquivo {
    public string ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string XARQUIVO { get; set; }
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public string EXTENSAO { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool IS_STREAM { get; set; }
    public string ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string DIRETORIO_GUID { get; set; }
//    public TipoDeArquivo TipoDeArquivo { get; set; }
    public List<ArquivoVersao> ArquivoVersoes { get; set; }
}

public class ArquivoVersao {
        public string XNOME { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fXw6DS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xZaxJZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ObjectInitialization.cs).

Quando tiver mais informações eu posso melhorar a resposta.

Também você deveria considerar não usar nomes com todos os caracteres maiúsculos e *underline* (sublinhado). Isto foge do [padrão adotado pelo C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101).

Comment: Realmente o erro estava vindo do outro lado.Mas obrigado pelas dicas.