# Retornar DataReader para campo tipo bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, ado.net, booleano

Preciso retornar um campo que é do tipo `bool`:

```
    public List<TB_USUARIO> ListarTodos()
    {
        var strQuery = "select * from tb_usuario";

        using (contexto = new Contexto())
        {
            var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
            return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(retornoDataReader);
        }

    }

    private List<TB_USUARIO> TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        var retornando = new List<TB_USUARIO>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            TB_USUARIO tabela = new TB_USUARIO()
            {
                IDUSUARIO = reader["IDUSUARIO"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["IDUSUARIO"]),
                NOME = reader["NOME"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["NOME"].ToString(),
                LOGIN = reader["LOGIN"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["LOGIN"].ToString(),
                SENHA = reader["SENHA"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["SENHA"].ToString(),
                ADMINISTRADOR = (bool)reader["ADMINISTRADOR"] //este campo
        };

            retornando.Add(tabela);
        }
        reader.Close();
        return retornando;
    }
```

Comment: Qual o valor que tem dentro de `reader["ADMINISTRADOR"]`? Está acontecendo algum problema? Esta coluna pode ser `null`? Qual o tipo dela?

Comment: está vindo sempre como false

Comment: Qual é o tipo da coluna no banco de dados?

Comment: banco de dados sql server coluna char(1), mais eu já tenho a resposta:
 ADMINISTRADOR = (reader["ADMINISTRADOR"] as string == "S") ? true : false

Comment: Não precisa do `? true : false`. A sentença `(reader["ADMINISTRADOR"] as string == "S")` já retorna um booleano.

Comment: @jbueno , agradeço a ajuda de todos! imensamente agradecido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta fazer isto:

```
ADMINISTRADOR = reader["ADMINISTRADOR"] as string == "S"; //se tem S ou N
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/ConvertType.cs).

Como a coluna originalmente não é um booleano e sim uma texto, deve-se comparar com o texto que representa o estado verdadeiro.

Embora seja tarde, aconselho não usar nomes tudo em maiúsculo e prefixos em nomes.

Comment: não é muito tarde, o banco tem os campos em maiúsculo, e as classes em fiz seguindo mesmo padrão, pode me explicar o problema disso ?

Comment: @itasouza Não há problema em manter as propriedades em maiúsculo, mas foge a [convenção de nomes do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Não é um problema, é violação de estilo apenas. NO SQL até é normal (embora eu não goste), mas é esquisito usar isto no C#. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101. E o uso de prefixo é algo redundante e desnecessário, é considerado notação húngara.

Comment: @itasouza Uma dica com base no seu comentário: linguagens geralmente tem convenções diferentes, só porque o SQL adota esse padrão, não quer dizer que no C# deve ser assim. Se você consumir esses dados via API com JS, o JS também tem outro padrão que deve ser respeitado. Mas conforme o comentário do #bigown, realmente não é um problema, só é uma violação de estilo.

Comment: Apesar que até hoje o mais comum que eu vi em bancos é usando o underscore. Vejo bastante também o PascalCase e o camelCase. Primeira vez que eu vejo UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo os comentários, a coluna `ADMINISTRADOR` é do tipo `char` e você salva os valores `S`/`N`.

A única conversão explícita de string para boolean que você pode fazer é converter `"true"` (para `true`) ou `"false"` (para `false`).

A solução é você validar qual o valor que existe na coluna, desta forma

```
ADMINISTRADOR = (string)reader["ADMINISTRADOR"] == "S"
```

Isso, se a coluna `ADMISTRADOR` não aceitar nulos, caso contrário use o operador `as` (nesse caso considerando que `null` corresponde a `false`.

```
ADMINISTRADOR = reader["ADMINISTRADOR"] as string == "S"
```