# Melhorar a performance de um método com ponteiros

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, ponteiro

Aqui vai o código funcionando:

```
string string_pick(string text, string tag, char caractere)
{
    int index = text.IndexOf(tag);
    return text.Substring(index + tag.Length, text.IndexOf(caractere, index + tag.Length + 1) - (index + tag.Length));
}
```

Exemplo de funcionamento:

```
string x = "kkkkkkkkkkkk jjjjjjjjjjj oloco icaro alguma coisa algumas palavras várias loucuras name:'icaro' lalala huhuasd sdiufhidf sdifuhisuhdf kkkkkkk";
string temporaria = string_pick(x,"name:'",'\'');
```

A temporária vai ser "icaro".

Bem, como vai mexer com uma *string* gigantesca, eu gostaria de apenas acessar aquela parte de memória e não copiar a *string* novamente (no caso do que o argumento da função está fazendo).

No C++ resolvi assim:

```
string string_pick(string *text, string tag, char caractere)
{
    int index = (*text).find(tag);
    return (*text).substr(index + tag.length(), (*text).find(caractere, index + tag.length() + 1) - (index + tag.length()));
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, se decida se é C++ ou C#. O segundo código não compila em nenhuma das duas. O primeiro parece que compila em C#. Coloque um [mcve]. Aproveite e explique melhor qual a intenção.

Comment: Cara, o segundo foi uma tentativa, ele realmente não funciona, deu errado aqui, mas eu estou explanando apenas oque eu quero entende?

Comment: Quanto ao C++ ou C#, é por que quem sabe em C++ provavelmente saberia em C# já que muda pouca coisa ali...

Comment: Eu vou responder o que dá mas se fizesse o que eu te pedi eu poderia dar uma resposta melhor.

Comment: Me desculpe, é meu primeiro post nesse overflow, eu vou ler oque você mandou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada fazer coisas doidas que "funcionam" não é programar. Fazer o que é certo é programar. Funcionar não é parâmetro para saber se está certo. Não vou dizer se isto está certo ou não porque não há informações suficientes para isto.

Mesmo que fosse possível colocar o ponteiro em C# (até existe como, mas em situações bem específicas que não vale falar aqui) fazer o que está tentando não resolveria nada para economizar memória já que dentro do método já está criando uma nova instância. Se há algum problema de consumo de memória, e mesmo isto é questionável, é dentro do método e não na comunicação dele com o mundo externo que só copia a referência e é bem eficiente.

Se fosse outro problema a classe [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8) poderia ser uma solução. Mas o caso nem demonstra ter um problema real de performance ou alocação excessiva. E se tiver a pergunta deveria demonstrar. E só deveria se preocupar com isso se o problema for real e não apenas uma suposição.

O código escrito em C++ não é nem um pouco mais eficiente do que o escrito em C#. Alias é uma completa desnecessidade usar ponteiro ali. Só está criando uma indireção sem sentido. Provavelmente está creditando uma qualidade ao ponteiro que ele não tem.

O código pode ser simplificado e ter uma [melhor nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Pode começar em usar o nome no padrão `StringPick()`. Os nomes dos parâmetros poderiam indicar melhor sua função aí, não só dizer o que terá nele, isto o tipo já diz.

Só para dar uma ideia do que pode ser melhorado. Eu faria melhor se soubesse os requisitos reais.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cP6W94). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5DIn7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/StringPick.cs).

Comment: Por que string_pick: Por que eu imagino eu eu estou minerando uma palavra com uma picareta...(quanto a isso é inquestionável).
Quanto a sua funcionalidade, ele pega uma página em html e pega uma palavra que está dentro de uma tag, ex:
string_pick(htmlpage,"name:'",'\''); Nesse caso ele pega oque está entre Name:' e '

Comment: reformulei a pergunta e coloquei do modo que funcionou em c++, da uma olhada

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, é por que eu vi uma aula de ponteiros e do nada comecei a imaginar que ponteiros iriam diminuir o processo.

Como você perguntou ali se é um problema real ou uma suposição, vou responder, é um problema real de um programa que eu fiz pro meu tio, tem uma parte do processo que faz um _loop_ com isso ai, e no meu computador esse _loop_ demora 6 minutos, o dele é uns 11 anos mais velho e eu imagino que possa demorar até 2 horas pra realizar a tarefa, por isso eu estava querendo melhorar a função.

Comment: Olha a otimização que eu consegui: (https://s31.postimg.org/ggz0ak3ff/Sem_t_tulo.png)

Comment: E perfilou para descobrir onde ´o problema. Não parece ser onde está falando. De qualquer forma, o que dava pra ajudar nessa pergunta eu ajudei, o problema nem está claro.

Comment: O problema é que eu estava pensando em formas de deixar essa função mais rápida, eu estava imaginando se não seria melhor em vez de copiar uma nova string, simplesmente trabalhar em cima da original... Mas isso nem é muito lento, esquece kk