# O que é um Span<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, memória

Depois do .NET Core 2.1, o framework introduziu o `System.Span`. Sua declaração é:

```
public readonly ref struct Span<T>
```

Na documentação tem algumas breves explicações sobre o armazenamento em [pilha ao invés de heap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-a-stack-e-heap) mas ainda não vi um real motivo para usar ele. Ele é compatível com a maioria dos tipos primitivos.

O que é o `Span<T>` e quando devo usá-lo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para a maioria dos códigos do tipo "só preciso que funcione (e esteja correto)" realmente ele não é tão útil. E convenhamos que o grosso da utilização de C# é assim. É só uma linguagem para criar soluções sem grandes preocupações com eficiência, ainda que não seja usada sem nenhuma preocupação com ela. Geralmente as pessoas não adotam C# porque ela é eficiente.

Mas em códigos que precisam de eficiência é necessário ter mecanismo que permite obter isso. E os códigos do próprio .NET e tecnologias associadas a eficiência é muito importante. Como você acha que eles conseguiram [ir para as cabeças no TechEmpower](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r21&test=plaintext)? E estão melhorando em outros *benchmarks* em cada versão, no momento que *linkei* isto ainda nem pegaram o .NET 7, que teve melhorias no `Span` entre outras coisas, por mudanças no *runtime* e na linguagem.

Muito das enormes melhorias de performance do .NET tem a ver com o uso do `Span` em locais que o acesso era feito de forma mais ingênua. No passado dava para melhorar usando ponteiro, mas isso *custava caro* para desenvolver, manter e garantir a robustez. Procure nos [fontes do .NET](https://github.com/dotnet) o seu uso. Em cada versão está sendo usado em muito mais lugares.

Não é que não desse para trazer essa eficiência antes, mas teria que fazer em C++ ou recorrer ao contexto [`unsafe`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142030/101) do C#, o que é algo ruim, menos robusto e menos produtivo e difícil de manter. A criação do `ref struct` e mais alguns outros mecanismos na linguagem vieram em primeiro lugar para poder criar o `Span` e não precisar [acessar a memória através de ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415168/101), que é algo "perigoso".

Em alguns casos passados usaram ponteiros e fizeram algumas gambiarras para obter eficiência, até mesmo o *runtime* tratar certas situações de forma diferente ou ter funções em C++ para fazer certas operações. Agora mudaram para `Span` sem perder performance, ganhando robustez, produtividade, sem contar com um ganho subjetivo de [*dog fooding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food).

Então o `Span` é uma forma de acessar uma porção da memória de forma mais eficiente e segura, sem usar ponteiros ou alocar no *heap* ou usar objetos não gerenciados. Se você precisa dessa eficiência no seu código ou vai colocar em um código usado por outras pessoas ou você mesmo onde a eficiência pode ser necessária, deve usar em vez de acessar de maneiras mais simples e que existem na linguagem desde o começo. O `Span` é uma forma de ponteiro mais seguro e simples, ainda que ligeiramente mais limitado, algo que o ponteiro de C# já é um pouco, comparando com C/C++.

Ele lembra um pouco as [*views*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324205/101) que o C++ criou para dar mais robustez evitando o uso direto do ponteiro. Você pode usar o ponteiro e o resultado será o mesmo, em quase todas as situações, mas de forma menos segura.

Então se você não está pensando em usar um ponteiro em C# não precisa pensar em `Span`. Porém, será que não está perdendo uma oportunidade de melhorar a eficiência por não pensar em um ponteiro?

Novamente, a maioria dos programadores não ligam ou não precisam disso, mas se você estiver em uma situação assim, use o `Span` no lugar de um ponteiro, se isso for possível, nem sempre é e o ponteiro ainda pode ser necessário, em raros casos. Em alguns casos pode usar o [`Memory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que serve para propósito semelhante, mas pode usar no *heap*.

Ambos permitem acessar qualquer porção de memória, de forma **quase** arbitrária, não importa onde ela esteja localizada, como um ponteiro poderia, mas de forma muito mais arbitrária. Para maioria dos fins é só essa estrutura que precisaria.

A [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-8.0) tem bons exemplos acessando *arrays*, *strings*, memória não gerenciada, etc. O que faltou justamente dizer lá de forma mais clara é que fazendo assim obtém-se mais eficiência mantendo a robustez, portanto é desnecessário pensar nisso se este não é o objetivo.

Não force o seu uso, se não estava pensando em ponteiro não precisa dele. Se for usá-lo provavelmente precisará pensar toda aplicação assim.

Cada dia mais o C#/.NET pode ser usado em lugares que antes só pensava em C++, inclusive os [*runtime*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) (CLR) está sendo portado ou experimentado portar para o C#. O [Roslyn](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) está ficando mais rápido por causa disto. Com o novo modo para gerar código diretamente nativo está mais rápido e gera executáveis pequenos, ficando, não igual, mas competitivo com tecnologias das mais eficientes.

Não vou entrar na questão da memória porque tem diversas outras respostas que já falam disto, como a *linkada* na pergunta:

- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)
- [O que é referência de tipos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318525/101)
- [O que são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266756/101)
- [Por que métodos que operem ponteiros são inseguros no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244754/101)
- [Melhorar a performance de um método com ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135518/101)
- [O que é Garbage Collector e como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agora as próximas perguntas serão sobre "como usar o Span direito?" :D