# Variáveis públicas estáticas em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Como posso organizar meu código? Ao programar vão surgindo variáveis as quais estou deixando no mesmo código no topo como:

```
namespace myData.MySql
{
    public partial class teste
    {
        public static string M_CPF_PROCURADOR;
        public static string strM_NirfFormatado;
        private static string m_datainicio = "";
        (...)
```

Seria o ideal eu criar uma classe e  discriminá-las e chamando-as quando necessárias? Se sim poderia me informar como fazer?

Comment: É difícil responder só com estas informações. Coloque mais código, dê mais contexto, indique o que acha que pode estar errado.

Comment: Por exemplo:o calculo c= a+b, se eu criar uma rotina tipo private void soma(). Se eu colocar o cálculo dentro desta rotina, quando precisar do resultado de c em outra rotina, ou eu deixo a variável pública  ou envio por valor na rotina. A dúvida é, posso utilizar estas variáveis publicas estaticas  desta forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Começo dizendo que tenho medo se esse `partial` realmente é necessário.

Variáveis estáticas são da classe e não da instância. Ou seja, só existe um objeto nelas, não pode ter vários. É isso que deseja? Não parece, mas posso estar enganado, o trecho colocado não dá para inferir. Se é para ter o dado em cada objeto criado para este classe, as variáveis não podem ser estáticas.

Se precisa das variáveis acessíveis em vários métodos basta declará-las como privadas, não tem razão alguma para serem públicas. Elas só precisariam ser públicas se houvesse necessidade de acesso direto à elas fora da classe. Não parece ser o caso.

Sempre é melhor usar parâmetros do que acessar variáveis internas. Mas nem sempre é **o melhor** a fazer, depende de cada caso. O ideal é ter [baixo acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101), mas nem sempre podemos ou devemos fazer isso (o custo pode ser alto demais).

Não vejo necessidade de criar outra classe, de acordo com o que foi demonstrado na pergunta, mas pode ser o ideal se o caso concreto determinar algo mais que não está na pergunta. Coesão é algo bom para se alcançar, mas ela só pode ser determinada com dados suficientes.

A [nomenclatura dos identificadores parecem bem fora do que estabelece o .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101).

Se a pergunta for melhorada, eu melhoro a resposta. O ideal é que tivesse um caso concreto. Com um código artificial, tudo pode ser válido.

Comment: Entendi bigown. Foi super claro!!