# Valor não é adicionado a uma váriavel dentro de uma função

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, método, propriedade

Estou fazendo um simples programa de um quiz com perguntas e respostas, com pontuação. O meu problema é o seguinte: eu fiz uma função para que toda vez que a resposta for certa, +1 será adicionado na variável da pontuação.

```
public static int pontu1 { get; set; }

    public static int pont(int pontu1)
    {
        pontu1++;
        return pontu1;
    }
```

Então aparentemente, ela está funcionando, resolvi criar a função "resposta certa", para toda vez que a resposta for certa, essa função será chamada:

```
public static void rcerta()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Resposta certa");
        pont(pontu1);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Clear();
    }
```

O problema é, fui testar o código, mandou a pergunta, botei a resposta certa. Okay, a função rodou normal, deu resposta certa, porem, quando eu fui ver quanto estava minha pontuação, com o seguinte código (ele fica dentro de um switch de um menu que eu fiz) :

```
case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sua pontuação é: " + pontu1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para continuar....");
                    break;
```

A pontuação aparece como 0, mesmo com a resposta certa. Alguem pode me ajudar? Segue todo o programa e a classe abaixo.

Programa:

```
class Program
{
    public static int pontu1 { get; set; }

    public static int pont(int pontu1)
    {
        pontu1++;
        return pontu1;
    }

    public static void rcerta()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Resposta certa");
        pont(pontu1);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Clear();
    }

    public static void rerrada()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Resposta errada");
        Console.Clear();
    }

    public static void resetar()
    {
        string r;
        Console.WriteLine("Sua pontuação atual é: " + pontu1);
        Console.WriteLine("Deseja reiniciar sua pontuação?      S  / N");
        r = Console.ReadLine();
        if (r == "S")
        {
            pontu1 = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Pontuação reiniciada.");
            Console.WriteLine("Sua pontuação atual é: " + pontu1);
            Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para voltar ao menu...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pontuação mantida.");
            Console.WriteLine("Sua pontuação atual é: " + pontu1);
            Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para voltar ao menu...");
        }
    }

    public static void QuizIncio()
    {
        int opcao;
        Console.WriteLine("Escolha um assunto!");
        Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] teste");
        Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] teste2");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("Digite uma opção: ");
        opcao = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (opcao)
        {
            case 1:
                Class1.teste();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int opcao;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] Iniciar");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] Ver Pontuação");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 3 ] Resetar Pontuação");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 0 ] Sair do Programa");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("Digite uma opção: ");
            opcao = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opcao)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    QuizIncio();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sua pontuação é: " + pontu1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para continuar....");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.Clear();
                    resetar();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        while (opcao != 0); 
    }




}
```

Classe:

```
class Class1 : Program
{
    public static void teste()
    {
        string r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
        Console.WriteLine("Quanto é 2 + 2?");
        Console.WriteLine("a) 4");
        Console.WriteLine("b) 3");
        r1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (r1 == "a")
        {
            rcerta();
        }
        else
        {
            rerrada();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código está bem confuso e cheio de problemas. Nem vou tentar consertar porque daria muito trabalho e o foco da pergunta é apenas um. Se o código fosse mais organizado o erro não ocorreria. Está usando o mesmo nome para a propriedade da classe e para o parâmetro local do método que tem prioridade, então está adicionando no variável local que desaparece ao final da execução do método, e não mexe na propriedade. troquei o nome da propriedade, que inclusive está mais [de acordo com o estilo do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101) e o problema foi resolvido.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program {
    public static int Pontu1 { get; set; }

    public static int IncrementaPontos(int pontu1) {
        Pontu1++;
        return pontu1;
    }

    public static void RespostaCerta() {
        WriteLine("Resposta certa");
        IncrementaPontos(Pontu1);
        Task.Delay(2000);
//        Console.Clear();
    }

    public static void RespostaErrada() {
        WriteLine("Resposta errada");
        Clear();
    }

    public static void Resetar() {
        WriteLine("Sua pontuação atual é: " + Pontu1);
        WriteLine("Deseja reiniciar sua pontuação?      S  / N");
        string r = ReadLine();
        if (r == "S")  {
            Pontu1 = 0;
            WriteLine("Pontuação reiniciada.");
        } else WriteLine("Pontuação mantida.");
        WriteLine("Sua pontuação atual é: " + Pontu1);
        WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para voltar ao menu...");
    }

    public static void QuizIncio() {
        WriteLine("Escolha um assunto!");
        WriteLine("[ 1 ] teste");
        WriteLine("[ 2 ] teste2");
        WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        Write("Digite uma opção: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out int opcao)) return;
        switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                Class1.Teste();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }
 //       Console.Clear();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int opcao;
        do
        {
            WriteLine("[ 1 ] Iniciar");
            WriteLine("[ 2 ] Ver Pontuação");
            WriteLine("[ 3 ] Resetar Pontuação");
            WriteLine("[ 0 ] Sair do Programa");
            WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
            Write("Digite uma opção: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out opcao)) continue;
            switch (opcao) {
                case 1:
 //                   Console.Clear();
                    QuizIncio();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    WriteLine("Sua pontuação é: " + Pontu1);
                    WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para continuar....");
                    break;
                case 3:
//                    Clear();
                    Resetar();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
            }
//            Console.Clear();
        } while (opcao != 0); 
    }
}

class Class1 : Program {
    public static void Teste() {
        WriteLine("Quanto é 2 + 2?");
        WriteLine("a) 4");
        WriteLine("b) 3");
        string r1 = ReadLine();
        if (r1 == "a") RespostaCerta();
        else RespostaErrada();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3YcWmW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WVvhti). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/AmbiguityLocal.cs).

Dei uma boa melhorada, mas ainda dá para fazer mais.