# Conversão VB.NET para C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, switch

Encontrei essa linha de código:

```
Try
        Dim WebReq As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(GET_Data)
        Using WebRes As HttpWebResponse = WebReq.GetResponse
            Using Reader As New StreamReader(WebRes.GetResponseStream)
                Dim Str As String = Reader.ReadLine
                Select Case True
                    Case Str.Contains(Answer1)
                        Return "True"
                    Case Str.Contains(Answer2)
                        Return "Banned"
                    Case Str.Contains(Answer3)
                        Return "Invalid"
                    Case Else
                        Return "Invalid"
                End Select
            End Using
        End Using
```

Como forma de estudo necessito desse mesmo código em C#

```
 try
        {
            WebRequest WebReq = WebRequest.Create(Get_Data);
            using (WebResponse WebRes = WebReq.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(WebRes.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string Str = Reader.ReadLine();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (Str.Contains(answer1).ToString()!= null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("sadsads");
                            return "True";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Eu tentei utilizar case, mas não deu certo essa foi a ultima tentativa com `if`.

Comment: Da uma conferida  se o [telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) te ajuda.

Comment: Mesmo tentando converter por esse site, o código apresenta erro.
http://prntscr.com/f8i7aa

Comment: Isso não é VB6.

Comment: Use `if` em tudo que dará certo. E não coloque coisas que o código original não tem. @Mathias Por que?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquele código é muito ruim, eu acho que a melhor forma de fazer isto seria com `if`:

```
var WebReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(GET_Data);
using var WebRes = WebReq.GetResponse);
using var Reader = new StreamReader(WebRes.GetResponseStream);
var Str = Reader.ReadLine;
if (Str.Contains(Answer1)) return "True";
if (Str.Contains(Answer2)) return "Banned";
if (Str.Contains(Answer3)) return "Invalid";
return "Invalid";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/SerialIf.cs)

`Switch` deve ser usado apenas quando se tem **uma** variável com **múltiplos** valores que precisam ser testados. Este é um caso que se tem **múltiplas** variáveis para testar um **único** valor, que é o caso para que o `if` existe.

Na sua tentativa o `while` não faz sentido, menos ainda o `.ToString()!= null`, isto não estava no original. Se deseja fazer algo diferente teria que dizer o que. De fato se a variável `Answer` fosse um *array* um outro tipo enumerável, daria para usar o `while` para fazer as 3 comparações em um único `if`. Alguma coisa me diz que esse código deveria se bem diferente disso que foi colocado.

Aproveitei e melhorei mais algumas coisas secundárias.

Veja isto também: [Padrão de nomenclatura no código para o C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101)

Answer (score 2):

Essa construção do `VB` realmente não vai funcionar com `C#`, você vai precisar mesmo usar `if` se quiser testar usando `Contains` dessa maneira. Você pode adaptar o código usando uma expressão pra avaliar o `Contains` antes do `switch`, algo assim:

```
// Precisa adicionar esses using no começo do método
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Aqui vai o código:
string Str = Reader.ReadLine();
// Adicionar as strings que quer comparar em subStrings
List<string> subStrings = new List<string> { Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 };
switch (subStrings.FirstOrDefault(Str.Contains))
{
    case Answer1:
        Console.WriteLine("True");
        break;
    case Answer2:
        Console.WriteLine("Banned");
        break;
    case Answer3:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o operador [`switch()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch):

```
{
    HttpWebRequest WebReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(GET_Data);
    using (HttpWebResponse WebRes = WebReq.GetResponse)
    {
        using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(WebRes.GetResponseStream))
        {
            string Str = Reader.ReadLine;
            switch (true)
            {
                case Str.Contains(Answer1):
                    return "True";
                case Str.Contains(Answer2):
                    return "Banned";
                case Str.Contains(Answer3):
                    return "Invalid";
                default:
                    return "Invalid";
            }
        }
    }
}
```