# Como acessar propriedades de um objecto que está dentro de outro objeto?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, propriedade

No fundo quero que este *output* `Console.WriteLine(cidade1.casas.dono);` retorna `João`

```
using System;


namespace arrayteste
{

    public class cidade
    {
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public object casas { get; set; }
        public cidade(string nome, object casas)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.casas = casas;
        }
    }
    public class casa
    {
        public string dono { get; set; }
        public string cor { get; set; }
        public casa(string dono, string cor)
        {
            this.dono = dono;
            this.cor = cor;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object[] casas =  new object[2];
            casa casa1 = new casa("João", "verde");
            casa casa2 = new casa("José", "vermelha");
            casas[0] = casa1;
            casas[1] = casa2;
            cidade cidade1 = new cidade("Lisboa", casas[0]);
            cidade cidade2 = new cidade("Porto", casas[1]);


            Console.WriteLine(cidade1.casas.dono); //João

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Quero acessar as propriedades de um objeto que estão dentro de outro objeto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para resolver este problema do jeito que você desenvolveu tem que fazer isto:

```
((casa)(cidade1.casas)).dono
```

O problema é que `casas` é do tipo `object` e ele não possui o membro `dono` por isso não pode ser acessado. Um objeto só pode acessar os membros que são daquele tipo. Você está se embanando com o conceito de herança e polimorfismo e até encapsulamento. Todo objeto em C# deriva de `object` portanto todo objeto de qualquer tipo pode ser guardado nele. Concretamente pode ser de outro tipo já que há relação de subtipo, mas quando acessa ele como `object` só fica visível para você os membros de `object`. Para o código enxergar os outros membros precisa fazer um *cast* para transformar o `object` em `casa`. Aí o membro `dono` fica disponível para uso. Se tentar fazer o *cast* e não for possível porque o tipo não é compatível, ou seja, não é um objeto `casa` dará erro.

Veja a [documentação de `Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)

Eu faria outras modificações. Me parece que a intenção é até outra.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace ArrayTeste {
    public class Cidade {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public Casa Casas { get; set; }
        public Cidade(string nome, Casa casas) {
            Nome = nome;
            Casas = casas;
        }
    }
    public class Casa {
        public string Dono { get; set; }
        public string Cor { get; set; }
        public Casa(string dono, string cor) {
            Dono = dono;
            Cor = cor;
        }

    }
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Casa[] casas =  new Casa[2] {
                new Casa("João", "verde"),
                new Casa("José", "vermelha")
            };
            Cidade cidade1 = new Cidade("Lisboa", casas[0]);
            Cidade cidade2 = new Cidade("Porto", casas[1]);
            WriteLine(cidade1.Casas.Dono);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/S8z0ul). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j9lZix). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/ListElements.cs).

Mas eu acho que você precisa fazer outras coisa. Quase sempre você quer usar uma lista ([`List<>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)) e não um *array*. Ela é mais flexível e atende melhor as necessidades. Esse *array* no código não tem sentido algum, ele não serve para nada e pode ser eliminado.

Mas ao que dá a entender a classe `Cidade` deve ter uma lista de casas dentro dela, então um dos membros deve ser uma lista. No caso seria útil ter um método para adicionar casas. A classe ainda é um pouco ingênua, mas já fica melhor.

Mudei o [padrão de nomenclatura para o que o C# adota](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101). E simplifiquei e modernizei o código. Se é pra aprender aprenda como se faz código real hoje.

Veja:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ListTeste {
    public class Cidade {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public List<Casa> Casas { get; set; } = new List<Casa>();
        public Cidade(string nome, Casa casa) {
            Nome = nome;
            Casas.Add(casa);
        }
        public void NovaCasa(Casa casa) {
            Casas.Add(casa);
        }
    }
    public class Casa {
        public string Dono { get; set; }
        public string Cor { get; set; }
        public Casa(string dono, string cor) {
            Dono = dono;
            Cor = cor;
        }

    }
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            var cidade1 = new Cidade("Lisboa", new Casa("João", "verde"));
            var cidade2 = new Cidade("Porto", new Casa("José", "vermelha"));
            cidade1.NovaCasa(new Casa("Joaquim", "azul"));
            WriteLine(cidade1.Casas[0].Dono);
            WriteLine(cidade1.Casas[1].Dono);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7bUygn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JFWZ4e). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ListElements.cs).

Comment: quero acessar as propriedades de um objecto que estão dentro de outro objecto. seria isso mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Você está tentando acessar a propriedade `casas` em um `object`, esta propriedade não existe em `object`.

Você pode fazer um *cast*

```
Console.WriteLine(((casa)(cidade1.casas)).dono).
```

Mas o correto é você alterar suas classes para não usar `object` e sim usar o nome da classe corretamente.

Claro que é possível usar `object` e ficar fazendo *casts* pra lá e pra cá, mas creio que não é isso que você deseja. Não é errado, mas é bem provável que dê problemas, sem contar que fazer isto sem motivo especifico é usar incorretamente o mecanismo.

Outra coisa importante é a nomenclatura e o estilo de codificar, acho importante seguir o padrão adotado pelo C#. [Veja mais sobre isso nesta pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/18246)

Seu código deveria ser como está abaixo, [veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PG9TU2):

```
using System;   

namespace arrayteste
{    
    public class cidade
    {
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public casa casas { get; set; }
        public cidade(string nome, casa casas)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.casas = casas;
        }
    }

    public class casa
    {
        public string dono { get; set; }
        public string cor { get; set; }
        public casa(string dono, string cor)
        {
            this.dono = dono;
            this.cor = cor;
        }

    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            casa[] casas =  new casa[2];
            casa casa1 = new casa("João", "verde");
            casa casa2 = new casa("José", "vermelha");
            casas[0] = casa1;
            casas[1] = casa2;
            cidade cidade1 = new cidade("Lisboa", casas[0]);
            cidade cidade2 = new cidade("Porto", casas[1]);


            Console.WriteLine(cidade1.casas.dono); //João


        }
    }
}
```