# Não encontra o parameter passado para o comando insert

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em ASP.NET e estou querendo inserir dados em uma tabela no banco de dados, mas ao especificar o `parameter` apresenta o seguinte erro na linha do `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", this._codigo);`:

> Cliente não contem definição para "_codigo", não foi possivel encontrar nenhuma metodo de extensão "_codigo" que aceite um argumento do tipo Cliente

```
   public partial class Cliente : IDisposable
    {

    public Cliente()
    {


    }

 public void gravar() {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|C:\Users\Antonio Viana\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Loja\Eccomerce\App_Data\dados.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText= "Insert Into Cliente (codigo,nome,email,sexo,estado,senha,data,celular,cpf,cidade,cep,confirmar, rua,numero,bairro,uf,login,telefone) values(@codigo,@nome,@email,@sexo,@estado,@senha,@data,@celular,@cpf,@cidade,@cep,@confirmar,@rua,@numero,@bairro,@uf,@login,@telefone)";
                cmd.Connection = cn;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", this._codigo);

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }

            }

        }

    }
    }

    public partial class Cliente
    {

    private int _codigo;
    public int Codigo
    {

        get { return _codigo; }//busca o valor do codigo
        set {
            if(value<0)
            {
                throw new Eccomerce.Excecoes.ValidacaoException("O codigo do 
           cliente não pode ser negativo");
                _codigo = 0;
            }

            _codigo = value; }
       }



    private String _nome;
    public String Nome
    {

        get { return _nome; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length<=10)
            {
                throw new Eccomerce.Excecoes.ValidacaoException("O nome deve ter no minimo 3 10 caracteres");
                _nome = value;
            }


        }
    }


    public String email { get; set; }
    public String sexo { get; set; }
    public String estado { get; set; }
    public String senha { get; set; }
    public String data { get; set; }
    public String celular { get; set; }
    public String cpf { get; set; }
    public String cidade { get; set; }
    public String cep { get; set; }
    public String confirmar { get; set; }
    public String rua { get; set; }
    public String numero { get; set; }
    public String bairro { get; set; }
    public String uf { get; set; }
    public String login { get; set; }
    public String telefone { get; set; }

}
```

Hierarquia do projeto

[image: Projeto]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código é muito confuso e até o compilador não está entendendo, tente fazer isso:

```
public class Cliente {
    public Cliente() {} //tem certeza que quer impedir a construção?

    public void gravar() {
        var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|C:\Users\Antonio Viana\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Loja\Eccomerce\App_Data\dados.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        cn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText= "Insert Into Cliente (codigo,nome,email,sexo,estado,senha,data,celular,cpf,cidade,cep,confirmar, rua,numero,bairro,uf,login,telefone) values(@codigo,@nome,@email,@sexo,@estado,@senha,@data,@celular,@cpf,@cidade,@cep,@confirmar,@rua,@numero,@bairro,@uf,@login,@telefone)";
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", this._codigo);
            //... aqui terá os outros campos, certo?
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    private int _codigo;
    public int Codigo {
        get { return _codigo; }
        set {
            if (value < 0) {
                throw new Eccomerce.Excecoes.ValidacaoException("O codigo do cliente não pode ser negativo"); //vai lançar exceção mesmo?
                _codigo = 0;
            }
            _codigo = value;
        }
    }
    private String _nome;
    public String Nome 
        get { return _nome; }
        set {
            if (value.Length <= 10) {
                throw new Eccomerce.Excecoes.ValidacaoException("O nome deve ter no minimo 3 10 caracteres");
                _nome = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String sexo { get; set; }
    public String estado { get; set; }
    public String senha { get; set; }
    public String data { get; set; }
    public String celular { get; set; }
    public String cpf { get; set; }
    public String cidade { get; set; }
    public String cep { get; set; }
    public String confirmar { get; set; }
    public String rua { get; set; }
    public String numero { get; set; }
    public String bairro { get; set; }
    public String uf { get; set; }
    public String login { get; set; }
    public String telefone { get; set; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Validation.cs).

Se não for isto, há problemas na configuração do projeto para compilação.

Dei uma boa limpada, tirando coisas desnecessárias como a `IDisposable`, captura de exceção que nada faz, mas poderia ter melhoro outras coisas. Eliminei a classe parcial que não vi vantagem alguma nela. Só use o que sabe usar e tenha uma boa explicação para usar.

Seria interessante manter um padrão. Pra que usar `_codigo`, se `codigo` já basta. Isto não costuma ser indicado como [nomenclatura em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Porque a propriedade `Codigo` está em maiúscula, e deve ser assim mesmo, e `email` está em minúscula? Seja consistente.

Answer (score 2):

Tem muito "oportunidades de melhorias" em seu código.

## Partial Classe

O que tem no `ClientDAO`?
Por que vc criou um `class partial Cliente`? Qual motivação?
Se fosse uma abstrata, pois vc pode ter vários tipos de clientes, sim, mas `partial`? Acho que não é esse o caminho que vc gostaria de seguir.

## Try..Catch

Se nada serve fazer isso:

```
try
{
    // codigo
}
catch (Exception) // nada está sendo capturado aqui
{
    throw; // a exceção não está sendo tratada, apenas jogada.
}
```

Se for para fazer isso, deixe apenas o código, que se der exceção, essa irá fazer o *bubble up* nativamente.

## Repositorio - DAO

Nao misture responsabilidade. Sua entidade `Cliente` não deve conhecer banco de dados. Faça apenas:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string Login {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    // outras propriedades
}
```

E um repositorio - antigamente conhecida como DAO - que irá tratar de persistir e recuperar dados do seu cliente.

```
public class ClienteRepositorio
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public ClienteRepositorio(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public void Gravar(Cliente cliente)
    {
        using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) 
        {
            cmd.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Cliente (...) VALUES (...)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", this._codigo);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }            
    } 
}
```

## Mau uso do IDisposable

Se utiliza IDisposable quando é importante realizar operação quando seu objeto for destruído. Exemplo: Antes de destruir um objeto de conexão, vc deve garantir que a conexão está fechada.

No código que postou, tem o IDisposable, mas não tem a implementação do método `Dispose()`, então assumo que está faltando algo.

## Objeto não contém definição para "name",

Considerando que sua query possui vários parâmetros, mas no exemplo somente postou um, entendo que tenha não publicado todos afim de não criar uma pergunta "poluída", mas acredito que o causador do problema está nos outros parâmetros - muito provavelmente um erro de digitação.