# Método genérico para localizar um valor específico em vários tipos de estruturas similares

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos

```
public enum EXEMPLOENUMERADOR1  { blablabla1, blablabla2 }

public enum EXEMPLOENUMERADOR2 { blablabla3, blablabla4, blablabla5}

public enum EXEMPLOENUMERADOR3 { blablabla6, blablabla7, blablabla8, blablabla9 }


public class ClasseExemplo01 {
    public EXEMPLOENUMERADOR1 exEnum;
    public int level = 1;
}

public class ClasseExemplo02 {
    public EXEMPLOENUMERADOR2 exEnum;
    public int level = 1;
}

public class ClasseExemplo03 {
    public EXEMPLOENUMERADOR3 exEnum;
    public int level = 1;
}
```

Com essas estruturas acima estou fazendo hoje métodos específicos para cada uma afim de localizar um valor especifico dentro da estrutura delas e me retornar o objeto em si da instancia dessa estrutura especifica, por exemplo:

```
//Essas variaveis estão no escopo da minha classe que eu to usando o metodo abaixo...
private List<ClasseExemplo01> listinhaGlobal;
private ClasseExemplo01 instanciaDeExemplo01;

private ClasseExemplo01 GetInformation()
    {
        foreach(ClasseExemplo01 item in listinhaGlobal)
        {
            if (item.exEnum.Equals(instanciaDeExemplo01.exEnum))
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Este método é especifico demais, eu não consigo reutilizar o mesmo para todos os tipos de classes e `enumerators` diferentes.

Como eu posso criar um método genérico que acesse e compare valores de várias estruturas similares?

Comment: Se eu entendi sua pergunta, você tem que usar um pouco de lógica, por exemplo: o que as 3 classes tem em comum? um atributo inteiro, ou seja.. o método "genérico" processaria as informações que recebe por parâmetro e retornaria este tipo de dado.

Comment: Seria bom colocar outras partes do código para podermos ajudar melhor. De qualquer forma é um código muito esquisito e nem parece C#.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente é isso que deseja:

```
public class Exemplo<T> {
    private List<T> listinhaGlobal;
    private T instanciaDeExemplo;
    private T GetInformation() {
        foreach(var item in listinhaGlobal) {
            if (item.exEnum == instanciaDeExemplo.exEnum)) {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/ClassDefinition.cs).

Aí vai instanciar por exemplo como

```
var objeto = new Exemplo<ClasseExemplo01>();
```

Ainda assim este código está muito esquisito e acho que não está ajudando muito. Duvido que precise fazer desta forma.

Seria bom dar uma lida no [padrão de nomenclatura de C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Acho que vem de C# e seria bom eliminar os vícios dela, principalmente não use tudo caixa alta em nomes.