# Como organizar namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, estilo-de-codificação, namespace, organização-de-projeto

Ouvi que namespaces deveriam ser organizados por camada, no caso, se utilizando algum *design pattern* que possibilite, como `Projeto.Controller`, `Projeto.UI`, `Projeto.Model`, porém, se olharmos os namespaces do próprio .NET Framework, eles não são organizados dessa forma:

- `System.NET`
- `System.IO`
- `Microsoft.Media`
- `System.Security.Crypography`

Existem convenções ou regras para organização de namespaces dentro de um projeto .NET?

Quais são as melhores práticas na definição de namespaces?

Os namespaces deveriam seguir a estrutura de pastas do projeto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como definir exatamente não sei se dá para dizer, acho meio aberto, depende do projeto. O que dá para fazer é ter algumas convenções de nomes. A Microsoft [documentou isso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas nada impede das pessoas usarem outras convenções. Note que é uma recomendação que nem sempre faz sentido para quem não está desenvolvendo o próprio .NET.

Um resumo:

- Prefixe com o nome da organização detentora do projeto. Só não vai colocar o domínio todo como alguns guias dizem para fazer. Tente ser simples. E não tem caso que dá para não usar isto.
- Use o nome do produto no segundo nível do nome, sem incluir variações, tem que ser algo que sempre será chamado assim. Eu acho que há casos que isso pode ir para o primeiro nível, mas precisa ser bem pensado e não é uma recomendação oficial.
- Não crie hierarquias dentro de uma organização (empresa) e sim em cima de tecnologias estáveis.
- Use o PascalCase e não o ponto para separar palavras que devem estar no mesmo nível.
- Prefira o plural sempre que fizer sentido (não vejo isso sendo tão usado na prática, tem tantas exceções que complica seguir a recomendação, tem que ir no "bom senso").
- Não use um nome de um tipo existente dentro dele.
- Evite nomes muitos genéricos, tente ser mais específico sobre o que é aquilo, mesmo que tenha que usar nomes compostos de mais palavras, qualifique o substantivo.

Uma parte disso já está em [Padrão de nomenclatura no código para o C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101).

Algumas coisas não ligadas ao nome e sim à organização são mais complicadas de seguir, nem sempre temos toda visão clara e disponível.

- Evite colocar tipos de mesmo nome que podem ser usados em conjunto e gerar conflitos. Deixe nomes iguais para tecnologias que acabam sendo excludentes entre si. Claro que existem exceções, principalmente quando o uso ocorre em contextos específicos.
- Evite nomes de tipos comuns no .NET.
- Evite nomes que possam conflitar com outras partes da mesma tecnologia. Este é um dos motivos que eu acho que não se deve criar muitos *namespaces*.

Não que não possa, mas acho estranho usar a mesma estrutura de pastas para a organização do *namespace*. Em geral são tipos de organização diferentes. Acima mostra que não é bem por aí. Você não deve ter conflitos dentro das camadas da mesma solução. Frequentemente terá uma duplicidade de nome pelo menos parcial no tipo e no *namespace*. Claro que tem um pouco de gosto, se quer fazer assim mantenha sempre desta forma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).