# Construtor padrão para calcular o salário anual de um funcionário em C#

Tags: c#, método, construtor

Preciso fazer um código que calcule o salário anual (`float`) a partir dos meses trabalhados (`int`) e salário mensal (`float`), mas tem que ser utilizando o método construtor.

Aqui vai um código que eu fiz mas está retornando 0 para o valor do salário anual:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SalarioAnual
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculo c = new Calculo();
            Console.Write("Informe o numero de meses trabalhados: ");
            c.Meses = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Informe o salário mensal: ");
            c.Salario = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("O salário anual é: " + c.SalarioAnual);
        }
    }
}
```

E aqui a classe `Cálculo`, com os atributos no método construtor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SalarioAnual
{
    class Calculo
    {
        int _Meses;
        float _Salario;
        float _SalarioAnual;

        public int Meses
        {
            set { _Meses = value; }
            get { return _Meses; }
        }

        public float Salario
        {
            set { _Salario = value; }
            get { return _Salario; }
        }

        public float SalarioAnual
        {
            set { _SalarioAnual = _Meses * _Salario; }
            get { return _SalarioAnual; }
        }
    }
}
```

Um novo código usando um construtor:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace SalarioAnual {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            int Meses;
            float Salario;

            Write("Informe o numero de meses trabalhados: ");
            Meses = int.Parse(ReadLine());

            Write("Informe o salário mensal: ");
            Salario = float.Parse(ReadLine());

            var c = new Calculo(Meses, Salario);

            WriteLine("O salário anual é: " + c.SalarioAnual);
        }

        public class Calculo
        {
            float _SalarioAnual;

            public Calculo(int meses, float salario)
            {
                _SalarioAnual = meses * salario;
            }

            public float SalarioAnual
            { get { return _SalarioAnual; } }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @guilherme bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor edite sua pergunta para tornar-la mais clara pois não é possível entender bem o seu problema, sugiro que visite https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Guilherme, você pode dar uma lida ( https://www.dotnetperls.com/constructor ) e reformular sua pergunta para que possamos ajuda-lo.

Comment: Só aguardando a aprovação para lhe mandar o código amigo, mas é coisa simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema, depois da edição, não parece ter nada a ver com [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). O código tem alguns problemas.

Tem coisas que não são usadas e usa coisas antigas que não é mais assim que se programa em C#. [Usar `float` para valor monetário que é um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Lê um dado externo sem validar, o que pode quebrar a aplicação (eu só encerrei, mas você pode fazer o tratamento que quiser se for inválido), o correto é usar o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). E usei os [padrões de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101).

Imagino que o que queria é que o salário anual fosse calculado automaticamente quando solicitado sem que tenha que preencher e que ele teria uma fórmula que é a quantidade de meses multiplicada pelo salário simples. Se for só isto basta usar um método *getter* na propriedade que faz esta conta, então ele sempre será calculado. As outras propriedades podem ser simples e não precisam fazer nada extra.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace SalarioAnual {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            var c = new Calculo();
            Write("Informe o numero de meses trabalhados: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var meses)) return;
            c.Meses = meses;
            Write("Informe o salário mensal: ");
            if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var salario)) return;
            c.Salario = salario;
            WriteLine($"O salário anual é: {c.SalarioAnual}");
        }
    }
    public class Calculo {
        private decimal salarioAnual;
        public int Meses { get; set; }
        public decimal Salario { get; set; }
        public decimal SalarioAnual => Meses * Salario;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xa3A24). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5FgFI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/ExampleSalary.cs).

Se for usar um construtor como foi colocado na edição da pergunta causa outro problema já que aí não será mais uma propriedade que calcula o salário anual automaticamente, o que não parece ser o caso. E não estará usando um construtor padrão que é só aquele sem parâmetros:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace SalarioAnual {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            Write("Informe o numero de meses trabalhados: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var meses)) return;
            Write("Informe o salário mensal: ");
            if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var salario)) return;
            var c = new Calculo(meses, salario);
            WriteLine($"O salário anual é: {c.SalarioAnual}");
        }
    }

    public class Calculo {
        public Calculo(int meses, decimal salario) {
            Meses = meses;
            Salario = salario;
            SalarioAnual = meses * salario;
        }
        private decimal salarioAnual;
        public int Meses { get; set; }
        public decimal Salario { get; set; }
        public decimal SalarioAnual { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MxqKgZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2woPd4). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ConstructorInitialization.cs).

Finalmente se deve calcular algo sem passar argumentos então usará valores padrões de cálculo, é mais um conceito errado, mas se insistir nisso não precisa criar um construtor padrão, apenas usará um e basta criar a inicialização padrão de propriedade:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace SalarioAnual {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            var c = new Calculo();
            WriteLine($"O salário anual é: {c.SalarioAnual}");
        }
    }

    public class Calculo {
        private decimal salarioAnual;
        public int Meses { get; set; } = 12;
        public decimal Salario { get; set; } = 100M;
        public decimal SalarioAnual => Meses * Salario;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MTEkMz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AnqJBd). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/PropertyInitialization.cs).

Mas quero deixar claro que a primeira é a solução correta.

Um último detalhe: [o que chama atributo na verdade é um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Quase todo mundo fala errado e assim todo mundo ensina errado.

Comment: Entendi, porém ainda tenho uma dúvida, estou criando este código para atender uma questão, e esta questão pede o seguinte:
'Desenvolva um código em C# utilizando o construtor padrão para calcular o salário anual de um funcionário, que deve ter como base o salário mensal e quantidade de meses trabalhados.'
Neste código que vc me passou (Ficou muito bom mesmo!) está sendo usado este construtor padrão?

Comment: Não, é que por essa descrição não diz como deve fazer, tem várias formas, não dá para saber só com isto. Na verdade com esta descrição nem sei sentido, e se fizer seria com um código bem diferente do que você fez.

Comment: Hum, certo, acho que vou perguntar ao meu tutor mais informações sobre a questão, para finalizar, fiz um código antes de ver a sua resposta em que o método construtor da classe Calculo recebe as variáveis como parâmetro, funcionou, mas queria saber se bateria com a descrição da questão: 
Vou editar minha pergunta com este código para vc analisar.

Comment: O problema é que você falou de um construtor padrão na pergunta. Como calcular um algo com a criação de objeto que não recebe parâmetros? Só se for um valor fixo, mas ficaria muito esquisito. Me parece que a questão não foi muito bem pensada.

Comment: Sim, também achei, mas editei a pergunta com um código onde o construtor recebe os parâmetros de meses e salário, depois vou adaptar ele para as modificações que vc fez no outro e enviar ao meu tutor.

Comment: @GuilhermeVanzAguirres O problema que editando com novo conteúdo invalida a resposta. mas eu melhorei a resposta. Você pode votar em tudo no site também, além de aceitar uma resposta. Veja o [tour].