# Voltar para menu anterior

Tags: c#, loop, controle-de-fluxo

Eu estou tentando adicionar um "Voltar" de um menu para o outro, primeiramente tentei usar o `do` só no 2o. menu para voltar ao primeiro, porém ele só fecha.

Segue o código inteiro:

```
namespace ConsoleApp10
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int menu;

                Console.WriteLine("1 - Conversões");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Medias");
                Console.WriteLine("0 - Sair");
                Console.WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: ");

                while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu)))
                {
                    Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: ");
                }
                switch (menu)
                {
                    case 2: media(); break;
                    case 1: conversoes(); break;
                    case 0: Console.WriteLine("Finalizando..."); break;
                    default: Console.WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break;
                }
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            static void media()
            {
            Console.Clear();

            int menu1;
            do // O PROBLEMA ESTÁ AQUI
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Média Aritmetica");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Média Ponderada");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Voltar");
                Console.WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: ");
                    menu1 = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine());

                    switch (menu1)
                    {
                        case 1: mediaari(); break;
                        case 2: mediapon(); break;
                        case 3: break;
                        default: Console.WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break;
                    }
            }
            while (false);
            }
            static void mediaari()
            {
            Console.Clear();
            int n1, n2, n3, n4;
                int soma, div;

                Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 1: ");
                n1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 2: ");
                n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 3: ");
                n3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 4: ");
                n4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                soma = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;
                div = soma / 4;
                Console.WriteLine("A média é: " + div);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            static void mediapon()
            {
            Console.Clear();
            int n1, n2, n3;
                int p1, p2, p3;
                int soma;

                Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 1: ");
                n1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite o peso 1: ");
                p1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 2: ");
                n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite o peso 2: ");
                p2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 3: ");
                n3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Digite o peso 3: ");
                p3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                soma = (n1 * p1 + n2 * p2) / (p1 + p2);

                Console.WriteLine("A média é: " + soma);
            }
            static void conversoes()
            {
            Console.Clear();
            int menu2;

                Console.WriteLine("1 - Temperatua");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Moeda");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Voltar");
                Console.WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: ");

                while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu2)))
                {
                    Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: ");
                }
                switch (menu2)
                {
                    case 1: temp(); break;
                    case 2:; break;
                    case 0: Console.WriteLine("Finalizando..."); break;
                    default: Console.WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break;
                }

            }
            static void temp()
            {
            Console.Clear();
            int menu2;

                Console.WriteLine("1 - °F -> °C");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - °C -> °F");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Voltar");
                Console.WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: ");

                while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu2)))
                {
                    Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: ");
                }
                switch (menu2)
                {
                    case 1: fc(); break;
                    case 2:; break;
                    case 0: Console.WriteLine("Finalizando..."); break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break;

                }
            }
            static void fc()
            {
            Console.Clear();
            int f, c;

                Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor em °F: ");
                f = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
                Console.WriteLine("A conversão é igual a: " + c);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Na opção 3 você quer que volte para a função chamadora do menu principal então não pode só sair do `switch` como está fazendo, tem que sair da função inteira com `return`.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApp10 {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            while (true) {
                WriteLine("1 - Conversões");
                WriteLine("2 - Medias");
                WriteLine("0 - Sair");
                WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: ");
                int menu;
                while (!(int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out menu))) Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: ");
                switch (menu) {
                    case 2: media(); break;
                    case 1: break;
                    case 0: WriteLine("Finalizando..."); return;
                    default: WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break;
                }
            }
        }
        static void media() {
            while (true) {
                WriteLine("1 - Média Aritmetica");
                WriteLine("2 - Média Ponderada");
                WriteLine("3 - Voltar");
                WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: ");
                int menu;
                while (!(int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out menu))) Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: ");
                switch (menu) {
                    case 1: break;
                    case 2: break;
                    case 3: return;
                    default: WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/343722/101). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WAnrs3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnInSwitch.cs).

Note que melhorei mais algumas coisas. Seu código pode ser bem mais simples, moderno e até correto. Se tratou o erro na digitação corretamente no primeiro menu, porque fez errado no segundo? Porque fez errado na entrada de dados? A entrada de dados precisa ser validada da mesma forma, não faz sentido começar certo e depois fazer errado.

Pelo que percebo não está entendendo o que o código faz e isso pode ser um problema. Sempre que vejo isso sugiro que comece por coisas mais simples, provavelmente está fazendo algo que ainda não aprendeu e isto não costuma ser bom para o aprendizado.

Seu código até está melhor do que a gente vê em novatos, mas pode ser melhor. Um exemplo é tentar usar nomes diferentes de variáveis que fazem a mesma coisa em funções diferentes. Os nomes dos métodos não seguem o [padrão de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Não tem porque declarar a variável para usa só lá na frente. Só complica a legibilidade do código, ou até criar variável onde não precisa. preste bastante atenção ao que eu mudei no código, o resto fica por sua conta melhorar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas infelismente, o seu código não funcionou, ele apenar fecha ao invés de voltar ao menu, eu atualizei meu código e agora está funcional, 100% funcional, vou postar abaixo

Comment: Me desculpe, não havia ficado claro que queria isso também, mas é só copiar a lógica de um para o outro, por isso reforço que está fazendo algo mais complexo do que você é capaz nesse momento. Vou mudar então.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int menu; do
            {
                Console.Clear(); Console.WriteLine("=======MENU======="); Console.WriteLine("1 - Médias"); Console.WriteLine("2 - Conversões"); Console.WriteLine("3 - Sair"); Console.WriteLine("=================="); Console.WriteLine("Escolha sua opção: "); while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu)))
                { Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: "); }
                switch (menu)
                { case 1: media(); break; case 2: conversoes(); break; case 3: break; default: Console.WriteLine("Opção inválida, tente outra vez"); break; }
            }
            while (menu != 3);
        }
        static void media()
        {
            int menu; do
            {
                Console.Clear(); Console.WriteLine("1 - Media Aritmética"); Console.WriteLine("2 - Média Ponderada"); Console.WriteLine("3 - Voltar"); Console.WriteLine("Escolha sua opção: "); while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu)))
                { Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: "); }
                switch (menu)
                { case 1: mediaari(); break; case 2: mediapon(); break; case 3: break; default: Console.WriteLine("Opção inválida, tente outra vez"); break; }
            }
            while (menu != 3);
        }
        static void mediaari()
        { Console.Clear(); double n1, n2, n3, n4; double sd; Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 1: "); n1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 2: "); n2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 3: "); n3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 4: "); n4 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); sd = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4; Console.WriteLine("A média é: " + sd); Console.ReadKey(); }
        static void mediapon()
        { Console.Clear(); double n1, n2, n3; double soma; Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 1: "); n1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 2: "); n2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite a nota 3: "); n3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); soma = (n1 * 2 + n2 * 3 + n3 * 5) / (2 + 3 + 5); Console.WriteLine("A média é: " + soma); Console.ReadKey(); }
        static void conversoes()
        {
            Console.Clear(); int menu; do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Temperatua"); Console.WriteLine("2 - Moeda"); Console.WriteLine("3 - Voltar"); Console.WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: "); while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu)))
                { Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: "); }
                switch (menu)
                { case 1: temp(); break; case 2: moeda(); break; case 3: break; default: Console.WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break; }
            }
            while (menu != 3);
        }
        static void temp()
        {
            Console.Clear(); int menu; do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 - °F -> °C"); Console.WriteLine("2 - °C -> °F"); Console.WriteLine("3 - Voltar"); Console.WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: "); while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu)))
                { Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: "); }
                switch (menu)
                { case 1: fc(); break; case 2: cf(); break; case 3: break; default: Console.WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break; }
                Console.Clear();
            }
            while (menu != 3);
        }
        static void fc()
        { Console.Clear(); double f, c; Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor em °F: "); f = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9; Console.WriteLine("A conversão é igual a: " + c); Console.ReadKey(); }
        static void cf()
        { Console.Clear(); double c, f; Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor em °C: "); c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); f = (c * 9) / 5 + 32; Console.WriteLine("A conversão é igual a: " + f); Console.ReadKey(); }
        static void moeda()
        {
            Console.Clear(); int menu; do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Real -> Dólar"); Console.WriteLine("2 - Real -> Euro"); Console.WriteLine("3 - Real -> Libra"); Console.WriteLine("4 - Voltar"); Console.WriteLine("Escolha o que deseja fazer: "); while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu)))
                { Console.Write("Opção não numerica, digite novamente: "); }
                switch (menu)
                { case 1: rd(); break; case 2: re(); break; case 3: rl(); break; case 4: break; default: Console.WriteLine("Nós não temos esta opção, escolhe novamente:"); break; }
                Console.Clear();
            }
            while (menu != 4);
        }
        static void rd()
        { Console.Clear(); double r, d, c; Console.WriteLine("Digite a cota do dia atual: "); c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor em Reais: "); r = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); d = r * c; Console.WriteLine("A conversão é igual a: " + d); Console.ReadKey(); }
        static void re()
        { Console.Clear(); double r, e, c; Console.WriteLine("Digite a cota do dia atual: "); c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor em Reais: "); r = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); e = r * c; Console.WriteLine("A conversão é igual a: " + e); Console.ReadKey(); }
        static void rl()
        { Console.Clear(); double r, l, c; Console.WriteLine("Digite a cota do dia atual: "); c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor em Reais: "); r = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); l = c * r; Console.WriteLine("A conversão é igual a: " + l); Console.ReadKey(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: esse post deveria ser uma edição à pergunta?

Comment: não, é so o código ja funcionando kk, para verem como resolvi

Comment: Jaum evite só comentar com código, explique também como você chegou nesta solução 