# Item da lista para varivel em loop C#

Tags: c#

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer um `for` ou `foreach` numa lista e dentro desta eu criar variaveis para os itens do meu obj

EXEMPLO:

```
public class Pessoa
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Nome1 {get;set;}
   public string Nome2 {get;set;}

   public List<Pessoa> lstPessoa{get;set;}
}

foreach (var item in lstPessoa)
{   
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // GOSTARIA DE SABER SE É POSSIVEL, DE ALGUMA MANEIRA, FAZER ISSO
        var exemplo = "item.Nome"+i; 

        mtdSalvarBanco(exemplo);
        cont++;
    }
}
```

> Nome1 = Joao
>
> Nome2 = Maria

`var exemplo =  "item.Nome"+i;`

`i = 1` > `exemplo = Joao`

`i = 2` > `exemplo = Maria`

diferente de

`var exemplo1 = item.Nome1;`

`var exemplo2 = item.Nome2;`

`exemplo1 = Joao`

`exemplo2 = Maria`

Não tem mais o que eu possa dizer, é só essa minha duvida... Não sei como escrever de outra forma

Comment: O difícil é a gente entender o que quer fazer, e se está tendo alguma dificuldade com o que está fazendo, ou se o que fez não te atende. Explique melhor para podermos ajudar. Talvez nem precise disso e ainda não sabe.

Comment: eu tenho um objeto com 20 campos "iguais", neste exemplo seria `Nome1` e `Nome2`, e eu preciso salvar no banco cada um deles.. A minha pergunta é se existe alguma forma, de com um contador por exemplo, eu passar o valor de cada item deste meu objeto para uma variavel, para que eu possa usa-la depois..

Comment: é q eu fiz rapido e esta sem sentido, vou dar uma melhorada

Comment: acho q agora esta um pouco melhor

Comment: Ainda não dá para saber o que quer ou que problema está tendo. Você tem que dizer isto. Na verdade piorou. O código está todo largado, sem sentido e sem explicação.

Comment: @Maniero, eu entendi que ele quer pegar os valores de `Nome1` e `Nome2` dinamicamente com um `for`, como se fosse em javascript um `item["Nome" + i]`. Pra mim ficou bem claro depois das edições do autor.

Comment: @Francisco não tenho certeza, mas se for isso precisa ser colocado na pergunta de forma clara, porque senão cada um interpreta como quiser e cada um tem uma solução, como eu acabei fazendo e errei. O que eu entendi é que nem ele sabe o que ele quer. Se for isso, a solução é simples, não usar o `for`, dá mais trabalho e custa mais caro fazer assim do que pegar cada um deles. Se o problema dele for outro, o q é altamente improvável (porque até seria um erro conceitual) aí seria o caso de fazer uma agregação.

Comment: Me perdoem por não conseguir me expressar, mas é exatamente o que o @Francisco disse acima.. Eu acho que poucas pessoas tem o conhecimento que você tem 'Mineiro', acredito q eu não chegue a 10% do que você conhece, então gostaria de um pouco mais de respeito sobre a forma com que tem se referido a mim.. Posso ter muita dificuldade de expressão e isso é uma coisa que trato a anos, se você não consegue entender, mesmo eu dizendo algumas vezes que para mim é dificil de exemplificar de outra maneira, então pelo menos tenha respeito em sua fala diante a mim.. Sua fala ofende, me senti 'humilhado'..

Comment: Da mesma forma que você diz que as pessoas interpretam como quiserem, eu interpretei sua fala como desrespeito, então antes de me pedir para melhorar o meu codigo, melhore a forma com que você fala comigo...

Comment: Perdão, eu errei seu nome @Maniero

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é mais ou menos isso que quer:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Pessoa.Lista();
    }
}

public class Pessoa {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome1 { get; set; }
    public string Nome2 { get; set; }
    public static List<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; } = new List<Pessoa>();
    public static void Lista() {
        for (var i = 0; i < Pessoas.Count; i++) WriteLine(Pessoas[i].Nome1 + (i + 1).ToString());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xQyj9S). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wd0loQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/AccessRaw.cs).

Tem vários erros neste código.

Se você contar os itens a melhor forma é usar um `for` bruto, mas não o `foreach`, não faz sentido usam ambos. Então vai do índice 0 até o contador de elementos da lista que é a propriedade [`Count`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Se vai acessar cada item e criar uma *string*, não coloque dentro das aspas porque aí vira texto e você quer que seja código. Você tem que pegar o número do contador e transformá-lo em *string*, mas como a lista começa do 0, você deve somar 1, não esquecendo de ser entre parênteses pra que o `ToString()` aplique à soma e não ao `1` apenas.

Ainda há um erro conceitual. Porque uma pessoa tem pessoas dentro dela? Isso não faz sentido, deveria estar em outro lugar. Mas para não mudar demais resolvido pelo menos os problemas mais graves. Transformei isso em um membro estático, então ele passa ser parte da classe e não da instância, então pelo menos agora você tem a lista uma única vez na aplicação toda e não uma lista para cada pessoa que criar.

Também precisa inicializar a lista, do jeito que estava ia dar erro no primeiro acesso a ela. Também mudei o nome para atender a [nomenclatura normalmente adotada em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101).

Aproveitei e modernizei e formatei o código melhor.

A impressão que dá é que está com dificuldade bem básicas, portanto minha sugestão é ainda se concentrar em aspectos mais básicos da linguagem antes de se aventurar em coisas mais complexas. Construa seu conhecimento um passo de cada vez sem pular nada, sem deixar nada para trás, aí vai aproveitar muito mais e entender o que está fazendo.

Comment: não é isso que eu quero, é complicado eu não consigo explicar de outra forma,  vou tentar, mas adotando que sou leigo, tente entender de uma forma leiga.. Eu quero fazer um loop para um item do meu objeto dinamicamente, pois atualmente estou fazendo um bloco repetir 20 vezes entenda: 
var exemplo = item.Nome1; var exemplo = item.Nome2; var exemplo = item.Nome3; var exemplo = item.Nome4; var exemplo = item.Nome5;
porem eu gostaria de fazer um unico bloco e que passasse em todas esses itens (que estao numa lista)

Comment: @Leooso crie outra lista assim: public `List<string> Nomes = new List<string>();`. E faça um foreach dentro desta lista, sempre que existir um nome, você vai iterar sobre ele. E basta usar `Nomes.Add("NOVO NOME");` para adicionar um novo

Comment: Nossa, é verdade... eu tenho esse problema, eu torno as coisas simples em complicadas, sendo q se eu começasse a pensar pelo simples eu resolveria.... Vou tentar aqui e te passo um feedback do resultado, obrigado