# Quantas classes eu posso colocar em um mesmo código?

Tags: c#, classes, namespace

Quantas "classes" eu consigo adicionar no meu código?

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte bloco de comando existente:

```
namespace _06_ByteBank
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        private string _cpf;

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF
    {
        get
        {
            return _cpf;
        }
        set
        {
            // Escrevo minha lógica de validação de CPF
            _cpf = value;
        }
    }
    public string Profissao { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Para adicionar outra "classe" eu escreveria embaixo deste bloco ou dentro dele?

Comment: Não conheço nada que limite colocar duas classes no mesmo `namespace`, nem de usar múltiplos `namespace`s no mesmo arquivo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tantas quantas quiser. Não há um limite teórico. Posso te garantir que você terá outros problemas antes de alcançar qualquer limite técnico (que será mais por limite de memória disponível para o compilador, e já temos muito).

O problema é que está pensando do modo errado. Você deve aprender organizar código. Entender o problema e fazer o código mais adequado possível para resolvê-lo. Aprender isso demora muito tempo, precisa de muita dedicação, e é bem mais difícil do que as pessoas imaginam. Fazer de qualquer jeito e botar para funcionar é fácil, escrever código de qualidade e que dure é algo bem mais complicado, e a observação que tenho é que a maioria das pessoas que estão começando ultimamente não estão aprendendo isso porque só querer ver o resultado, não importa como. No longo prazo isso não dá certo.

Você não precisa colocar outra classe aí. Pode criar outro arquivo com a nova classe. Claro, depende do caso, você terá que aprender quando colocar no mesmo arquivo ou não.

Mas se quiser insistir tem que colocar a classe dentro do bloco do `namespace`, digo, provavelmente, é possível colocar fora, mas é improvável que queria isto. Pode até querer criar outro `namespace` fora. Ou até aninhá-los.

Você pode repetir o `namespace`, ele é só um sobrenome. Mesmo em arquivos diferentes todos os tipos que usam o mesmo nome de *namespace* farão parte dele.

Seria legal aprender alguns [padrões de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101) para ir organizando o código.