# Erros no programa para determinar triangulo

Tags: c++

Quais erros estou cometendo?

> Leia 3 valores de ponto flutuante A, B e C e ordene-os em ordem decrescente, de modo que o lado A representa o maior dos 3 lados. A seguir, determine o tipo de triângulo que estes três lados formam, com base nos seguintes casos, sempre escrevendo uma mensagem adequada:
>
> 1. se A ≥ B+C, apresente a mensagem: NAO FORMA TRIANGULO
>
>    2. se A2 = B2 + C2, apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO RETANGULO
>    3. se A2 > B2 + C2, apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO
>    4. se A2 < B2 + C2, apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO
>    5. se os três lados forem iguais, apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO EQUILATERO
>    6. se apenas dois dos lados forem iguais, apresente a mensagem:
>         TRIANGULO ISOSCELES

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){

        double a=0, b=0, c=0, ValorUm=0, ValorDois=0, ValorTres=0, b2=0, a2=0, c2=0, bc=0, b2c2=0;

//aqui o usuário insere os valores...Usei as variaveis ValorUm...
//para depois inverter para a ordem "a" "b" "c" , os valores tem que
ficar  // em ordem decrecente, o valor maior tem que ser a ..por
 exemplo  //a== 10 , b == 5 , c == 3 do maior para o menor

    cin>>ValorUm>>ValorDois>>ValorTres;


 /*usei os if para inverter as posições, pelo oque testei   o problema
 nao esta nessa parte de trocar as posicoes*/

    if(ValorUm<ValorDois&&ValorDois<ValorTres)  {
        c=ValorUm;
        b=ValorDois;
        a=ValorTres;
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorUm>ValorDois&&ValorDois>ValorTres){
        a=ValorUm;
        b=ValorDois;
        c=ValorTres;
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorDois>ValorUm&&ValorTres<ValorDois&&ValorTres<ValorUm){     
        a=ValorDois;
        b=ValorUm;
        c=ValorTres;    
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorUm>ValorDois&&ValorUm<ValorTres){
        a=ValorTres;
        b=ValorUm;
        c=ValorDois;
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorUm>ValorDois&&ValorTres<ValorUm&&ValorDois<ValorTres){
        a=ValorUm;
        b=ValorTres;
        c=ValorDois;cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }
    bc=b+c; 
    a2=a*a;
    b2=b*b;
    c2=c*c;
    b2c2=b2+c2;
    /*até onde sei é aqui , que está o problema o TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO
    e o TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO está com diversos erros*/
//a2 a*a b2 c2...  b2c2 é b2+c2 e bc é b+c

        if (ValorUm>ValorDois+ValorTres || ValorUm==ValorDois+ValorTres){
          cout<<"NAO FORMA TRIANGULO"<<endl;

        }
        else
        if(a2==b2c2)
        {
          cout<<"TRIANGULO RETANGULO"<<endl;
        }
        if(a2>b2c2){
          cout<<"TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO"<<endl;

        }
        if(a2 < b2c2){
            cout<<"TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO"<<endl;
     }
     if(a==c && a!=b){
         cout<<"TRIANGULO ISOSCELES"<<endl;
     }
     if(a==b && a!=c){
         cout<<"TRIANGULO ISOSCELES"<<endl;
     }
    if(a == b && a == c ){
        cout<<"TRIANGULO EQUILATERO"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Seu código está muito poluído, poderia simplificar os if e else, mas isto não vem ao caso, executei seu código e me parece tudo ok, qual seria o erro exatamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não fiz nenhuma melhoria no seu código, porém darei algumas dicas para melhorá-lo

O saída, indesejada, que você estava encontrado quando a entrada era:

```
ValorUm=10;
ValorDois=5;
ValorTres=3
```

Saída:

```
NAO FORMA TRIANGULO                                                                                                            
TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO
```

Acontecia pois faltava delimitar o primeiro `else` com chaves

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

        double a=0, b=0, c=0, ValorUm=0, ValorDois=0, ValorTres=0, b2=0, a2=0, c2=0, bc=0, b2c2=0;

//aqui o usuário insere os valores...Usei as variaveis ValorUm...
//para depois inverter para a ordem "a" "b" "c" , os valores tem que
//ficar   em ordem decrecente, o valor maior tem que ser a ..por
// exemplo  //a== 10 , b == 5 , c == 3 do maior para o menor

    cin>>ValorUm>>ValorDois>>ValorTres;


 /*usei os if para inverter as posições, pelo oque testei   o problema
 nao esta nessa parte de trocar as posicoes*/

    if(ValorUm<ValorDois&&ValorDois<ValorTres)  {
        c=ValorUm;
        b=ValorDois;
        a=ValorTres;
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorUm>ValorDois&&ValorDois>ValorTres){
        a=ValorUm;
        b=ValorDois;
        c=ValorTres;
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorDois>ValorUm&&ValorTres<ValorDois&&ValorTres<ValorUm){     
        a=ValorDois;
        b=ValorUm;
        c=ValorTres;    
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorUm>ValorDois&&ValorUm<ValorTres){
        a=ValorTres;
        b=ValorUm;
        c=ValorDois;
        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }if(ValorUm>ValorDois&&ValorTres<ValorUm&&ValorDois<ValorTres){
        a=ValorUm;
        b=ValorTres;
        c=ValorDois;cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl;      
    }
    bc=b+c; 
    a2=a*a;
    b2=b*b;
    c2=c*c;
    b2c2=b2+c2;
    /*até onde sei é aqui , que está o problema o TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO
    e o TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO está com diversos erros*/
//a2 a*a b2 c2...  b2c2 é b2+c2 e bc é b+c

        if ((ValorUm>ValorDois+ValorTres) || (ValorUm==ValorDois+ValorTres)){
          cout<<"NAO FORMA TRIANGULO"<<endl;

        }
        else{ **// FALTAVA ESTÁ CHAVE AQUI**
        if(a2==b2c2)
        {
          cout<<"TRIANGULO RETANGULO"<<endl;
        }
        if(a2>b2c2){
          cout<<"TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO"<<endl;

        }
        if(a2 < b2c2){
            cout<<"TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO"<<endl;
     }
     if(a==c && a!=b){
         cout<<"TRIANGULO ISOSCELES"<<endl;
     }
     if(a==b && a!=c){
         cout<<"TRIANGULO ISOSCELES"<<endl;
     }
    if(a == b && a == c ){
        cout<<"TRIANGULO EQUILATERO"<<endl;
    }
        }**// FALTAVA ESTÁ CHAVE AQUI**
    return 0;
    }
```

Sobre "TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO" é um pequeno erro de lógica, verifique as estruturas de condição `if/else`, pois há alguns `if` sem o seu respectivo `else`, por mais que não seja obrigatório cada `if` possuir seu `else`, é uma boa pratica faze-lo.

Lembre-se das boas práticas de programação do [Deitel](https://www.amazon.com.br/C-como-programar-Paul-Deitel/dp/8576059347/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_img_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=NKB0RF3N8DSJA8T3P6Y9):

> 1. Indentar ambos os comandos do corpo de uma estrutura if/else;
> 2. Se existem vários níveis de indentação, cada nível deve ser
>      indentado pelo mesmo espaço adicional

**DICAS**

1. Por que fazer tantas estruturas de condições if/else? Seu código é
   pequeno, então por agora não terá problemas, mas e no futuro, e se
   tiver que implementar um código com milhares de condicionais, fará
   tantos if/else assim?

Opte fazer assim: ( Em C, pois não te darei o código pronto! :P)

```
if (a < b){ x = a; a = b; b = x; } 
if (b < c){ x = b; b = c; c = x; }
```

2. Veja o quão mais limpo ficará seu código usando o [Operador
   ternário](http://excript.com/cpp/operador-ternario-cpp.html);
3. Ao nomear variáveis evite nomes tais como:  `bc`; `a2`; `c2`; `b2c2`; Dê nomes significativos as variáveis.

Para sanar mais dúvidas, leie esta resposta: [Padrão de nomenclatura no código para o C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/110782)

Fonte:  [Tipos de Triângulos SOLUÇÃO EM C](http://muitomaiscodigoss.blogspot.com/2017/05/uri-problema-1045-tipos-de-triangulos.html)

[Tipos de Triângulos SOLUÇÃO EM PYTHON](http://muitomaiscodigoss.blogspot.com/2018/09/uri-problema-1045-tipos-de-triangulos.html)

Comment: Qual o erro lógico, não encontrei erro? bc=b+c; 
a2=a*a;
b2=b*b;
c2=c*c;
b2c2=b2+c2;

Comment: Cometi um engano, a lógica está certa, o erro é na cascata de if/else, pois há if sem um else respectivo e por sua vez sem delimitação por chaves.

Comment: @cristovanlopes editei a resposta, veja se sanou suas dúvidas

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    double a=0, b=0, c=0, x=0;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
if (a < b){ x = a; a = b; b = x; } 
if (b < c){ x = b; b = c; c = x; }  
if (a < b){ x = a; a = b; b = x; }
if (a >= b + c) {cout<<"NAO FORMA TRIANGULO"<<endl;}
else
{
if(a*a==b*b+c*c){cout<<"TRIANGULO RETANGULO"<<endl;}
else 
if(a*a>b*b+c*c){cout<<"TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO"<<endl;}
if(a*a < b*b+c*c)
{
cout<<"TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO"<<endl;
}
if(a == b && b == c )
{
cout<<"TRIANGULO EQUILATERO"<<endl;
}
else
{
    if(a==b || b==c){cout<<"TRIANGULO ISOSCELES"<<endl;}
}

 }
}
```