# Como eu poderia ordenar uma lista de registros, a partir de um determinado atributo da minha classe no C#

Tags: c#, order

Como eu poderia ordenar uma lista de registros, a partir de um determinado atributo da minha classe como "Codigo"?

Sendo a minha classe a seguinte:

```
private int Codigo;
private string Nome;
private float SalarioMensal;
private string CPF;
private int Idade;

//Metodo CONSTRUTOR 1
public CEmpregado()
{
    Codigo = 0;
    Nome = "";
    SalarioMensal = 0.0f;
    CPF = "";
    Idade = 0;
}

//Metodo CONSTRUTOR 2
/// <summary>
/// Novo empregado
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_Codigo"> Codigo do Empregado</param> 
/// <param name="_Nome"> Nome do empregado</param> 
/// <param name="_SalarioMensal"> Salario mensal do empregado</param> 
/// <param name="_CPF"> CPF do empregado</param>
/// <param name="_Idade"> Idade do empregado</param>
public CEmpregado (int _Codigo, string _Nome, float _SalarioMensal, string _CPF, int _Idade)
{
    this.Codigo = _Codigo;
    this.Nome = _Nome;
    this.SalarioMensal = _SalarioMensal;
    this.CPF = _CPF;
    this.Idade = _Idade;
}

//Definindo os metodos SET
public void setCodigo(int Codigo)
{
    this.Codigo = Codigo;
}
public void setNome(string Nome)
{
    this.Nome = Nome;
}
public void setSalarioMensal(float SalarioMensal)
{
    this.SalarioMensal = SalarioMensal;
}
public void setCPF(string CPF)
{
    this.CPF = CPF;
}
public void setIdade(int Idade)
{
    this.Idade = Idade;
}

//Definindo os metodos GET
public int getCodigo()
{
    return this.Codigo;
}
public string getNome()
{
    return this.Nome;
}
public float getSalarioMensal()
{
    return this.SalarioMensal;
}
public string getCPF()
{
    return this.CPF;
}
public int getIdade()
{
    return this.Idade;
}
```

Para complemento da pergunta, adiciono um registro na classe assim:

Crio uma lista:

`CEmpregado empregado = new CEmpregado();`

Add na classe:

`ListaEmpregados.Add(empregado);`

Comment: Você quer ordenar a `ListaEmpregados`?

Comment: Positivo tenho a lista de empregados, com n empregados, cada empregado possuir esses 5 atributos e preciso ordena-los por um determinado atributo no caso o "Codigo" que o próprio  usuário informa para cada empregado

Answer (score 4):

Para ordenar uma lista você pode importar o *namespace* `System.Linq` e na sua lista utilizar o `OrderBy` ou o `OrderByDescending`, ele retornará uma lista ordenada, exemplificando:

```
var listaOrdenada = ListaEmpregados.OrderBy(p=> p.Codigo);
var outraListaOrdenada = ListaEmpregados.OrderByDescending(p=> p.Codigo);
```

Note que como parâmetro é passado a propriedade que deverá ordenar.

O código adicionado na pergunta não parece ser C#, parece que foi importado de outra linguagem. Sugiro a leitura de [Padrão de nomenclatura no código para o C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31646/padr%c3%a3o-de-nomenclatura-no-c%c3%b3digo-para-o-c)

Comment: Acho que compensaria citar o método `Sort`, caso ela quisesse ordenar a própria lista..

Comment: Esse metodo tinha tentado usar, mas me ocorre erro no OrderBy: (CS0411  C# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.)

Comment: @Bianca Como você tentou usá-lo? Poderia adicionar na pergunta, por favor?