# Por que esse programa não está rodando os comandos dentro da segunda função em diante?

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EX7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* 7.Criar um algoritmo que possa armazenar nome, duas notas e a média de 50
            alunos.A média será calculada segundo o critério: peso 3 para a primeira
            nota e peso 7 para a segunda.A impressão deverá conter nome, duas notas
            e a média.
            ESCOLA VIVA
            1.Cadastra nomes
            2.Cadastrar 1a nota
            3.Cadastrar 2a nota     
            4.Calcular média
            5.Lista no monitor
            6.Sair
            OPÇÃO: */

            float med;
            int choice, alns, cod, codmed;
            string[] alunos = new string[50];
            string[] cpf = new string[50];
            float[] nota1 = new float[50];
            float[] nota2 = new float[50];
            menu();


            void menu()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ESCOLA VIVA");
                Console.WriteLine("1.Cadastrar nomes");
                Console.WriteLine("2.Cadastrar 1a nota");
                Console.WriteLine("3.Cadastrar 2a nota");
                Console.WriteLine("4.Calcular média");
                Console.WriteLine("5.Lista no monitor");
                Console.WriteLine("6 - Sair");

                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                if (choice != 6)
                {
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.Clear();
                            cad();

                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Console.Clear();
                            cad1nota();
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Console.Clear();
                            cad2nota();
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            Console.Clear();
                            calcmedia();
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            Console.Clear();
                            list();
                            break;

                        default:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("---------Opção Inválida!--------");
                            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                            menu();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            void cad()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------- Cadastro de Alunos ---------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Digite quantos alunos deseja cadastrar (máx 50): ");
                alns = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int i = 0; i < alns; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
                    alunos[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite o cpf do aluno: ");
                    cpf[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n O códido de cadastro do aluno " + alunos[i] + " é: " + i + " \n");
                }

                menu();


            }

            void cad1nota()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------- Cadastro da 1a Nota ----------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Digite o codigo do aluno que deseja cadastrar nota:");
                cod = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Digite a 1a nota do aluno "+alunos[cod]);
                nota1[cod] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Clear();
                menu();




            }

            void cad2nota()
            {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------- Cadastro da 2a Nota ----------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Digite o codigo do aluno que deseja cadastrar nota:");
                cod = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Digite a 2a nota do aluno " + alunos[cod]);
                nota2[cod] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                menu();
            }
            void calcmedia()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------- Calculo da Media de Notas ----------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Digite o codigo do aluno que deseja calcular média:");
                codmed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                med = ( nota1[codmed] + nota2[codmed] ) / 2;
                Console.WriteLine("a media é" + med);
            }
            void list()
            {

            }


            Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para sair...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por exemplo na funçao cad1nota ela roda só que na hora de ela chamar a funçao menu novamente ela para

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um quantidade enorme de erros no código, fora a desorganização. Não vou consertar todos. Simplificando e modernizando:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace EX7 {
    class Program {
        static string[] alunos = new string[50];
        static string[] cpf = new string[50];
        static float[] nota1 = new float[50];
        static float[] nota2 = new float[50];
        static void Main() {
            while (true) {
                WriteLine("ESCOLA VIVA");
                WriteLine("1.Cadastrar nomes");
                WriteLine("2.Cadastrar 1a nota");
                WriteLine("3.Cadastrar 2a nota");
                WriteLine("4.Calcular média");
                WriteLine("5.Lista no monitor");
                WriteLine("6 - Sair");
                int choice = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                Clear();
                if (choice == 6) return;
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        Aluno();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Nota1();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Nota2();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        CalculaMedia();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Listagem();
                        break;
                    default:
                        WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                        WriteLine("---------Opção Inválida!--------");
                        WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        static void Aluno() {
            WriteLine("--------------- Cadastro de Alunos ---------------");
            WriteLine("Digite quantos alunos deseja cadastrar (máx 50): ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var quantidade) && quantidade <= 50) {
                WriteLine("Quantidade inválida");
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
                WriteLine("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
                alunos[i] = ReadLine();
                WriteLine("Digite o cpf do aluno: ");
                cpf[i] = ReadLine();
                WriteLine("\n O códido de cadastro do aluno " + alunos[i] + " é: " + i + " \n");
            }
        }
        static void Nota1() {
            WriteLine("--------------- Cadastro da 1a Nota ----------------");
            WriteLine("Digite o codigo do aluno que deseja cadastrar nota:");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var codigo)) {
                WriteLine("Código inválido");
                return;
            }
            WriteLine("Digite a 1a nota do aluno " + alunos[codigo]);
            if (!float.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var nota)) {
                WriteLine("Código inválido");
                return;
            }
            nota1[codigo] = nota;
        }
        static void Nota2() {
            WriteLine("--------------- Cadastro da 2a Nota ----------------");
            WriteLine("Digite o codigo do aluno que deseja cadastrar nota:");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var codigo)) {
                WriteLine("Código inválido");
                return;
            }
            WriteLine("Digite a 2a nota do aluno " + alunos[codigo]);
            if (!float.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var nota)) {
                WriteLine("Código inválido");
                return;
            }
            nota2[codigo] = nota;
        }
        static void CalculaMedia() {
            WriteLine("--------------- Calculo da Media de Notas ----------------");
            WriteLine("Digite o codigo do aluno que deseja calcular média:");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var codigo)) {
                WriteLine("Código inválido");
                return;
            }
            WriteLine("a media é" + (nota1[codigo] + nota2[codigo]) / 2);
        }
        static void Listagem() {}
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BNxiMk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBb8Fr). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/StudentRecords.cs).

Não dá para ter certeza de tudo como queria, mas vamos lá:

- passei as variáveis que são usadas em todos os métodos para o objeto que me parece ser mais adequado fazê-lo para este exercício. Dificilmente isto seria assim em código real, inclusive o mais correto é criar uma classe para o aluno contendo todas informações e aí ter só um *array*. Note que coloquei tudo estático para poder ser acessado por métodos estáticos.
- Fiz com que todos os métodos fossem estáticos, afinal se você chama um método diretamente dentro de um método estático ele precisa ser estático também, por uma questão de tempo de vida (pesquise mais sobre o assunto aqui mesmo).
- Coloquei um laço para repetor o menu. DO jeito que estava fazendo ia fazer uma macarronada só e ia estourar a pilha de execução. Você não pode ficar chamando métodos assim de um pro outro sem encerrar a execução, fica tudo pendurado e vira uma confusão só.
- Simplifiquei a saída quando for digitado a opção de saída, se é para sair então sai logo.
- Código repetitivo `Clear()` você isola e usa uma vez só.
- Coloquei nomes mais significativos e dentro do padrão de [nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101).
- Eu acho que o cálculo da média deveria ser armazenado em um *array* também, mas deixei isso pra você.
- Não use `Parse()`, [prefira `TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) que não quebra a plicação se se a conversão falhar.
- Validei para não permitir número maior ou igual a 50.
- O conceito todo está errado, mas enfim, já melhorou.