# Existe alguma diferença entre os termos "chamar", "invocar" ou "aplicar" uma função?

Tags: terminologia, independente-de-linguagem, semântica, convenções-de-nome

Comumente leio o termo "**invocar**" ou "**chamar**" uma função para referir à ação de executar essa função. Mas eventualmente também leio o termo "**aplicar**".

No meu entendimento, todos esses três termos têm o mesmo significado, isso está certo?

Existe alguma diferença semântica ou algum significado especial que diferencie esses três termos, ou é tudo a mesma coisa? Também gostaria de saber se, além dessas três, há mais alguma forma para se referir à ação de executar uma função (além desses três termos)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca vi uma definição formal clara sobre isso, mas de fato os termos são usados em contextos diferentes, ainda que na prática não faça diferença. Se convencionou usar termos diferentes quando a execução é feita de forma diferente.

E isso pode variar de linguagem para linguagem de acordo com a cultura adotada. E tenho a impressão que está perguntando isso mais por causa de JavaScript que de fato usa esses termos em métodos que fazem chamadas de função. Se for falar disso tem uma [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986909/221800) que justifica a diferença entre os métodos, então só para deixar completo. Por JS não ter sobrecarga de funções teve que dar nomes diferentes por causa dos parâmetros, caso contrário nada impediria usar o mesmo nome.

Mas considerando apenas os termos mesmo, em [uma resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101) falo um pouco sobre a importância de dar o nome correto. O que para nós lusófonos pode ser um pouco mais difícil de usar em inglês. Até em português o normal é usar uma palavra parecida como se fosse um sinônimo puro.

Eu procurei algumas coisas e não achei nada que me convence, por exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50884893/221800 fala de outras coisas ou especulações.

Dá pra pensar em vários termos que poderiam ser usados, alguns menos adequados, mas que na prática faça a mesma coisa: *run*, *request*, *demand* ou *start* (sim eu consigo ver algum sentido em certos contextos, embora podem ser mais específicos) seriam alguns deles.

*Call*, *invoke* ou *apply* podem dar alguma indicação melhor de acordo com o contexto também, mas para a função pura vejo dificuldade em distinguir. E acho melhor usar os termos em inglês, porque em português *pode* dar uma semântica um pouco diferente do que se costuma usar em programação. E por isso nem vou colocar a definição que se costuma dar em português de cada palavra.

- **Call** - pede para algo acontecer ou responder
- **Invoke** - vai usar algo que dá um resultado que se espera
- **Apply** - pede algo formalmente