# Como editar uma Partial Class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, classes

Peguei um projeto de um cliente e tem uma classe que está como parcial. Quando clico para ir na referencia abre o arquivo, mas no projeto eu não acho o arquivo, e tem o seguinte texto no arquivo da classe:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Nunca usei `partial class`, como funciona e como edito?

Comment: Você quer saber o conceito de `partial class` ou quer saber se pode editar o arquivo?

Comment: gostaria de editar, pois não estou encontrando o arquivo, oque seria esse auto generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Definição

[*Partial class*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é apenas uma forma de separar duas partes do código de uma classe em arquivos distintos. Não tem nenhum segredo ou semântica especial. É essencialmente uma forma de facilitar a organização de código e indicar para o compilador que os dois códigos disponíveis nos dois arquivos com uma classe de mesmo nome não é um erro de duplicação e sim um código é complementar ao outro e deve ser compilado como se fosse uma coisa só.

## Uso

Em geral este tipo de artifício só deve ser usado por geradores de código, assim uma parte é gerada em um arquivo e ninguém deve mexer neste arquivo. Em outro arquivo tem as partes do código da classe que o programador pode mexer sem causar problemas.

Claro que nada impede que o programador mexa na parte gerada, mas não deveria. É uma proteção organizacional apenas para deixar claro quais são as partes que pode mexer e as partes que não pode, mas não protege de fato.

Se você for criar alguma classe que precise ser parcial, basta usar o modificador `partial` antes de `class` para indicar que haverá uma outra parte, faça isto nos dois arquivos que possuem as duas partes, não precisa mais nada. Mas lembre-se que você só deveria usar isto se criar um gerador e deseja que uma parte não seja modificada.

## Partial Method

Na documentação acima se fala em *partial method* que é um método que só possui a declaração sem um corpo. Neste caso o corpo estará no outro arquivo. É uma forma de garantir que a assinatura do método não seja mudada no outro arquivo. Se ela for mudada, o compilador indicará problemas.

## Não mexa em código gerado

Então o arquivo que você quer mexer não deveria ser mexido.

## Onde achar os arquivos

Os arquivos costumam ficar juntos no projeto, senão na mesma pasta, em alguma outra relacionada. Tente verificar pelo Windows Explorer todos os arquivos disponíveis no projeto. O nome do arquivo provavelmente fará alguma menção a *partial* ou *designer* ou pelo menos terá um nome semelhante ao arquivo que você quer mexer e não consegue achar. Se achar no Windows Explorer, pode ficar mais fácil localizá-lo no VS.

Veja no VS se os arquivos não estão agrupados no projeto. Clique no sinal de mais `[+]` para abrir os arquivos relacionados. Dependendo da verão pode ser um triângulo ou outro símbolo, mas é o que abre a árvore de arquivos.

Mas vou reforçar, não edite esta parte a não ser que você saiba muito o que está fazendo e conheça todas as implicações, o que não deve ser o caso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

O @Maniero explicou muito bem - que um *partial class* é apenas uma classe divida em várias arquivos.

Exemplo:

#### auto/Pessoa.cs

```
namepsace App.Gente {
  public partial class Pessoa {
      public Pessoa() {
      }
  }
}
```

#### manual/Pessoa.cs

```
namespace App.Gente {
  public partial class Pessoa {
     //não pode ter construtor aqui, pois já está definido no outro arquivo
     //porém pode ter tantas quantas funções/métodos que queira

     public void FazAlgo() {

     }
  }
}
```

#### Main.cs

```
public static class Main {
   Pessoa p = new Pessoa(); //chama o consturtor em auto/Pessoa.cs
   p.FazAlgo(); //chama o método definido em manual/Pessoa.cs
}
```

**Obs:** O partial class deveria ser no *mesmo namespace*, independente da localização do arquivo físico. Se for em outro namespace, **é outra classe**.