# Em qual ordem dispor os métodos de uma classe Java?

Tags: java, classes, variáveis, método, estilo-de-codificação

Em qual ordem dispor os métodos de uma classe Java?

Considerando que uma classe pode ter: construtores, métodos estáticos, métodos privados, métodos públicos, métodos abstratos.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Classe {

    public Classe() { ... }

    public Classe(int valor) { ... }

    public void init() { ... }

    public void fazerAlgoPublico() {
        fazerAlgoPrivado();
    }

    public void fazerOutraCoisaPublica() {
        fazerAlgoPublico();
    }

    private void fazerAlgoPrivado() { ... }
}
```

ou então:

```
public class Classe {

    public Classe() { ... }

    public Classe(int valor) { ... }

    public void init() { ... }

    public void fazerAlgoPublico() {
        fazerAlgoPrivado();
    }

    private void fazerAlgoPrivado() { ... }

    public void fazerOutraCoisaPublica() {
        fazerAlgoPublico();
    }
}
```

Em qual ordem colocar os métodos para que seja fácil achar um método que esteja sendo chamado dentro de outro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é gosto, não há motivos técnicos para escolher um caminho ou outro.

Entretanto pode existir uma lógica que nem todos concordarão, e eu mesmo nem sempre concordo com tudo que eu prego, algumas questões são bem complicadas.

## Campos

Eu gosto de ver uma classe como uma estrutura de dados antes de tudo com campos... e depois métodos, então fica claro que os campos devem vir antes dos métodos, certo?

É, mais ou menos, isso se torna um pouco mais complicado por causa dos *getters* e *setters*, porque estes tendem a ficar mais legíveis com o campo perto. Mas não há consenso e eu tendo a não misturar estado com comportamento. Aí os métodos devem ir junto do campo ou o campo junto do método?

E é verdade que uso uma outra linguagem que essa decisão se torna mais fácil porque ela tem propriedades :) O que tem lá seu problema também, mas é outra questão.

Em tese campos privados devem vir antes dos públicos. Mas se você tem ambos será que não seria melhor separar tudo o que é detalhe de implementação e o que é API sem se preocupar com o tipo de membro? Não é simples responder isso, prefiro deixar todos campos juntos. Algumas pessoas não tem esse problema porque decidiram que todos os campos são detalhes de implementação e portanto são privados.

Algumas linguagens até fazem essa separação de forma mais clara.

## Construtores

Me parece óbvio que os construtores deveriam vir em seguida, afinal é a porta de entrada do objeto. Já vi algumas pessoas considerando que essa parte é menos importante e deixar no final (veja mais abaixo outra questão que complica), mas acho estranho e pouco comum.

## Privados x Públicos

Agora começa algo mais complicado.

Se considerar que os campos devem vir primeiro e eles tendem a ser mais privados então os métodos privados deveriam vir antes dos públicos, certo?

Mas os construtores são públicos (quase sempre), então quebrou isso. Algumas pessoas vão optar por ter os métodos privados antes dos construtores então. Eu vejo algum sentido nisso, já falei sobre nos parágrafos anteriores de campos, mas eu tendo a colocar depois dos construtores.

Algumas pessoas preferirão colocar os privados depois justamente porque teriam os públicos todos juntos (construtores e métodos normais) e depois tem os privados, mesmo que fique separado dos campos privados, afinal são tipos de membros bem distintos.

Mas ainda é mais complicado quando tem um construtor privado. EU tendo a fazer antes dos construtores públicos (quando tem, porque é comum ter unicamente o privado quando ele existe).

Algumas pessoas farão blocos e preferirão intercalar parte privada da pública, e portanto agrupar mais o tipo de membro que é (campo ou método).

E os protegidos? Provavelmente devem estar entre os privados e públicos, se fizer essa separação.

Algumas pessoas gostam de manter uma ordem de uso e declarar antes o que será usado internamente dentro de algum algoritmo de método. Isso é obrigatório em algumas linguagens que a compilação ocorre em apenas um passo. Mas tem os casos de referência circular, ainda que não direta, então fica mais complicado.

Algumas pessoas não gostam de separar nada disso e acham que ser privado ou não é irrelevante. Mas parece ser algo um pouco fora do normal (que não significa errado, o popular muitas vezes é o errado, lembre-se que a maioria das pessoas são medíocres e tomam decisões medíocres, mas não vou entrar no mérito, só estou alertando que poderia acontecer em qualquer caso, não só nesse).

## Membros estáticos

E fica mais complicado quando entra os membros estáticos. É onde eu menos vejo consenso, algumas pessoas acham que deve vir por último, outros antes de tudo.

Inclusive pode ser que os campos estáticos podem ser separados dos campos de instância, porque de fato fazem parte de outra estrutura.

Há quem diga que a parte estática nem deveria estar junta da parte de instância (algumas pessoas sempre usam outra classe), ou até mais radicalmente nem deveria existir.

Eu prefiro tudo no fim porque é comum que a parte da instância ser mais importante e raramente há campos estáticos, o que faz os métodos serem mais utilitários, se pensar que deveria ser algo fora da classe, então por mais no final faz muito sentido.

Mas eu já me peguei usando no meio dos métodos de instância, principalmente se o método é privado porque ele seria um utilitário feito para ajudar um método de instância público e provavelmente só chamado ali. Em C# tem até a função local quando é garantido que só será usado por um método, isso ajuda decidir porque não é nem antes ou depois é dentro.

Se optar por manter perto do uso precisa decidir se será logo acima ou logo abaixo. É muita decisão :).

E os privados estáticos deveriam vir antes do públicos estáticos, certo? Mas ele é detalhe de implementação também, e muitas vezes para usar com os métodos de instância, o que torna mais complicado.

Tem um outro problema já que construtores são métodos estáticos. Eles devem ser tratados de forma diferente? Eu acho que sim, eles são fundamentais para o objeto, os outros estáticos são só utilitários.

Os construtores estáticos, se existir algum, deveria vir antes dos normais, certo? Estranho se todos os estáticos estão separados, mas faz algum sentido.

## Métodos abstratos

A questão dos métodos abstratos poderia ser mais simples, mas não é. Há quem ache que deva colocar os métodos na ordem que faça mais sentido para visualizar o objeto, o que nem sempre você encontra algo que faça tão sentido assim, e de fato não deveria ter métodos mais importantes ou que devem ser usados antes.

Há quem defenda que os abstratos devem vir separados, alguns acham que devem vir antes porque faz parte só do contrato e não do comportamento em si.

Há quem pense justamente o oposto, se ele não tem comportamento para esta classe ele pouco importa e ele deveria vir em uma ordem adequado como se tivesse implementação porque na classe derivada mantém mais ou menos a mesma ordem.

## Métodos virtuais

Há quem ache que deve segregar os métodos que não são virtuais (`final`). É mais complicado decidir sobre isso, não me parece ter um bom motivo para isso. Talvez seja interessante adotar o mesmo que adotou no abstrato.

## Implementação de interfaces

Na pergunta não fala, mas há quem goste de separar os métodos que são implementações de interfaces dos demais.

E depois colocar os métodos internos dela na ordem que está na interface, o que te obriga olhar o fonte dela que não é algo que deveria ser obrigatório e tem caso que você nem tem acesso) então essa parte é mais complicada.

E como sempre, alguns que preferirão antes ou depois dos demais porque eles são mais confortantes com uma API mais geral; ou porque são mais específicos com o objeto atual e essas são mais importantes.

Seja consistente com métodos abstratos de classes abstratas.

## Outras ordens

Dentro dessas organizações já estabelecidas para desempatar deve colocar tudo alfabeticamente ou de forma que faça sentido? O primeiro pode tornar mais fácil achar no meio de muitos, e o segundo nem sempre é fácil achar um sentido, mas há casos que tem. Será que tem métodos que você tende a mexer mais ou consultar o fonte mais vezes? Estes deveriam estar antes?

Me parece certo que todos os métodos de mesmo nome (sobrecarga) devem estar juntos. Alguns acham que deve ter primeiro os métodos com menos parâmetros primeiro, outros acham que deve ter o mais completo antes que é o que importa mais e costuma ter um comportamento de fato, os demais seriam quase um proxy para os demais na maior parte dos casos (veja acima que já falei sobre essa questão de por antes quem chama outros métodos).

Há quem prefira separar os métodos que são procedimentos (retorna `void`) porque são quase sempre utilitários, e de fato é comum serem raros e estáticos (se feito do jeito certo).

Sorte que Java não tem eventos, operadores, delegates pra complicar mais :).

Algumas pessoas gostam de separar campos que são *lambdas* (nem sei se pode em Java, acho que sim). Eles são campos cujo valor é um método.

Nem entrei no caso de ter um `enum` ou uma classe interna porque é mais raro e mais polêmico.

Quero reforçar que algumas pessoas darão preferência de todos privados e de todos públicos antes de considerar outro critério. Eu já tentei fazer isso e depois priorizar outras formas independente de ser privado ou público, não consegui concluir qual é melhor até agora :D

Muitas vezes o privado é um utilitário de um público o que deveria fazê-lo ficar ali perto, mas tem tantas outras formas que não pregam isso que não é tão fácil defender isso sempre.

De forma geral eu tendo preferir o que será usado junto postado junto.

## Mais

Lembrando que interfaces hoje em dia podem ter vários tipos de membros também.

Em C# é possível [separar partes do código em mais de um arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77528/101) o que pode facilitar a decisão se souber fazer bem feito já que não precisa pensar na ordem. Mas pode complicar por não estar tudo no mesmo arquivo. Não gosto muito.

C# também tem marcadores de região, que [costuma ser uma bela gambiarra na maioria das vezes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82413/101).

Não sei se há convenção de comentário em Java que algum IDE adota para simular isso.

## Conclusão

Pode ter vários motivadores para uma ordem ou outra.

O mais importante é ser consistente, as pessoas precisam saber onde está cada coisa.

Pensou que eu ia dizer o que fazer? A única forma de responder este tipo de pergunta sem cair no GTKY é assim, dá as opções e tenta justificar, não pode falar o que eu uso diretamente, isso não ensina.

É a desgraça de quem tem TOC porque não consegue achar um jeito que tudo se encaixe, alguma coisa sempre parecerá fora de lugar :D

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: _Ver uma classe como uma estrutura antes de tudo com campos:_ [nem todo mundo concorda](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2075271/encapsulation-is-not-information-hiding.html?page=3). :) Vide: _"As a corollary to the first two information hiding rules, I place all internal data at the bottom of the class text, after the methods that operate on the data. (...)"_

Comment: Quase tudo oque eu escrevi nem todo mundo concorda, nem eu concordei totalmente :D