# Herança e Polimorfismo

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, modelagem, herança

Tenho a classe `Funcionario`.

```
private String nome;
private int idade;

public function vender (Funcionario f)
{
  ...
}
```

Tenho as subclasses `Gerente` e `Professor` que herdam (estendem) de `Funcionario`!

Gerente

```
private String cargo;
```

Vendedor

```
private String departamento.
```

Tenho um ambiente e gostaria de dar acesso aos dois.

No caso, acho que deveriam ser criados assim:

```
Funcionario g = new Gerente();
Funcionario v = new Vendedor();
```

Gravando a venda na base de dados, qual seria o objeto que seria guardado que executou a venda?

#### Funcionario, Gerente ou Vendedor?

Se for funcionário, na hora de exibir a venda posteriormente e destacar se quem vendeu foi o Gerente ou o Vendedor o que fazer se Gerente tem atributos diferentes de Vendedor e não existe uma tabela na base de dados chamada Funcionario com os atributos de Gerente e Vendedor juntos?

Comment: `public function`?

Comment: Mesmo que você esteja só estudando OOP, seria bacana você utilizar um problema que você conseguisse formular bem. Quando você tenta discutir a solução para um problema de modelagem que não esteja bem definido é fácil cair em divagações sem fim que andam em círculos e acabam não agregando muito valor. Veja que não se trata de conhecer a fundo todas as suas necessidades para só então modelar, trata-se de conhecer a fundo uma parte do problema, e daí modelar a solução para esta parte. Se você quiser atualizar a pergunta com mais detalhes sobre o problema creio que poderemos ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Várias tabelas

Existem duas formas de resolver isto com várias tabelas.

### Tabelas relacionadas

Também existem duas formas de organizar esta forma. Esta é a forma [normalizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

Não se esqueça que se o funcionário mudar de função, você terá que deletar dados de uma tabela e criar dados em outra. Estas tabelas das funções só devem ter vinculação direta com a tabela do funcionário. Salvo algum caso muito específico, elas não devem ser usadas em outras partes da aplicação diretamente.

#### Herança

Se quiser estabelecer estritamente a herança adotada nas classes, terá que ter uma tabela funcionários. E deverá ter uma tabela para cada classe descendente nova que criar. Isto deixa tudo organizado, fica fácil estender a aplicação com novas funções de funcionários e é um pouco mais fácil preencher as classes e gravar os dados delas no banco de dados.
Só cuidado para não ferir o [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) ou o [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Se levar a herança a sério e não quiser ter membros de uma classe derivada que são duplicados em outra derivada sem que seja herdado, então é provável que precisará criar uma hierarquia de classes para estruturar todos os membros de forma adequada. Isto pode se tornar confuso, difícil de manipular e é considerado um erro por quase todos desenvolvedores.

Começa ficar complicado se tiver que fazer algo assim:

```
Pessoa
    Fisica
        Funcionario
            Comercial
                Gerente
                Atendente
                Vendedor
                    Principal
                    Auxiliar
                    PosVenda
            Administrativo
            Producao
        Cliente
    Juridica
        Fornecedor
        Banco
```

Fiz a hierarquia de forma até simplificada, poderia ter mais níveis e obviamente muito mais derivados em cada nível.

Mas então vai fazer a herança mais ou menos (meia-boca)? Vai resolver o principal e depois vai solucionar estes outros casos de agrupamento de membros de outra forma? Ou seja, ou vai ter determinados membros idênticos que existirão em classes derivadas diferentes sem ter um ancestral comum, ou vai ter estes membros na classe `Funcionario` mas não será usado por todas derivadas?

Claro que a herança destas coisas pode ser obtida por interfaces (é fácil em C# com propriedades, em Java 8 com métodos padrão ou C++ com herança múltipla), que facilitaria um pouco, mas ainda seria um pouco confuso se tiver muitos membros assim. E a interface não é solução para tudo. Criar interface sem ter um motivo além do agrupamento puro e simples, pode ser um exagero.

Então, vai fazer a herança por completo ou pela metade? Talvez seja melhor fazer a composição.

#### Relacionamento (composição)

A não ser que use um [banco de dados orientado a objeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database) (não costumo recomendar), tabelas compõem os objetos e não herdam eles. Por isso pode ser mais interessante fazer uma [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101) e não uma herança nas suas tabelas. Em um modelo relacional os objetos são compostos. Quando você tenta ter um banco de dados relacional e um modelo orientado a objeto na aplicação você tem uma [impedância](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

Tem duas formas de você fazer a composição.

Pode ter uma referência para os dados do funcionário nas classes/tabelas das funções e usar as funções como elemento vinculante nas operações como a venda que você falou. Tem uma resposta mostrando como faz isto. Mas eu acho errado. O que acontece se o funcionário mudar de função? Tem que mudar todos os lugares onde ela foi usada? Quem vendeu foi o vendedor ou o funcionário? Bom, tem casos que pode até fazer sentido usar a função. Tem que analisar o que precisa.

Ou pode compor um funcionário com uma função (ou mais de uma eventualmente, depende do que precisa). Note que esta função, se feita da forma correta, pode ser trocada sempre que precisar. E esta forma permite trabalhar com o funcionário como elemento vinculante na venda.

Curiosamente se ele só pode ter uma função de cada vez, usar o funcionário faz muito sentido. Se ele puder ter outras funções e se algumas deles puderem existir paralelamente a outras mas estarem desabilitadas para uso, pode ser que manter a função seja interessante.

A pergunta que precisa ser feita é: **as funções possuem um funcionário ou o funcionário possui função(ões)?** Se responder certo, já sabe o que escolher.

Me diga como vai usar herança para um funcionário acumular funções! Este é um erro clássico que as pessoas cometem quando fecham os olhos e acham que herança é tudo.

Herança deve ser usada [quando um objeto **é um** (*is-a*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) outro objeto com particularidades. Um gerente **é um** funcionário, certo? Ou será que um funcionário, em um determinado momento, tem características de um gerente? Ele **é um** gerente ou ele **está um** gerente? Em inglês é mais difícil resolver esta questão :P

Por outro lado uma venda deve ter apenas vendedores? Então quem sabe possa ser o certo ter a hierarquia ou pelo menos a composição na função. Ou seja, você sempre vai colocar um vendedor como o responsável pela venda. E eventualmente pode colocar o gerente dele como corresponsável pela venda. E esta vinculação deve ser feita somente com estas duas funções respectivamente. Não pode ser um funcionário qualquer. Neste caso um funcionário pode deixar de ser vendedor mas terá que ainda existir um objeto para isto para manter consistente todo o modelo, já que vendas foram feitas com este vendedor. Isto é bom ou ruim para você?

Pense de outra forma. Se um funcionário sai da empresa, ele não pode ser removido porque tem vários outros objetos que dependem dele, mas ele não é funcionário, você troca ele para "ex-funcionário" (e aí teria que ter uma classe base para estas duas formas: funcionário e ex-funcionário) ou mate-o e tem uma propriedade mostrando que ele não é ativo mais?

E se um vendedor trabalha um tempo assim, deixa de ser vendedor e depois volta ser. As duas fases devem ser consideradas funções diferentes ou deve ser a mesma? Tudo isto ajuda definir como deve ser modelado.

Note que aqui só estou falando da composição, não importa quem compõe o que, não é herança.

### Desvinculação das funções

Esta é uma outra alternativa muito adotada no passado. Na verdade ainda muito usada hoje porque as pessoas aprendem do jeito antigo. Não quer dizer que este jeito está errado e não deve ser adotado. Ele tem lá suas vantagens... e obviamente desvantagens.

Neste modelo você tem tabelas de funções que possuem todos os dados do funcionário. Assim você evita a composição, a herança, não tem problemas com colunas que deverão ser nulas. Não tem problemas para criar novas funções.

Claro que a forma de estender a aplicação com novas funções será diferente. É evidente que na venda ou outros locais terá que dizer que é o funcionário e de alguma forma identificar a função dele para saber que tabela buscar seus dados, seja por um padrão de código ou por uma informação explícita.

Se tiver que alterar no modelo algo que vale para todas as funções, terá que fazer isto em todas as tabelas. E se seguir o mesmo modelo nas classes, terá que fazer o mesmo nelas.

Isto pode parecer terrível, mas não é de todo mal. Se considerar que todo mundo manda aplicar certos princípios em OOP e um deles é o [*open-close*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), pode ser pior alterar uma classe que é herdada do que uma classe que não terá derivadas. Aí começamos ver que OOP tem lá seus defeitos.

## Uma tabela

Na forma acima com várias tabelas pode ter um perda de performance. Praticamente todas as vezes que quiser informações de funcionários terá que ler duas tabelas distintas para pegar os dados gerais do funcionário e os específicos da função dele.

Para resolver isto você pode montar uma única tabela de funcionários e nela ter os dados de todas as funções possíveis, deixando sem dados os que não interessam para as demais funções daquele funcionário.

Esta forma tem o problema de ter um monte de colunas que nunca serão preenchidas, um monte de `null`. Teria que tratar estas coisas.

Além disto será mais difícil transportar os dados do e para o banco de dados se ele mantiver a estrutura de herança.

Esta forma não é normalizada mas há casos que ela é melhor.

Dependendo do caso não descarte a possibilidade de fazer uma única tabela e fazer as classes refletirem isto. Fazer herança é lindo no papel, mas nem sempre é a melhor solução em aplicações reais. O mesmo vale para [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

Mas isto dificulta criar novas funções porque teria que modificar a tabela do banco de dados para incluir as informações específicas. Mas precisa saber se isto será comum ou não acontecer. O problema não é tanto mudar a tabela, mas a forma de alterar a aplicação pode ficar mais difícil se fizer um "linguição".

Por outro lado, a estrutura de herança ou composição torna a aplicação mais complexa. Com qual dificuldade você quer lidar?

## Na venda

Na venda você vai guardar sempre o funcionário porque é sempre ele que faz a venda, não importa a função dele.

Eventualmente você pode ter mais que um responsável pela venda. E aí vai da sua aplicação decidir quantos podem, e que funções podem ter. Pode ser por exemplo que seja um vendedor e um gerente sempre, ou pode quaisquer funções, ou só vendedores. Mesmo que seja só possível colocar vendedor(es), ainda poderia referenciar a um gerente se houver esta informação hierárquica no cadastro do funcionário.

Quando você tem informações diferentes, tem que tratar de forma diferente. É o que eu falei acima, terá que saber onde buscar os dados adicionais. Você certamente tem a informação da função do funcionário nesta tabela. Então é fácil identificar onde procurar.

Se adotar o desacoplamento mesmo, seja por herança, seja por [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101) (que [desacopla melhor e mantém mais coeso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)), para manter a consistências, as telas deverão ser feitas da mesma forma.

Agora pense o seguinte: na aplicação, como vai guardar o responsável pela venda? Provavelmente a função, certo?

Se fizer a herança na aplicação (na tabela relacional não dá), você vai usar o que em toda a aplicação? O funcionário ou a função (gerente, vendedor, etc.)? Tem casos para tudo. Quando só importar as partes dos funcionários, tratará direto com ele mesmo que o objeto concreto seja um gerente ou um vendedor. Mas na maioria dos casos tratará das classes derivadas com as funções. Isto pode se tornar confuso com relação ao banco de dados. Se souber bem o que está fazendo, se organizar da forma correta, não terá problemas. Mas se errar, vai se perder por causa da impedância já mencionada.

O polimorfismo pode ajudar ou atrapalhar neste caso.

## Conclusão

Para que está fazendo isto?

Se for aprendizado para fazer tudo orientado a objeto, siga esta forma, entenda como resolver o problema do relacionamento e a herança ou prefira fazer a composição que não deixa de ser orientado a objeto.

Se for uma aplicação real, pense no que ela poderá ter no futuro. Pense na facilidade de manutenção.

Em aplicações que tendem a ser complexas, que poderão ter muita manutenção, ter adição de novas funções, pode ser interessante usar a forma da herança ou composição e tabelas relacionadas.

Em aplicações simples, que serão mais ou menos estáticas, que precisam de custo baixo, facilidade de entendimento de tudo, ter velocidade de acesso aos dados, fazer algo mais simples é melhor, mesmo que seja um *design* ruim do ponto de vista teórico.

A única forma de saber o certo para cada caso é ter experiência. Pessoas experientes podem lhe ajudar mas só se elas conhecerem profundamente toda situação e estiverem comprometidas em fazer o certo. E estou falando de experiência de qualidade e não quantidade. Tem gente com 30 anos fazendo isto e faz tudo errado. Perguntar para pessoas aleatórias na internet pode lhe dar informações gerais para te ajudar, mas não será a solução definitiva para o seu caso.

Se montar a classe de um jeito, por que a tabela deva ser diferente? Até pode, mas precisa saber porque. E saber as consequências disto.

Uma coisa que aprendi quando vou mudar algo na aplicação e tenho dificuldade é que a modelagem inicial dos objetos estava errada. É muito difícil modelar certo, pensar em tudo, mas tem que fazer certo para facilitar a manutenção, tem que entender o problema corretamente, mesmo os experientes não costumam fazer isto. Eu vivo errando ainda hoje depois de anos fazendo isto, mas não erro de novo depois que aprendo algo novo. Isto é o mais importante.

E tem que deixar de lado o jeito certo em alguns casos se tiver outras preocupações como a simplificação ou performance.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Creio ter um erro nesse trecho: "Uma tabela... Desta forma, praticamente todas as vezes que quiser informações de funcionários terá que ler duas tabelas distintas..."

Comment: @cantoni ainda não terminei e vou revisar tudo, mas fora um erro de digitação no trecho seguinte, não sei de que erro você está falando. Pode esclarecer?

Comment: percebi que foi no processo de edição mesmo. Dentro da seção "Um Tabela", você deixou o trecho que vale pra "Várias Tabelas"..

Comment: Acho que por composição deve ficar melhor do que por herança!
Gostaria de saber se eu postar aqui um zip com meu projetinho, algum de vocês pode dar uma rápida olhada com relação à arquitetura!
Estou vindo do php Então estou apanhando um pouco. Esse projeto estou que estou fazendo não é comercial mas apenas para aprendizado da nova linguagem. De qualquer forma, vou deixar o link de onde esta o zip com o projeto. http://www.funerariosaopedro.net.br/imwsaogotardo.zip.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar!

Comment: @cantoni você tem razão, tá bem confuso esta parte, melhorei. Ainda não terminei mas se tiver algo mais é só falar.

Comment: @CarlosRocha provavelmente sim. Na maioria dos casos é a solução que eu daria. Postar o projeto inteiro não é possível aqui. A filosofia do site é resolver problemas específicos e não gerais. Sua pergunta é boa para o padrão do site, mas pedir para revisar todo seu projeto não é. Veja o [tour]. Podemos responder todas suas dúvidas mas precisa ser de forma específica. Veja [ask] e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Esta aqui o projeto!
http://www.funerariasaopedro.net.br/imwsaogotardo.zip

A ideia é apenas revisar a arquitetura mvc e as classes de modelo. Não o projeto todo!

Comment: Então a saída seria mesmo a venda ser realizada por um Funcionário.
Na hora de exibir dados da venda deverá ser feita uma pesquisa nas tabelas Gerente e Vendedor qual deles tem o idFuncionario igual ao idFunciomario da tabela Funcionario e então decidir quais dados de  objeto exibir.

Comment: Ah, não é o projeto todo, é sua uma parte considerável dele? Leia o que eu passei para você. Perguntas específicas são perguntas específicas. Pedir revisão do projeto todo ou parte dele não funciona. Você começou bem, fazendo perguntas específicas, não mude o caminho que estava bom.

Comment: Ta bom. Mas de qualquer forma vou reler as respostas aqui publicadas e estudar um pouco mais sobre herança versus composição para me decidir. Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Viu como uma pergunta simples pode render? Imagine fazer a revisão toda que deseja.

Comment: @bigown, sua resposta ficou excelente. +1 pra ela. Vou favoritar essa pergunta.

Comment: @cantoni não está pronta ainda, eu acho que o conteúdo tá ficando legal mesmo, mas a forma ainda está ruim.

Comment: @bigown, respostas como essa não são para ser lidas apenas 1x. Eu já li umas 3x e alguns trechos mais do que os outros. É muito denso (e tem que ser mesmo, pois o assunto requer profundidade). A única sugestão é: colocar figuras das entidades e suas relações no Banco de Dados para cada situação descrita. Isso facilitará o entendimento de cada situação. No final digo: essa resposta ficará como um fonte de consultas excelentes sobre o tema. Parabéns pela dedicação!

Comment: @cantoni é, vou tentar fazer alguma coisa neste sentido.

Comment: é @bigown, realmente não dá para ler apenas 1 vez. Este projeto é apenas uma iniciação ao java que estou fazendo por conta própria. Também li que existe o recurso do instanceof parta resolver esse problema. Mas diante do que eu li aqui estou começando a me inclinar à composição em relação à herança. O que acham?

Comment: @CarlosRocha eu ainda vou melhor o texto, tive mais algumas ideias hoje. Mas é isso, a composição quase sempre funciona melhor.

Comment: @bigown. Uma dúvida que passou pela minha mente. Seria correto usar composição em cenas onde a herança é mais propícia? Por exemplo. Um Gerente é um Funcionário. Mas Um Funcionário não é feito de Gerentes! Logo, penso que fazer idFuncionario na tabela Gerente, ou seja, composição, não ficaria coerente! Qual orientação me dá nesse caso?

Answer (score 8):

Tudo depende da maneira como você vai mapear essa herança no banco de dados.

Basicamente, existem duas opções. A primeira consiste em utilizar uma única tabela pra toda hierarquia de classes. Já segunda utiliza uma tabela por classe. Cada uma tem as suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Abaixo vou explorar as duas opções baseado no seguinte modelo de classes:

Exemplo:

```
Funcionario
    Nome
    Sobrenome

Vendedor herda de Funcionario
    Departamento

Gerente herda de Funcionario
    Cargo
```

**Uma tabela pra toda hierarquia de classes**

Fazer tudo em uma tabela apenas evita a necessidade de realizar joins, além de simplificar as operações de CRUD (Create, Update, Delete). Porém, existem alguns efeitos colaterais, como, por exemplo, a não possibilidade de utilizar a restrição NOT NULL nos campos das classes filhas.

A hierarquia acima seria mapeada para uma tabela chamada FUNCIONARIO. Essa tabela teria os 4 campos acima. Porém, apenas o campo Nome e Sobrenome poderiam ser NOT NULL. O restante, Departamento e Cargo, devem permitir, obrigatoriamente, o valor NULL.

Para diferenciar Funcionario, Vendedor e Gerente, é necessário criar um campo na tabela que será utilizado como discriminador. Esse é o campo que será utilizado pra saber de qual classe é determinado registro.

Assim, esse campo pode ter o valor FUNCIONARIO quando o resgistro no banco de dados representar um Funcionador, o valor VENDEDOR quando um Vendedor e o campo GERENTE quando representar um Gerente.

**Uma tabela pra cada classe da Hierarquia**

Nesse caso, é criada uma tabela pra cada classe, ou seja, uma tabela pra Funcionario, outra pra Gerente e outra pra Vendedor. A relação da tabela funcionário com Gerente e Vendedor é de 1:1. Nessa abordagem, você preserva a normalização e pode utilizar a restrição NOT NULL normalmente. Porém, existe um custo, já que ao recuperar um Vendedor ou um Gerente, será necessário realizar um Join. Além disso, as operações de CRUD ficam mais complexas.

ORMs modernos, como Hibernate e outros, permitem que você especifique essas duas formas de realizar o mapeamento. Eles mesmos decidem, no momento de recuperar o registro, qual será o tipo de objeto criado.

Comment: E como é feita a relação do funcionário com sua função no segundo caso?

Comment: Complicado mesmo @bigown,  modelar a Função (Gerente, Vendedor, etc), como herança da classe Funcionário também não me parece algo consistente com a realidade. Certamente haverá problemas, pois se um funcionário deixa de ser vendedor e passar a ser gerente, será necessário migrá-lo de uma tabela pra outra. Se houver outras relações diretas com a classe Vendedor, por exemplo, aí complica mais ainda. De qualquer maneira, minha resposta foi mais no sentido de explicar como a herança OO é mapeada em um banco de dados relacional do que realmente focada no contexto da pergunta.

Comment: Eu entendi. A dúvida é qual você acha que deveria usar neste caso que você descreveu.

Comment: Acho que um bom caminho é desacoplar o Funcionário e a Função. Para isso haveria uma tabela FUNCIONARIO_FUNCAO que armazenaria todas as funções de um funcionário, a(s) atual(is) e as passadas. Um campo flag serviria pra marcar se é a função atual ou uma função passada. No final, esta tabela seria o histórico de funções que um funcionário exerceu na empresa. O que você pensa?

Comment: É uma solução interessante. É complexo mas quando se quer resolver tudo direito, acaba tendo que fazer estas coisas. Claro que não vi implementação, provavelmente os detalhes variariam dependendo da situação, mas é mais ou menos isto mesmo se for necessário. Só um detalhe, "se é **uma** das funções atuais", pode ter mais que uma :) Mas ainda minha dúvida seria: as funções possuem um funcionário ou os funcionários possui(em) função(ões)? Ou seja, quem será FK da outra?

Comment: Sim, nesse modelo o Funcionario poderia acumular funcoes. :-) Nesse caso seria: Um Funcionario pode estar em N Funcoes e uma Funcao pode ser de N Funcionarios. No final, é uma relação NxN entre Funcionario e Funcao. Na tabela FUNCIONARIO_FUNCAO haveriam duas chaves estrangeiras (uma para cada tabela). Elas podem repetir, pois um Funcionario pode virar Gerente mais de uma vez, em tempos distintos. Isso tudo mostra como é complicado modelar um problema. É sem dúvida uma das atividades mais complicadas que existem no desenvolvimento de software.

Answer (score 4):

Minha sugestão de mapeamento seria assim.

```
public class Funcionario {
  private Long id;
  private String nome;
}

public class Venda {
  private Long id;
  private Funcionario funcionario; //relacionamento com o funcionario que fez a venda
}

public class Gerente {
  private Long id;
  private Funcionario funcionario; // relacionamento com as informações de funcionario do gerente
}

public class Vendedor {
  private Long id;
  private Funcionario funcionario; // relacionamento com as informações de funcionario do vendedor
}
```

Você deve estar se perguntando pelo motivo de eu não ter feito herança entre Vendedor/Gerente e Funcionario. Em geral, para mapeamento de banco de dados, [isto atrapalha bastante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/891820/2387977).

Vamos agora as suas perguntas, com base na minha sugestão de mapeamento.

> Gravando a venda na base de dados, qual seria o objeto que seria
>   guardado que executou a venda? Funcionario, Gerente ou Vendedor?

Funcionario

> Se for funcionário, na hora de exibir a venda posteriormente e
>   destacar se quem vendeu foi o Gerente ou o Vendedor o que fazer se
>   Gerente tem atributos diferentes de Vendedor e não existe uma tabela
>   na base de dados chamada Funcionario com os atributos de Gerente e
>   Vendedor juntos?

Vai a minha sugestão para este caso. Identifique antes de abrir a tela se a venda foi feita pelo Gerente ou Vendedor, fazendo uma simples consulta no banco de dados pelo idFuncionario da Venda na tabelas de Vendedor e Gerente. Tendo esta informação, você pode criar a lógica para exibir as informações de Vendedor ou Gerente na tela. E em outro ponto desta tela, exiba sempre as informações em comum de Gerente e Vendedor, que são as informações da tabela Funcionario.

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente é possível saber através do ID, por exemplo gerente e vendedor são ambos funcionários, portando se houver uma tabela funcionário que possua o registro de todos os funcionários da empresa, é possível apenas armazenar o ID do funcionário que realizou a venda e com este você consegue saber quem realizou a venda seja gerente ou vendedor.

Comment: Parecer que todos os estão tendendo à composição mesmo!
Embora corra o risco de calculo errado do id do funcionario na hora de gravar na tabela gerente qual o funcionario (superclasse) dele mas mesmo parece mais profissional!

Comment: Nesse caso teremos herança no código e composição na base de dados!

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa entender a diferença entre `variável de referência` e `objeto de referência`.
Veja bem: você declarou um objeto assim `Funcionário f = new Vendedor();`
**O que isso significa para o `Java` ?**
Temos a variável de referência `f` que é um `Funcionário`, e um `objeto de referência` que é um `Vendedor`. Isso quer dizer que você possui um `Vendedor` em memória, mas uma variável `Funcionário` apontando pra ele. 
**Na prática, o que isso quer dizer ?**
Quer dizer que você possui um objeto Vendedor que está autorizado a utilizar apenas os métodos herdados/sobrescritos da classe `Funcionário`.
Devido à herança, podemos afirmar que `Gerente IS-A Funcionário` e `Vendedor IS-A Funcionário`, mas não o contrário.
Se você quiser verificar se o funcionário é um Gerente ou um Vendedor, aplique a verificação `objeto instanceof Vendedor` ou `objeto instanceof Gerente`.

**Consideraçoes**

Dado o mapeamento que você apresentou, acredito que a classe `Funcionário` não estará representada no banco de dados, assim você irá salvar um `Gerente` ou um `Vendedor`, pois `Funcionário` é apenas uma classe **abstraindo informações comuns entre Vendedor e Gerente**, podendo ela ser revista posteriormente e ser transformada em uma **classe abstrata ou uma interface**, dependendo dos seus objetivos.

Answer (score 2):

## Existem três opções clássicas (e não apenas duas)

Veja o artigo *Tipos de Herança no Hibernate* https://www.devmedia.com.br/tipos-de-heranca-no-hibernate/28641 que detalha as três opções. O artigo ainda esclarece como o código que realiza o mapeamento entre OO e relacional pode ser implementado com o apoio do Hibernate.

O domínio deste problema é conhecido por *impedance mismatch* (detalhes [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)).