# Como representar relações do tipo "é-um" no modelo lógico?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tipagem, modelagem

Eu estou criando um modelo de dados onde uma entidade cliente é também uma pessoa, do tipo jurídica ou física. Porém no estado em que se encontra não será possível implementá-lo fisicamente, pois não estou conseguindo criar o modelo lógico que descreve corretamente uma maneira de fazer com que uma entidade herde atributos de duas outra diferentes. Veja.

Primeiramente, fiz a representação conceitual da situação descrita da seguinte maneira: 
[image: Conceitual-Cliente-É-Um]

Nota-se a duplicidade de alguns atributos visto este ser um modelo conceitual. Infelizmente na bibliografia que estou usando para modelagem de dados não existe nenhuma situação-exemplo onde uma entidade possui mais de um relacionamento do tipo "é-um", portanto, não sei se este modelo conceitual está correto, podendo esta ser a causa do erro no modelo lógico, descrito a seguir:

Tabela de clientes e sua respectiva tabela de junção.

[image: Lógico-Relaciona-Cliente[2]]

Tabelas de pessoa física e jurídica, respectivamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que para implementar este modelo, eu não sei o que devo fazer para que um cliente seja apenas um tipo de pessoa, física ou jurídica. Meu professor sugeriu que eu criasse uma entidade "Pessoa", ao invés de duas (jurídica e física), porém encontrei o mesmo problema, pois uma entidade pessoa deverá ter os atributos CPF e CNPJ, ao mesmo tempo.

Obs: Implementarei o BD no SQL Server 2014 e a aplicação será programada em VB.NET.

Obrigado, desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

`Cliente(..., FK_PessoaFisica, FK_PessoaJuridica )`

Se o `Cliente` for uma `Pessoa Física`... ele terá FK_PessoaFisica atribuído, e FK_PessoaJuridica nulo...

Se o `Cliente` for uma `Pessoa Jurídica`... ele terá FK_PessoaJuridica atribuído, e FK_PessoaFisica nulo...

Comment: Que legal, vou tomar nota desta sugestão. Eu estava pensando em fazer algo do tipo mas pensei que o modelo só iria ficar ainda mais bagunçado.
Muito obrigado Pedro.

Answer (score 4):

Seu problema é semelhante ao que eu respondi [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101).

Sinceramente não entendi esta tabela de junção. Os dados do CPF/CNPJ claramente devem pertencer às tabelas de pessoas e só. Salvo algum entendimento errado meu do que você deseja com isto, esta tabela não faz sentido.

O próprio cliente terá uma forma de ligar com a tabela de pessoas. Você terá uma coluna para a chave estrangeira para a pessoa física e outra para pessoa jurídica. Obviamente só uma delas será preenchida de cada vez. A ligação poderá ser feito com uma coluna natural, como o CPF/CNPJ ou por um substituto (um ID), que eu prefiro na maioria dos casos.

Talvez você possa mudar algumas das colunas que são comuns para os dois tipos de pessoa e jogar na tabela de cliente. Do jeito que está feito nem faz sentido existir a tabela de cliente. Você não está transpondo o modelo conceitual, você, por alguma razão que desconheço, resolveu pegar os dados que estavam em cliente no modelo conceitual e jogou para as pessoas.

O modelo conceitual já está esquisito porque tem `nome` nas três entidades. `renda_mensal` desta forma, dificilmente é algo comum a todos os tipos de cliente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sim, obrigado pela sugestão. Este é o meu primeiro modelo de dados, estou aprendendo muito por livros então não fica muito claro como se aplicam os conceitos na prática. A questão é que imaginei que no banco de dados é que eu distinguiria se o cliente é pessoa física ou jurídica mas pelo que você me disse me parece que isso eu definirei na aplicação, não é mesmo?

Além disso, gostaria de saber mais sobre como você gosta de trabalhar em relação às ID's no lugar do CPF...

Comment: o CPF/CPNJ é único para cada PF/PJ, então o que ele sugere é utilizar CPF/CNPJ no lugar dos IDs... é isso mesmo, @bigown ?

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa eu não falei isto, você tem que identificar no banco de dados qual o tipo de pessoa. Você só não precisa, mas pode ter, uma coluna só para isto. Aí fica a sua escolha. Se tiver a coluna fica mais fácil, mas de certa forma é uma informação redundante, dependendo de como você faz. Se você quer saber mais sobre alguma coisa, você deve abrir uma pergunta para isto.

Comment: @PedroLaini é uma possibilidade, você pode usar desta forma, mas eu não sugeri isto, eu só mencionei que é possível. Minha sugestão é o ID.

Answer (score 2):

Se você precisa modelar seus clientes identificando se são pessoa física ou jurídica, você poderia ter **simplesmente duas entidades:**

- **Pessoa**, cuja identidade seria seu cadastro nacional, um campo chamado por exemplo de `CpfCnpj` (sim, estes documentos possuem o mesmo caráter, é natural usar o mesmo campo). Esta entidade teria um atributo para identificar se é pessoa física ou jurídica (preenchido na base de dados por exemplo com `F` ou `J`). Os poucos campos exclusivos de pessoa física ou jurídica podem não justificar duas tabelas distintas.
- **Cliente**, que não precisa de relação hierárquica com pessoa mas basta apenas referenciar uma pessoa. Para identificar então se um cliente é pessoa física ou jurídica você recorre à entidade *Pessoa* ao qual ele está relacionado.

Se no domínio os tipos de cliente (física/jurídica) realmente caracterizam diferentes tipos de entidades, então você teria aqui duas classes: *Cliente Pessoa Física* e *Cliente Pessoa Jurídica*. Mas:

> Observe que é raro um domínio onde **Cliente Pessoa Física** e **Cliente Pessoa Jurídica** sejam entidades distintas. Geralmente só precisamos diferenciá-los através dos seus atributos para tomar algumas decisões durante o processo de venda.

E também é raro um domínio onde exista realmente uma entidade *Pessoa*. Geralmente ela só aparece no código para facilitar reutilização e desenho da base de dados.

> Os domínios reais, geralmente, em vez de possuírem entidade *Pessoa*, possuem na verdade entidades *Cliente*, *Funcionário*, *Fornecedor*... Algumas destas entidades são a mesma pessoa na vida real mas para o sistema continuam sendo entidades distintas pois possuem propósitos distintos no domínio.

## Conclusão

A maioria dos problemas ao modelar pessoas aparece durante exercícios. Essa modelagem parece um problema interessante mas na prática não é. Veja os sistemas por aí: eles tem uma tabela "Pessoa(s)" e pronto.

Mesmo sistemas bem modelados geralmente não precisam distinguir pessoa física e jurídica como entidades distintas mas apenas como um atributo que a caracteriza como sendo de um tipo ou de outro; não apenas porque é mais simples de modelar mas porque assim é o domínio real do problema.

Quando o domínio requer entidades distintas conforme o tipo de pessoa, geralmente o que ele requer não são "pessoas" de tipos distintos mas sim, por exemplo, "clientes" de tipos distintos. Nestes casos (raros), "Pessoa" continua lá sendo a mesma para física e jurídica e o cliente é que é especializado: *Cliente Pessoa Física* e *Cliente Pessoa Jurídica*.

## Sugestão

Ao modelar, seja por exercício ou por necessidade profissional, procure primeiro definir bem o problema, numa linguagem de negócio, e então modele orientado pelo problema e não pela maneira como gostaria de implementar.