# Uso da Generalização/Especialização na modelagem de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, herança, modelo-relacional

Já li alguns artigos sobre [Generalização/Especialização](https://sites.google.com/site/uniplibancodedados1/aulas/aula-9---generalizacao-e-especializacao) na modelagem de dados, mas algumas dúvidas surgiram: A chave primária da generalização é, também, chave primária das especializações - isto é, as especializações podem conter chaves primárias próprias? Se sim, como se dão os relacionamentos entre elas? Uma entidade especializada deve possuir, obrigatoriamente, atributos? Quando devo -  ou não - especializar uma entidade e quando devo generalizar outras?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Não gosto muito dessa ideia. Pra falar a verdade ela é maior absurda e se aplicada cria coisas muito esquisitas. Pelo menos em banco de dados se fizer a generalização do jeito certo não é para ter qualquer dificuldade.

Em uma aplicação há quem diga, e hoje tendo a concordar na maior parte dos casos, que um tipo de dados deve ser preparado para ser especializado e não permitir criar um objeto concreto dele, ou poder criar o objeto concreto e não poder ser especializado. Existem exceções úteis para isso, então é permitido que um tipo gere objeto concreto e seja especializado, mas não deveria ser abusado.

Em banco de dados não tem esta necessidade, ou é geral e nunca terá dados desse tipo ou é específico e tem dados, nunca ambos. Então o tipo generalizado só faz parte do modelo lógico para organizar melhor o modelo, não haverá dados persistidos no *storage* com esse tipo, somente terá dos tipos específicos, então fazendo assim que é o certo seu problema não existe, só existe chave primária real no tipo especializado.

Se insistir em fazer errado, eu nem acho que esteja fazendo especialização, está normalizando tabelas estabelecendo um relacionamento. E com performance pior pra zero ganho. Se for realmente uma especialização a [relação é 1:1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101), completamente desnecessário em quase todos casos onde está fazendo certo. Não faz sentido.

Não existe isso de especializar algumas entidade e generalizar outros, existe o estabelecimento de relação de generalidade e especialidade entre entidades. Quando percebe que existe um padrão em certas entidades e isto pode provocar a criação da ideia de um entidade lógica geral para que toda vez que mexa nela tenha que mexer junto nas suas especializadas, deve fazê-lo. Tem menos casos assim do que pode parecer. A maior parte dos casos que as pessoas acham que tem este tipo de relação na verdade de outras formas de composição de dados, em geral são papeis.

Os exemplos do *link* citado são ruins e aparentemente feito porque quem não faz softwares reais. Pessoa física e jurídica não são especializações de de um cliente em contexto algum. Em geral você tem a pessoa física ou jurídica que são concretas (e pode ter pessoa com a generalização abstrata) e o cliente é só um papel de uma pessoa. OP exemplo inclusive é simplista demais para ensinar algo útil. Mais ou menos vale o mesmo para os outros.

Para fazer tudo certo precisa entender muito do assunto que está modelando, tem que praticar muito taxonomia e ontologia. É necessário entender as relações das coisas fora do software para modelar certo dentro dele. Se você não entende o que é cada entendida e a real relação entre elas você modelará errado ou acertará só por coincidência, uma verdadeira loteria. Não tem livro, curso ou qualquer coisa que ensine isto. A única forma é construir o conhecimento consumindo, observando, debatendo, praticando sobre esses domínios e assuntos gerais, para formar um pensamento lógico, crítico e holístico sobre o mundo e os sistemas já estabelecidos no mundo real.

Algumas perguntas relacionadas:

- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)
- [Funcionário pode ser papel de Pessoa Física?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313990/101)
- [Como representar relações do tipo “é-um” no modelo lógico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81628/101)
- [Herança e Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101)
- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).