# Qual a diferença entre os métodos virtual e abstract?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança, método, polimorfismo

Em quais casos devo preferir usar um tipo ao invés do outro?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ambos são mecanismos de [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101).

[Métodos virtuais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) possuem implementação que **podem** ser sobrepostas por uma classe derivada.

[Métodos abstratos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) não possuem implementação e, portanto, **devem** ter uma implementação na primeira classe derivada concreta da hierarquia.

Métodos virtuais podem estar em [classes abstratas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101) ou concretas. Métodos abstratos só podem estar em classes abstratas.

```
public abstract class Base {
    public abstract void MetodoAbstrato(string nome); //não há implementação

    public virtual void MetodoVirtual(int x) {
        //faz algo aqui
    }
}

public class Derivada : Base {
    public override void MetodoAbstrato(string nome) {
        //faz algo aqui
    }
    public override void MetodoVirtual(int x) {
        //faz algo aqui
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/VirtualVsAbstract.cs).

Interfaces só possuem métodos abstratos. Por isso nem precisam do modificar `virtual` ou `abstract`.

[Veja mais sobre o uso de `virtual`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101).

Comment: "devem ter uma implementação na classe derivada." só modificaria esta parte para devem ter uma implementação na classe derivada que não for abstrata.

Comment: @LeonardoXavier boa, editado, obrigado.