# Pra que usar de private?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, private

Estou aprendendo variáveis `public` e `private`.

Se sou eu quem crio todo o código do programa, qual a necessidade de criar uma variável `private`? Sendo que basta eu não programar um código que acesse a mesma de outra classe.

Mesmo tendo lendo muita coisa na teoria, ainda não consegui entender na prática.

Comment: Outra relacionada: [Modificadores de acesso no C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/28595)

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas. a teoria eu uma noção, mas não tinha pensado na duplicada de nomes das variáveis igual @diegofm falou.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: De fato se é só você quem codifica esse software e ele é pequeno e simples o bastante para você não depender de uma interface bem desenhada para compreendê-lo, tanto faz especificar a visibilidade do membro; você está correto com relação a isso. Mas o C# não foi feito apenas para pequenos e simples softwares desenvolvidos por uma única pessoa, certo? Em softwares que atendam necessidades mais complexas, uma interface bem definida ajuda muito a entender o sistema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porque a filosofia do C# é proteger você de você mesmo, afinal você pode acabar esquecendo e acessar o que não deve, principalmente depois de um tempo que criou aquele código. Mais ainda, quem garante que só você mexerá nesse código? Pra que usar uma convenção se pode ter uma garantia?

A filosofia da linguagem é encapsular a implementação e expor apenas o contrato. Ainda tem chão para entender essas coisas em detalhes, mas tem bastante coisa aqui no site que pode pesquisar e perguntar se ainda não tiver uma reposta. Exemplo: [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)

Escondendo o detalhe de implementação fica mais fácil melhorar o código sem quebrar a compatibilidade externa.

Além disso, com algo marcado como privado, é possível para o compilador fazer algumas otimizações por saber que nunca será chamado fora.

Alguns padrões de projeto podem se beneficiar dessa característica.

Não programamos para funcionar, programamos para ser tudo certo. Desenvolver software é bastante complicado e temos que ser os mais cuidadosos possíveis.

Esse é um recurso que ajuda **gerenciar melhor essa complexidade**. Na dúvida deve-se proteger ao máximo e ir abrindo conforme a necessidade.

Se a dúvida é sobre criar propriedades no lugar de variáveis, aí já foi respondida em [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).