# Pra que serve a palavra-chave "virtual" em C#?

Tags: c#

Em C# é já vi alguma classe usando a palavra-chave `virtual` em alguns métodos.

Exemplo:

```
class Person
{

      public virtual string GetName()
      {
            // faz alguma coisa aí
      }
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber pra que serve esse `virtual`.

Comment: Que martelada linda, kkkkkk

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25831/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-classe-atributos-e-m%C3%A9todos-virtual