# Polimorfismo em linguagem procedural

Tags: c, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, polimorfismo

Uma das características da orientação a objetos é o polimorfismo, capacidade de um método executar diferentes comportamentos conforme o contexto que pode ser definido por uma hierarquia (herança/interface) ou sobrecarga(*overloading*).

É sugerido que em algumas situações seja feita a [troca de cadeias de `if/switch` por polimorfismo](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) que parece ser uma solução mais elegante.

#### Pergunta

O conceito de polimorfismo (sobrescrita, funções com o mesmo nome executar comportamentos diferentes) pode ser aplicado no paradigma procedural na linguagem C?

Qual seria **ideia** básica de implementá-lo?

Comment: Acho que isso varia de linguagem para linguagem, não? De todo modo, uma forma *possível* de emulá-lo seria guardar junto com cada dado seu tipo, e ao chamar a função decidir qual a implementação mais apropriada baseado no mesmo. Isso dificilmente teria suporte da sintaxe, entretanto... Mas de novo, creio que isso varia de linguagem pra linguagem.

Comment: Complementando (estou incerto se devo postar ou não uma resposta, pois essa pergunta me parece bastante ampla) se a linguagem é fortemente tipada fica mais difícil escrever código "genérico" que se aplique a mais do que um único tipo. Caso contrário, há mais possibilidades, mesmo que a linguagem não seja orientada por objeto (ex.: em C pode-se usar `void*` como "ponteiro pra qualquer coisa").

Comment: @mgibsonbr, obrigado pela observações da pergunta, não tinha notado que está tão ampla. Vou reformular, seu primeiro comentário da ideia uma resposta que me parece adequada acho que vc captou a inteção da pergunta. Se tiver mais alguma sugestão/edição de como especificar/restringir a pergunta chama ai.

Comment: Concordo com tudo o que o @mgibsonbr disse. Sempre é possível criar uma forma de obter o resultado desejado, o quanto será fácil, elegante e o resultado compense é que é a questão.

Comment: existem casos em que usar switch é mais elegante do que dispatch por métodos. Métodos deixam fácil extender o programa com novas classes mas fica difícil extender o programa com novos métodos. Switchs funcionam na direção oposta: é difícil extender o programa com novos casos para o switch mas é fácil criar novas funções com um switch dentro. Na comunidade de programação funcional (onde é comum usar tipos algébricos e "switch") essa diferença é conhecida como *problema da expressão* (expression problem).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Um `switch` sempre pode ser substituído por uma tabela, afinal sua implementação interna costuma ser feita com uma tabela. Uma sequência de `if`s só não é assim porque fica difícil para o compilador determinar uniformidade. Então isto já dá um bom indício da resposta.

## Polimorfismo estático

Se estivermos falando de polimorfismo estático, resolvido em tempo de compilação, fica difícil fazer muita coisa. Ou faz manual ou usa uma ferramenta de manipulação de código. Talvez seja possível usar o pré-processador para ajudar, mas provavelmente teria que ter um compilador que tratasse disto antes do compilador oficial atual. Não parece ser o foco da pergunta, mas coloco por questão de completeza.

## Polimorfismo paramétrico

O polimorfismo paramétrico pode ser facilmente obtido com `void *`. O problema é que ele não dá segurança de tipo. A segurança poderia ser obtida estaticamente com um analisador, então cai na questão anterior que citei. De fato o C11 até tem algo neste sentido com [`_Generic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic).

Em linguagens dinâmicas, de uma certa forma, todos os tipos já são `void *` que é um ponteiro para qualquer tipo. Na verdade é comum em linguagens dinâmicas que os objetos tenham seu tipo agregado ao valor. Então todos os dados são paramétricos ou pelo menos polimórficos.

## Polimorfismo *ad hoc*

Com o polimorfismo *ad hoc* (sobrecarga) dinâmico, que não é muito comum na maioria das linguagens estáticas *mainstream*, é possível criar uma tabela com nomes de funções e seus respectivos endereços. Quando digo nome, pode ser uma *string* ou pode ser um valor inteiro que represente o nome, talvez até através de uma enumeração. Se for *string* provavelmente será feito com uma estrutura de dicionário, mas com um inteiro sequencial pode-se usar um *array* mesmo.

Provavelmente teria uma função que controlaria o acesso de acordo com determinados critérios.

Em linguagens dinâmicas esta tabela pode ser bem natural. De fato os objetos nessas linguagens costumam ser implementados como dicionários ou estruturas semelhantes. Aí no próprio objeto já consta qual é cada função que deve ser chamada. Ou seja, neste tipo de linguagem tudo usa polimorfismo dinâmico. O que parece óbvio já que a linguagem é dinâmica.

Este mecanismo também poderia ser usado no próximo tipo de polimorfismo, embora talvez com menor eficiência.

Ao invés de tabela também é possível montar uma estrutura.

## Polimorfismo de subtipo

Este eu chamaria de polimorfismo clássico, o que todo mundo reconhece logo de cara como um mecanismo de polimorfismo. Na implementação mais comum ele escolhe que função usar de acordo com um ponteiro contido em algum lugar, então o objeto concreto tem a informação de que tipo ele é disponível em tempo de execução e este tipo vai determinar qual função será chamada. Acho que é do que se trata a pergunta.

Há uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/524033/221800) que fala sobre polimorfismo em C que é uma das poucas linguagens *mainstream* que ainda não possui polimorfismo de subtipo na linguagem. Lá há algumas soluções:

```
typedef struct {
   data member_x;
} base;

typedef struct {
   struct base;
   data member_y;
} derived;

//esta função pertence à base e pode ser usada com estruturas derived
void function_on_base(struct base * a);

//esta função só pode receber derived de forma segura   
void function_on_derived(struct derived * b);
```

É possível fazer a função ser internalizada na estrutura conforme outro exemplo contido na pergunta do SO:

```
struct inode_operations {
    int (*create) (struct inode *,struct dentry *,int, struct nameidata *);
    struct dentry * (*lookup) (struct inode *,struct dentry *, struct nameidata *);
    ...
};

//chamada
struct inode_operations   *i_op;
i_op -> create(...);
```

Outra forma:

```
typedef struct {
   int (*SomeFunction)(TheClass* this, int i);
   void (*OtherFunction)(TheClass* this, char* c);
} VTable;

typedef struct {
   VTable* pVTable;
   int member;
} TheClass;

//chamada
int CallSomeFunction(TheClass* this, int i) {
  (this->SomeFunction)(this, i);
}
```

Exemplo retirado de uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524076/221800).

Pode parecer gambiarra mas é mais ou menos isto que ocorre internamente em C++, por exemplo. Note que os ponteiros para `SomeFunction` e `OtherFunction` são ajustados de acordo com o dado concreto, ou seja dependendo do tipo do objeto ele apontará para funções diferentes. Evidentemente que o código para montar essa `VTable` deverá ser feito na mão sempre que se criar um novo objeto, não há facilidades de sintaxe para ajudar.

A chamada através de ponteiro (`(this->SomeFunction)`) só é necessária se opta pelo polimorfismo, se uma função não precisa deste recurso a chamada pode ser normal. Para quem não conhece esta sintaxe o que faz aí é pegar o conteúdo de `this->SomeFunction` que é um ponteiro, como pode ser visto na definição da estrutura, e é dado um `call` neste ponteiro. Em uma chamada normal o ponteiro é fixo e está presente direto no código não precisando de uma variável para indicar o que chamar. Obviamente quando tem que acessar uma variável para pegar o ponteiro que será usado para a chamada é um pouco mais lento. Isto é chamado [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Um parâmetro `this` existe e é visto, mas em uma linguagem com sintaxe OOP ele é oculto e fica implícito no código.

#### Linguagens dinâmicas

Em uma linguagem dinâmica uma forma é usar um dicionário. Vamos supor uma linguagem fictícia que tenha uma sintaxe de dicionário e de referência para funções, então poderia fazer:

```
func Base()
    var objeto = { => }
    objeto["dado"] = 1
    objeto["teste"] = &Base_teste
    return objeto
func Base_teste()
    return "base"
func Derivada()
    var objeto = { => }
    objeto["dado"] = 1
    objeto["dado2"] = "dado"
    objeto["teste"] = &Berivada_teste
    return objeto
func Derivada_teste()
    return "derivada"
//chamada
var base = Base()
var derivada = Derivada()
//imprime base porque a variável base possui um membro "teste" que contem &Base_teste
print base.teste()
//imprime derivada porque a variável base possui um membro "teste" que contem &Derivada_teste
print derivada.teste()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Polymorphism.c).

Então mesmo que algum lugar espere um tipo `Base` se passar um objeto do tipo `Derivada` vai chamar o método `teste` do tipo concreto.

Claro que varia de linguagem para linguagem, mas PHP, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Lua, Harbour, enfim, qualquer linguagem dinâmica, algumas até expõe isto parcialmente, que implementem alguma forma de OOP fazem basicamente isto sem o programador ver desta forma.

## Conclusão

Computadores são procedurais, então concretamente não existe polimorfismo, ele é criado através de padrões de código, os tais padrões de projeto que podem ser embutidos em um mecanismo da linguagem. Computadores só sabem transferir dados de um lugar para o outro, alterar seus *bits* em um conjunto muito limitado de operações, fazer comparações de dados e mudar a continuidade de execução do código. Cada vez mais vemos abstrações e nos afastamos do funcionamento real dos computadores.

C++ inicialmente não era um compilador completo e apenas transformava o código de entrada em um código C.

Aí fica a dúvida, usando C que é um linguagem procedural podemos fazer códigos polimórficos e implementar as demais características de OOP, então o código escrito desta forma é orientado a objeto mesmo que escrito em linguagem procedural? Eu imagino que sim mas não tenho informações que definem isso formalmente.

## Adendo

Algumas pessoas acham que OOP cura câncer. Ela é só uma ferramenta. É uma abstração criada para facilitar a solução de determinados problemas. Tanto não é um paradigma universal que a única linguagem pura deste paradigma fracassou. Funcionaram bem as linguagens multi-paradigmas onde a maior parte do tempo se programa proceduralmente e em algumas circunstâncias usa-se a orientação a objeto.

Mesmo quem defende o uso correto do paradigma sabe e usa dessa forma. Só os puristas acham que qualquer vestígio procedural é ruim. Mas mesmo estes não costumam usar Smalltalk.

Então no fundo usar OOP em uma linguagem procedural é o que fazemos, algumas linguagens só facilitaram um pouco isto.

Veja o que aconteceu com C. Quase ninguém via OOP como algo muito importante e é extremamente raro ver alguém implementando algo que se aproximasse do paradigma. Quando surgiu C++, as pessoas continuaram programando em C e basicamente do mesmo jeito. Muitos que preferiram C++ fizeram a escolha por outros motivos e não porque ela podia ser usada com orientação a objeto de forma fácil.

PHP não era nada orientada a objeto mas sempre foi relativamente fácil usar o paradigma com o que já existia na linguagem. Ninguém fazia isso. E OOP já estava na moda há muito tempo. De repente PHP passou ter sintaxe que simplificava OOP. E o que aconteceu? Todo mundo achou que isto era a forma correta de programar, que é muito melhor assim, que as vantagens são grandes demais para ignorar.

Ora, se OOP era tão bom e trazia tantos benefícios, porque ninguém usava o paradigma mesmo tendo que fazer manualmente na linguagem procedural? Se OOP só é vantajoso se tiver uma sintaxe que facilite então concluo que a vantagem é pequena. Uma explicação para o não uso antes é que não costuma compensar seu uso na maioria dos casos.

Outra explicação é que as pessoas não entendem o funcionamento dos mecanismos que fazem OOP funcionar, não sabem que linguagens procedurais podem se comportar como linguagens ditas orientadas a objeto. Por isto a pergunta é importante.

Comment: Eu comecei escrever a resposta quando ela estava em outro formato, como está mais completa, vou deixar assim.

Comment: "a única linguagem pura deste paradigma fracassou", qual?

Comment: @Patrick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk

Comment: Computadores na verdade só fazem correr elétrons através de semicondutores, então o que você descreve como funcionamento real do computador já é uma abstração (e elétrons e semicondutores, em algum nível, também são abstrações). Conforme a natureza do estudo, é adotado um nível diferente de abstração - se falarmos sempre em "real" não saímos do lugar. Usar um paradigma é escrever código funcional que abstraia o trabalho que o compilador terá transformando aquilo em outra coisa - se escrevermos esta outra coisa e não o código que a abstraia, definitivamente não estamos usando aquele paradigma.