# Como fazer herança visual de formulário no Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, winforms, herança, polimorfismo

Tenho um `form` base que vai ser o `form` 'Pai', com 3 botões nele.
Adicionar, Excluir e Alterar.

Vou utilizar o `formbase` para padronizar minhas telas de cadastro, sendo assim cada tela de cadastro quando clicar 'Gravar', vai executar uma rotina de gravação diferente.

Então tenho o seguinte:

```
class frmCadastroFuncionario: Views.formulariobase
{

//herdando os botoes e o evento 'onclick'

}


Class formulariobase
 {

    public void Altera(string nome)
    {
       if (this.Form.Name.ToString() == "FuncionarioCadastro")
            //faça isso

    }

 }
```

Então quando eu chamar a função de alterar, tenho que ver o que vou executar dentro do `if` porque depende do `form` que eu chamar a função altera vai fazer ser diferente. Mas esse `if` que fiz não dá certo. Então queria saber se utilizando herança tem como saber que `form` esta utilizando a herança visual e de eventos do `formbase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De fato o que está fazendo não faz sentido. Mata toda vantagem da herança.

Se eu entendi, você quer fazer [polimorfismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo). Então você transforma este método em `virtual` e o reimplementa nas classes filhas.

```
class frmCadastroFuncionario: Views.formulariobase {
//herdando os botoes e o evento 'onclick'
    public override void Altera(string nome) {
        //faça alguma coisa específica aqui
    }
}

Class formulariobase {
    public virtual void Altera(string nome) {
        //faça alguma coisa
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Inheritance.cs).

Desta forma ele vai chamar o método de cada classe, conforme ela for instanciada. Se por acaso, a classe filha precisar chamar o que a classe mãe faz com este método (duvido que seja o caso neste exemplo) poderá chamar `base.Altera(nome)`, dentro da filha. Isto chamará o método superior.

Eventualmente esta classe base deveria ser `abstract`, aí o método virtual poderia até ficar sem implementação e deixar sempre para as classes filhas implementarem.

Seria interessante estudar mais sobre orientação a objetos antes de começar usá-la. Tem muito material bom aqui mesmo no site. Ela pode ser uma ferramenta poderosa se bem usada. E terrível se abusada.

Comment: Obrigado pelo o exemplo vai realmente me ajudar, masno caso do evento 'On click' do botão que o c# fornece, quando eu estou no  form que está herdando ele ignora o evento que eu implemento ali, então pelo que entendi tenho que tornar ele virtual no form base e depois dar um override no frmCadastroFuncinario ? Estou no serviço(não dá pra testar no momento), mas agradeço desde já a resposta!!

Comment: Não sei dizer porque isto não está contemplado na sua pergunta. Abra uma nova pergunta colocando esses detalhes. O C# não fornece nada. Seu código é que fornece alguma coisa. Não deveria ignorar se estiver correto. Mas precisaria analisar o código real. O `virtual` só serve para poder trocar a implementação. A herança é automática, a não ser que o método seja `privado`. Pode ser o caso.

Comment: Ok ! Muito obrigado !

Comment: Chegando em casa consegui o resultado esperado ! O evento 'OnClick' vem private então basta colocar ele como public virtual e implementar ele no form filho com override! Novamente muito obrigado e é  aquilo que sempre digo,compartilhando conhecimento e boas maneiras de OO  é assim que aprendemos! Um grande abraço.

Answer (score 0):

E se você desse um override nesse metodo Altera, onde cada filho implementa seu proprio `Altera()`, não cheguei a testar mas acredito que funcione.

```
//classe pai
public virtual void Altera() {}

//classe filho1
public override void Altera() 
{
    //implementação do form1
}

//classe filho2
public override void Altera()
{
    //implementação do form2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso de form acho muito mais elegante utilizar event's. Dentro dos eventos de click para executar uma ação no form base você chama o event que são implementados em cada form herdado:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public event ActionFormEventHandler FormIncluirClick;
```

No form 'filho' aparecem os eventos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código você implementa o evento:

```
private bool FrmCadastroCartorio_ActionFormIncluirClick()
{
        // implementar aqui..
}
```

No form base chama o event:

```
private void BtnSalvarClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ActionFormIncluirClick()){
    // cadastrou!
    }
}
```