# Isso é polimorfismo?

Tags: java, polimorfismo

Isso é polimorfismo? Se sim por quê?
Eu acho que é porque não há nenhuma chamada de método. Por favor me explique se estou correta ou me corrija. obrigada :)

```
OutputStream saida = new FileOutputStream("alunos.pdf");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sim, isso é polimorfismo de inclusão (também chamado de polimorfismo de subtipos). Observe que o [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) pode ser implementado de forma concreta por várias classes diferentes, tais como o [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) ou o [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), entre outros.

Em Java, essa forma de polimorfismo é comumente implementada por meio de interfaces ou por herança entre classes (existem outras formas menos ortodoxas e mais complexas também, mas como o assunto aqui é algo introdutório, vamos deixar as demais de lado). No caso do `OutputStream`, que é uma classe abstrata, as subclasses completam, complementam, refinam e/ou substituem o comportamento da superclasse. Algo parecido ocorre com interfaces também, especialmente a partir do Java 8 onde interfaces podem ter métodos com implementação `default`.

O `OutputStream` tem o método [`write(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-byte:A-), que permite escrever-se conjuntos de bytes em algum lugar. Há outros métodos assemelhados também. Mas, em qual lugar que esses bytes são escritos? A resposta é que depende da implementação do `OutputStream`. No caso do `FileOutputStream`, eles são escritos em um arquivo. No caso do `ByteArrayOutputStream`, eles são escritos em um *buffer* de memória. Outras implementações existentes permitem que os bytes escritos sejam enviados pela rede ou pela internet ou direcionados para dispositivos periféricos para serem interpretados como comandos, entre muitas outras possibilidades. Enfim, o `OutputStream` provê a todas essas diferentes formas de se escrever bytes em algum lugar, um tratamento unificado e padronizado.

Dessa forma, o `OutputStream` representa uma **abstração**, ou seja, uma estrutura que permite encapsular e esconder a real complexidade de se realizar operações. Dizer que ele está escondendo algo pode a primeira vista soar um tanto estranho, mas quando você quer escrever bytes em algum lugar, ter que ficar se preocupando se é em um arquivo, se é na memória, se é em uma conexão de internet, ou onde for seria muito chato. Por exemplo, imagine como ficaria o código abaixo se fosse necessário se preocupar com tudo isso:

```
public void escreveTexto(OutputStream stream) {
    byte[] escrever = "Polimorfismo é legal".toByteArray();
    stream.write(escrever);
}
```

Note que esse código acima ficaria horrivelmente mais complicado se tivessemos que ter uma versão que escreve isso na memória, uma que escreve no arquivo, uma que envia pela internet, etc. Entretanto, o propósito desse método é simplesmente escrever a string `"Polimorfismo é legal"` em algum lugar qualquer. A complexidade de fazer cada uma dessas formas de escrita fica encapsulada e escondida dentro do `OutputStream`, e nesse caso o programador apenas se preocupa em usar a funcionalidade oferecida sendo poupado da necessidade de se preocupar com os detalhes internos do funcionamento dela. Ou seja, essa complexidade é **abstraída**.

Bem, e então percebemos que o `OutputStream` pode existir sobre **muitas formas** diferentes. Há diversas implementações para ele conforme mencionado, cada uma fazendo o processo de escrever bytes em algum lugar de um jeito. No grego, "*poli*" significa "*muitas*" e "*morfos*" significa "*forma*", e é isso que é polimorfismo, algo que tem muitas formas diferentes. `OutputStream` é polimórifico porque ele pode ser implementado de muitas formas diferentes.

Existem também outras formas de polimorfismo além do polimorfismo de inclusão. A sobrecarga é uma forma de polimorfismo, que em Java aparece quando em uma mesma classe você tem métodos com o mesmo nome, mas parâmetros de tipos diferentes. Outra forma de polimorfismo é a coerção, que permite converter `int` em `long` ou `float` em `double` sem precisar fazer um *cast* explícito. Ainda temos também o polimorfismo paramétrico, que é provido em Java por meio dos generics.

O polimorfismo também pode ser classificado como estático ou dinâmico. O estático é aquele que pode ser resolvido em tempo de compilação (coerções e sobrecarga), enquanto que o dinâmico necessita de informação disponível apenas em tempo de execução (polimorfismo de inclusão e paramétrico).

Comment: Eu quero usar o bookmark nessa reposta. Muito bem!!!

Answer (score 2):

Conheço pouco sobre a classe OutputStream, mas FileOutputStream é uma classe filha na qual extende de OutputStream como herança, sendo assim as classes filhas podem utilizar certos atributos e sobrescrever seus métodos, caso seja preciso redefinir alguns comportamentos nesta herança. Pelo que aprendi no simestre passado e que quando uma classe mãe pode receber qualquer estancia de suas filhas é considerado polimorfismo, pela definição de polimorfismo, é o estado de ser capaz de assumir diferentes formas, é a maneira de que um objeto pode ser referenciado de varias formas.

Ex. Um gerente é um funcionário, logo então gerente extenderia de funcionario que seria sua classe mãe, que por sua vez alem de funcionarios teria suas especialidades, então:

Funcionario fGer = new Gerente();