# JAVA: qual a diferença entre OutputStream e getOutputStream()?

Tags: java

Eu estou estudando java e me deparei com várias classes de entrada e saída de dados, mas eu tive uma dúvida na diferença entre `OutputStream` e `getOutputStream()`.

Pelo que eu entendi, o `getOutputStream()` pega o que você está passando. E o `OutputStream`?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142604/132

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) é uma **classe**. Corresponde a um objeto que escreve sequências de bytes em algum lugar.

Existem vários outros objetos que têm um **método** chamado `getOutputStream()` que como o nome indica, retorna um objeto do tipo `OutputStream` (ou alguma de suas subclasses).

Enfim, o `getOutputStream()` é o método que você chama para obter uma instância de um `OutputStream` para escrever alguma coisa em algum lugar.

O lugar onde a escrita ocorrerá depende da instância do `OutputStream` obtida, e portanto depende do objeto que tem o método `getOutputStream()`.

Comment: O objeto como o OutputStreamWriter, certo ?

Comment: @Daniel O [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) é uma classe que serve como ponte entre o [`java.io.Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) e o `OutputStream`. O `Writer` é parecido com o `OutputStream`, mas ao invés de escrever bytes, ele escreve caracteres.

Answer (score 7):

Em adição à resposta do Victor, que corretamente enfatiza a diferença entre o tipo (classe `OutputStream`) e o método de acesso ao objeto daquele tipo (`getOutputStream`), acho importante salientar que...

### 1. Métodos com o mesmo nome podem retornar outros tipos de objetos

O método [`ServletResponse#getOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream--), por exemplo, retorna um [`ServletOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html), que não deixa de ser uma subclasse de `OutputStream`, mas ainda assim é importante saber que é um tipo concreto diferente.

### 2. Métodos de mesmo nome existem em diferentes classes com diferentes finalidades

Exemplos:

- [`Socket#getOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream--)
- [`DataSource#getOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/activation/DataSource.html#getOutputStream--)
- [`Process#getOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--)

### 3. O Java possui uma complexa hierarquia de classes de *stream* para *input* e *output*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não é necessário ser um especialista em cada uma delas, mas para cada situação que envolve *streams* de dados é importante consultar a documentação e entender qual o melhor tipo para se trabalhar de acordo com os recursos oferecidos.