# Dúvida em sobrescrita de métodos em Java

Tags: java, herança, sobrecarga, sobrescrita

O código Java a seguir apresenta a sobrescrita de métodos em uma classe com herança, mas não consegui entender qual é o critério para o compilador escolher qual método vai utilizar. Ao rodar o código, é impresso na tela a string **"lmnoplmnop"**

1. No trecho de código `"Va1 o = new Va2()"` o que posso esperar de um objeto `Va2` sendo criado, mas armazenado como objeto `Va1`?
2. Pelo que pude entender, o código lê o método `getStr()` de `Va1`, porém tal método esta sobrescrito em `Va2`. Por que, então, não é lido o método `getStr()` de `Va1`?
3. Ao executar `fin()` e chamar `ini()`, dessa vez ele lê o `ini()` definido em `Va2`, sobrescrevendo o `ini()` de `Va1`, diferente de como fez com o `getStr()`. Por quê?

Ao ler esse código, não consegui compreender qual caminho eu devo esperar de um compilador do quesito sobrescrita de métodos.

```
public class Va1 {
    public static String getStr() {
        return "abcdefghijklmnop";
    }
    public String ini(String s, int cpr) {
        return s.substring(0, cpr);
    }
    public String fin(String s, int cpr) {
        return ini(s, cpr)+s.substring(s.length()-cpr, s.length());
    }
}
public class Va2 extends Va1 {
    public static String getStr() {
        return "0123456789ABCDEF";
    }
    public String ini(String s, int cpr) {
        return s.substring(s.length()-cpr, s.length());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Va1 o = new Va2();
        System.out.println(o.fin(o.getStr(), 5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *No trecho de código "Va1 o = new Va2()" o que posso esperar de um objeto Va2 sendo criado, mas armazenado como objeto Va1?*

Você pode esperar que funcione :-)

Primeiramente, a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2) deixa bem claro que isso é perfeitamente válido:

> *A variable of a class type T can hold a null reference or a reference to an instance of class T or of **any class that is a subclass of T**.*

Ou seja, se você declara uma variável do tipo `Va1`, ela pode receber como valor uma instância de `Va1` ou de qualquer uma de suas subclasses (como por exemplo `Va2`).

O que acontece é que, ao chamar um método usando esta variável, é usado o tipo da instância, e não o tipo da variável.

Ou seja:

- o método `o.fin` é chamado. Mas este método não existe em `Va2`, então ele usa a implementação que foi herdada de `Va1`
- dentro do método `fin`, ele chama o método `ini`
- mas `Va2` sobrescreveu o método `ini`, ou seja, ele tem sua própria implementação
- e como `o` é uma instância de `Va2` (pois este é de fato o tipo do objeto criado, independente do tipo da variável ser da classe "mãe"), então o método `ini` de `Va2` será chamado

Este processo de determinar em tempo de execução qual método de qual classe será executado é chamado de [*dynamic dispatch*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343247)

---

**Porém, isso não acontece com métodos estáticos**.

Na verdade, para evitar confusão, um método estático só deveria ser chamado usando-se o nome da classe: `Va1.getStr()` ou `Va2.getStr()`. Mas o Java permite que eles sejam chamados através de instâncias (como você fez com `o.getStr()`). Só que no caso de métodos estáticos não há o *dynamic dispatch*, e ele usa o tipo da variável (independente do tipo da instância que foi criada). Por isso no seu caso ele chama `Va1.getStr()`.

Se quer que a chamada seja feita em `Va2`, você pode mudar o método para não ser estático, assim ocorrerá o *dynamic dispatch*. Ou então chame explicitamente com o nome da classe (`Va1.getStr()` ou `Va2.getStr()`), caso queira sempre um deles.

Para ler mais sobre essa diferença, veja [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção! Aprendi muito com a resposta e eliminou qualquer confusão.

Answer (score 2):

> No trecho de código "Va1 o = new Va2()" o que posso esperar de um objeto Va2 sendo criado, mas armazenado como objeto Va1?

Quase isso. Será armazenado `Va2`, mas será interpretado como `Va1` se usar de forma direta a variável `o`.

> Pelo que pude entender, o código lê o método getStr() de Va1, porém tal método esta sobrescrito em Va2. Por que, então, não é lido o método getStr() de Va1?

O método `getStr()` é estático e pertence à classe, e não à instância, ao objeto. Então não tem herança, não tem polimorfismo, e não tem sobrescrita ali, ele chama o tipo da classe. Então vale o tipo que está declarado, não o tipo do objeto, porque não se trata do objeto é só sobre o tipo que está acessando, o tipo da variável.

> Ao executar fin() e chamar ini(), dessa vez ele lê o ini() definido em Va2, sobrescrevendo o ini() de Va1, diferente de como fez com o getStr(). Por quê?

O objetivo da sobrescrita é justamente permitir ao objeto usar a sua implementação, mesmo que o tipo normal da variável do objeto não seja o mesmo, portanto, o que vale sempre é o que o objeto provê. Sem o [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) valeria o tipo e não o objeto.

Tem linguagem que não permite membros estáticos serem acessados pela variável do objeto, só através da classe mesmo, justamente porque é confuso e pode dar um resultado não esperado. Embora dê alguma facilidade é falso que está acessando o membro daquele objeto, como a variável dá a entender, porque a variável não tem aquele membro, quem tem é a classe.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou muito!