# Instanciando um Objeto com uma referência diferente

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Estou aprendendo Polimorfismo em Java, mas estou com algumas dúvidas.

```
public class Animal {

    int numPatas;

    public void fazerBarulho() {

        // Código do Método
    }

    public void comportamento() {

        // Código do Método
    }
}

public class Felino extends Animal {

    public void comportamento() {

        // Aqui o método é reescrito,
        // pois um Felino tem um
        // comportamento próprio
        // de um felino.

    }
}

public class Gato extends Felino {

    // O Gato é um Felino e ao mesmo
    // tempo é um animal.
    // Então ele tem um numero de patas e,
    // o comportamento de um felino.

    public void fazerBarulho() {

        // Mas gato tem um barulho único
        // de um gato.
        // Pois um gato não faz o mesmo
        // barulho de um leão.

    }
}
```

Este conceito de polimorfimo eu entendo.
Mas o que acontece quando fazemos isso?

```
Animal umAnimal  = new Gato();
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que criar um objeto usando a superclasse?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5290/3117)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando se instancia um Gato no Animal, esse animal terá todas as propriedades do gato como pode ver no exemplo abaixo.

Porém ele continuará sendo um animal e qualquer método adicional do Gato ou Felino não estará *disponível* no mesmo (sem casting).

O código abaixo está [no Gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/e33a50369833253071d0).

**Principal.java**

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal bicho = new Gato();
        System.out.println("Num patas do bicho " + bicho.numPatas);
        bicho.fazerBarulho();
        //bicho.gatoMia(); <- não pode porque não está definido no Animal
        Gato gato = (Gato) bicho;
        gato.gatoMia();
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Num patas do bicho 4
>
> MIAU
>
> MIAU

**Animal.java**

```
public class Animal {
    int numPatas;

    public void fazerBarulho() {

        // Código do Método
    }

    public void comportamento() {

        // Código do Método
    }
}
```

**Felino.java**

```
public class Felino extends Animal{
       public Felino(){
           this.numPatas = 4;
       }
}
```

**Gato.java**

```
public class Gato extends Felino{
    @Override
    public void fazerBarulho(){
        System.out.println("MIAU");
    }
    public void gatoMia(){
        this.fazerBarulho();
    }
}
```

## Observação

Neste caso, o recomendado seria que o Animal fosse uma interface assim como representado abaixo:

```
public interface Animal {
    public int getNumPatas();
    public void fazerBarulho();
    public void comportamento();
}
```

E ai as outras classes implementariam tal interface:

```
public class Felino implements Animal {
    int numPatas;
    public Felino() {
        this.numPatas = 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumPatas() {
        return numPatas;
    }

    @Override
    public void fazerBarulho() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Não disponível.");
    }

    @Override
    public void comportamento() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Não disponível.");
    }
}
```

Note que Gato não precisa de ser modificado (com essas recomendações e a única alteração na Classe Principal é `bicho.getNumPatas()` no lugar de `bicho.numPatas`.

Comment: Obrigado Kyllopardiun! sobre a interface vou ve-la no próximo capítulo do meu livro. Mas no exemplo acima, ainda existe herança na classe gato, quando você implementa Animal à classe felino?

Comment: Não, tudo acontece de acordo como está definido na hora de chamar se fizer `Felino felino = (Felino) bicho;` terá o `felino.numPatas` e `felino.fazerBarulho()` mas não terá o `gatoMia()`. E se instanciar `Animal bicho = new Felino();` o método `fazerBarulho()` não fará nada.

Comment: Ah agora acho que entendi entendi :) Na herança, uma classe Gato que estende Felino, terá todos os métodos e atributos de Felino, agora se instanciar Animal bicho = new Felino(); todos métodos da classe Animal que foram sobrepostos em Felino, rodará como Felino, mas se Felino tiver métodos que não existem em Animal, não existirá em bicho se não houver o casting explicito?

Comment: Exatamente isso. =)

Comment: Ahhh cara depois que li o que eu escrevi achei que eu estava ficando louco, rachei de rir ahsuahsuahusah Brigadão :) !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Quando você faz:

```
Animal umAnimal  = new Gato();
```

Significa que a variável umAnimal, do tipo Animal, se comportará como um Gato.

Se você criar um método **andar** na classe **Animal**, e depois sobrescrever esse método **andar** na classe **Gato**, quando você chamar **umAnimal.andar();** em tempo de execução será invocado o método escrito na classe **Gato** e não o que foi escrito na classe **Animal**, **pois o que está na memória (o que foi instanciado) é um objeto Gato**.

Se quiser entender melhor e de forma clara conceitos de herança, reescrita e polimorfismo, te aconselho a [clicar aqui](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/heranca-reescrita-e-polimorfismo/).

Comment: Obrigado Electus! Baixei a apostila e sei que ajudará muito. Infelizmente ainda não posso marcar sua resposta como útil. Preciso de mais tempo de casa no stackoverflow :)

Comment: Não tem problema. Mais importante que ter a resposta marcada como correta é poder ajudar. Abraço.