# Polimorfismo em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Exemplo:

```
// Super classe: Carro
abstract public class Carro {
     String nome;

     public void andar(){
        // anda
     }
 }

// Sub classe: Fusca
public class Fusca extends Carro {

     public void andar(){
        super.andar();
        // Faz algo a mais
     }
}

// Main
public class Principal { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Carro fusca1 = new Fusca(); // 1
        Fusca fusca2 = new Fusca(); // 2
    }
}
```

Queria saber qual a diferença da instancia 1 pra instancia 2? E uma dúvida a mais, que surgiu, qual modificador de acesso devo usar na superclasse?

Comment: Referência: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25968/7210

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A instancia 1 aceita qualquer objeto que seja da classe Carro ou de uma classe filha da mesma, logo ela aceita objetos `Carro`, `Fusca` e uma `Ferrari` que extenda a classe `Carro`. E de acordo com o comentário do @Jorge B., essa instância não aceitará comandos de uma classe filha, pois a super classe não definiu esses comandos.

A instancia 2 aceita apenas objetos `Fusca`, pegando o exemplo da `Ferrari`, esta não seria aceita, pois não é uma classe filha de `Fusca`.

Caso você vá fazer uso de interfaces, faça desse jeito:

```
public interface InterfaceExemplo {
  public void metodo();
}

public class A implements InterfaceExemplo {
  public void metodo() {
    //Corpo do metodo
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InterfaceExemplo Obj1 = new A(); //Aceito
  }
}
```