# Usar Connection é polimorfismo?

Tags: java, polimorfismo

```
Connection connection;
connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
```

Posso dizer que fazer isso é polimorfismo?

O `Connection` receber a conexão da classe `ConnectionFactory`.

Comment: Olha sem olhar a implementação não da pra afirma mais tá mais pra herança

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89309/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46724/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25100/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101

Comment: @bigown depois estudo a sua resposta. :D <3

Comment: @AlineGonzaga Ele removeu a resposta dele.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sim.**

O tipo de retorno do método [`getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/resource/cci/ConnectionFactory.html#getConnection--) é a **interface** [`Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/resource/cci/Connection.html). Logo, você está vendo apenas a interface a não a implementação, que pode ser de vários "sabores".

## Definindo polimorfismo

A definição inicial na Wikipédia para *polimorfismo* é um pouco enganadora, ao definir o termo como "*referências de tipos de classes mais abstratas representem o comportamento das classes concretas*".

Isso pode dar a entender que polimorfismo *somente existe quando há herança*, o que não é verdade.

Entretanto, lendo adiante fica claro que isso foi apenas uma simplificação, pois o texto continua dizendo que com polimorfismo "*é possível tratar vários tipos de maneira homogênea (através da interface do tipo mais abstrato)*" e que "*uma das formas de implementar o polimorfismo é através de uma classe abstrata,*".

Enfim, existem vários tipos de polimorfismo, sendo um deles o que usa mecanismos de extensão ou herança. Vale lembrar que em algumas linguagens pode haver herança múltipla, ou seja, herdar várias classes, enquanto em Java isso é feito usando interfaces. Quanto ao polimorfismo, o resultado de ambas as técnicas é praticamente o mesmo.

## Vários tipos de conexão, uma interface

A grande maioria das aplicações reais (não acadêmicas) usam algum tipo diferente de `Connection`.

O exemplo mais simples é quando você usa um *pool* de conexões, pois o `close` não fecha realmente a conexão, mas devolve para o *pool* de conexões disponíveis.

Isso é feito implementando um `Connection` diferente que encapsula a conexão de verdade, ou seja, outra classe que também implementa `Connection`.

Toda a API do `JDBC` é feita usando polimorfismo de forma que você sempre está usando tipos abstratos ou interfaces e nunca diretamente as implementações. Isso faz com que seu código funcione bem com todos os diferentes tipos de bancos de dados suprindo todas as diferentes implementações (com exceção é claro do código SQL).

## Exemplo sem polimorfismo

Se a API JDBC não fosse implementada com polimorfismo, teríamos que instanciar e referenciar classes específicas para cada tipo diferente de banco ou de biblioteca.

Exemplos:

```
MySqlConnection con1 = mySqlConnectionFactory.getConnection();
MySqlStatement st1 = con1.createStatement("select * from tabela");
MySqlResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery();

OracleConnection con2 = oracleConnectionFactory.getConnection();
OracleStatement st2 = con2.createStatement("select * from tabela");
OracleResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery();
```

Comment: WHAT? Então eu estou certa? Mas outra pessoa me tratou com arrogância e me falou que **não** isso não é polimorfismo... : /

Comment: @Aline O que pode ter causado dificuldades com a outra resposta foi o outro trecho de código que você postou antes da edição.

Comment: Com certeza não foi isso; a outra pessoa falou que se não há herança não tem polimorfismo. Ele é nível iniciante tbm...

Comment: Mas obrigada pela resposta @utluiz