# Como funciona o "new" e o "virtual" no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, método

Pode me explicar como eles funcionam no C#?

Quando eu crio uma classe pai e nela tem um método `teste()` e quero reescrever este método na classe filha, preciso usar `virtual` e `new`?

Se eu crio:

```
class Veiculo {
    public void andar() { /// BLA BLA }
}

class Carro: Veiculo {
    public void andar() { /// BLUBLU }
}
```

1. Estou reesecrevendo o método andar e funciona. Logo pra que serve o `virtual` e `new` nesse contexto?
2. Qual seria diferença neste caso e por que usar o `virtual` e `override` se aqui funciona igual?

Comment: Eu percebi que já fez 45 perguntas e não aceitou nenhuma sequer. E deu apenas um voto até hoje. Isso é proposital, ou não sabe que é possível fazer essas coisas? Na verdade é altamente desejável que faça. Você pode aceitar uma resposta em todas perguntas suas e pode votar em tudo que achar útil no site todo. Veja o [tour] para entender mais. Seria interessante revisar pelo menos todas perguntas que fez e ver o que pode aceitar e votar. Depois pode votar em tudo que for vendo no site e achar que ajudou.

Answer (score 8):

O mais comum é fazer polimorfismo assim, quando enviar a classe `Carro` onde se espera a classe `Veiculo`, o método de `Carro` é chamado no lugar do método da classe `Veiculo`. Nesse caso o [`virtual`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) deve ser colocado no `Andar()` da classe `Veiculo` e o [`override`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) deve ser colocado no `Andar()` da classe `Carro`.

O modificador [`new`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) raramente deve ser usado. Ele apenas informa que você realmente quer criar um novo método que já existe na classe `Carro` substituindo ele, mas não fazendo polimorfismo. Se o método for chamado em uma instância da `Carro`, então chama o método dela, mas se for chamado em instância de `Veiculo`, será chamado o método de `Veiculo` mesmo.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Veiculo a = new Carro();
        a.Andar(); //imprime Carro, mesmo que x seja do tipo Veiculo
        Carro b = new Carro();
        b.Andar(); //imprime Carro, claro, isso é fácil deduzir
        Veiculo c = new Veiculo();
        c.Andar(); //imprime Veiculo, é óbvio
        Carro2 d = new Carro2();
        d.Andar(); //óbvio que imprime Carro
        Veiculo e = new Carro2(); //aqui só esconde, não faz polimorfismo, a instância não importa
        e.Andar(); //aqui imprime Veiculo, afinal o tipo da variável é dessa classe
        Carro3 f = new Carro3();
        f.Andar(); //funciona igual, nenhuma confusão
        Veiculo g = new Carro3(); //pode estar esperando polimorfismo que não ocorrerá
        g.Andar(); //funciona igual, mas poderia não ser o que deseja
        Carro4 h = new Carro4();
        h.Andar(); //funciona igual, nenhuma confusão
        Veiculo2 i = new Carro4(); //pode estar esperando polimorfismo que não ocorrerá
        i.Andar(); //funciona igual, mas poderia não ser o que deseja
    }
}
public class Veiculo {
    public virtual void Andar() { WriteLine("Veiculo"); }
}
public class Carro : Veiculo {
    public override void Andar() { WriteLine("Carro"); }
}
public class Carro2 : Veiculo {
    public new void Andar() { WriteLine("Carro"); }
}
public class Carro3 : Veiculo {
    public void Andar() { WriteLine("Carro"); } //note o warning
}
public class Veiculo2 {
    public void Andar() { WriteLine("Veiculo"); }
}
public class Carro4 : Veiculo2 {
    public void Andar() { WriteLine("Carro"); } //note o warning
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6pX8hr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o4o17I). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/NewOrVirtual.cs).

Note que a classe `Carro3` tem problemas para definir o método sem `new` afinal isso pode estar ocorrendo sem querer. O `new` serve para o programador dizer ao compilador que sabe o que está fazendo e é proposital criar uma nova versão do método.

É possível usar o `new` para esconder métodos não virtuais também. Usei o termo esconder porque é o que ele faz. Ele diz explicitamente que deseja que use esse método e esconda o existente na classe pai.

Algumas perguntas que podem ajudar entender:

- [Quais as diferenças entre os conceitos de polimorfismo e sobrescrita em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89309/101) (acredito que a melhor para esse contexto)
- [Quando e por que devemos usar polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25100/101)
- [Isso é polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142596/101)
- [Polimorfismo em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46724/101)

Algumas são sobre Java, mas explica o polimorfismo de forma aproveitável para C# e outras linguagens.

Comment: Se eu crio uma classe Carro 

class Veiculo{
public void andar()
{
/// BLA BLA
}
}

E crio uma classe Carro, que herde de veiculo

class Carro: Veiculo{
public void andar()
{
/// BLUBLU
}
}

1 - Estou reesecrevendo o método andar, e funciona. Logo pra que serve o virtual e new nesse contexto? 2 - Qual seria diferença neste caso e por que usar o virtual e override se aqui funciona igual?

Comment: E seria interessante colocar isso na pergunta? Na verdade não teria sindo interessante ter colocando antes de haver respostas? De qualquer forma leia a resposta e veja se está respondido.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia dizer o que está errado

Comment: @Maniero Mesmo após muito tempo, poderia me dizer por que na linha  "Veiculo e = new Carro2()" Imprime VEICULO e não carro ?  Reli a sua explicação várias vezes, mas nao conseguir entender

Comment: @LuizAugusto É simples. Qual é o tipo da variável `e`? É `Veiculo`, certo? Olha lá no tipo `Veiculo` o que ele manda imprimir.

Answer (score 2):

Para reescrever métodos utiliza o `virtual` e na classe que herda o `override`.

Classe Veiculo

```
public class Veiculo {
     public virtual void Andar()
     {
         //code
     }
}
```

Classe Carro

```
public class Carro: Veiculo
{
     public override void Andar()
     {
         //code
     }
}
```

O `new` como modificador tem como funcionalidade ocultar/esconder o método que é herdado de um classe base, e quando isso acontece é substituído o método da classe base. [Ref link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

Com as duas perguntas:

Estou reesecrevendo o método andar e funciona. Logo pra que serve o virtual e new nesse contexto?

O `virtual` indica que o método pode ser reescrito pela outra classe que herdou, mas, se for omitido vai funcionar não fazendo a reescrita do método, tem um carácter funcional. Por uma melhor leitura do seu código é ideal e legível que seja informado para a classe quais métodos podem ser reescrito, dando um padrão por exemplo a uma equipe de desenvolvimento. O `new` por sua vez, tem um carácter de ocultar o método que foi herdado da classe, dando então, a impressão de um novo método ou substituindo aquele que foi herdado, apesar de existir isso, particularmente não vejo muita lógica, mas, existe.

Qual seria diferença neste caso e por que usar o virtual e override se aqui funciona igual?

No caso apresentado não seria então, obrigatório o uso do `virtual` e `override`?, talvez, já que não foram informados não seguem uma nomenclatura padrão de desenvolvimento e no código não teria validade nenhuma. Quando  informa na classe base um método com o modificador `virtual`, na classe que recebe a herança ao digitar `override` ele te mostra quais os métodos podem ser reescritos e isso é uma grande finalidade quando se obtêm códigos de terceiros.

Realmente funciona e fica **implícito** ao compilador a fazer esse código funcionar, mas, sempre trabalhe no padrão coloque o `virtual` nos métodos que precisam ser reescritos e `override` naqueles que você reescreveu, torna o código legível e sempre é uma boa prática. Tem também um fator que os métodos podem se comportar de maneira diferente trazendo dados também diferentes, então, observe os links logo abaixo:

[Exemplo](http://ideone.com/fork/wTBIHK) sem informar o `virtual` e `override`

[Exemplo](http://ideone.com/fork/OmThqy) informando o `virtual` e `override`

Ou seja, o compilador vai tratar a informação de retorno diferente!

Comment: Se eu crio uma classe Carro 

class Veiculo{
public void andar()
{
/// BLA BLA
}
}

E crio uma classe Carro, que herde de veiculo

class Carro: Veiculo{
public void andar()
{
/// BLUBLU
}
}

1 - Estou reesecrevendo o método andar, e funciona. Logo pra que serve o virtual e new nesse contexto? 2 - Qual seria diferença neste caso e por que usar o virtual e override se aqui funciona igual?

Comment: Quando você adiciona o virtual na classe veiculo, você está dizendo para a classe que a herda que esse método pode ser escrito de novo mas, deve-se atribuir o override para que ele saiba que você está fazendo o mesmo método com codificação diferente. Em C# se você não colocar virtual não funciona... Link excelente para leitura https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Comment: O `new` no contexto da perguntas não é o que está na resposta. Há uma diferença entre `new` operador, o da resposta, o `new` modificador, o da pergunta, e o `new` restrição, não importante aqui.

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não sei qual ela perguntou, você tem certeza qual é? Se tivesse algum código seria mais simples interpreta o que ela está perguntando.

Comment: 100% não, mas não faria o menor sentido perguntar sobre coisas tão desconexas. Tem gente que faz isso, mas não acho que seja o caso, é muito mais provável que seja as coisas conectadas.

Comment: Eu conheço as 3 funcionalidades de new, mas, sem que ela fale qual é fica complicado dizer, bom espero que entenda!