# Como e quando usar "Shadows" e "Overrides"?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, vb.net, característica-linguagem, método

Como e quando usar [`Shadows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3wytf6.aspx) e [`Overrides`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)? Quais são as recomendações de uso para cada uma e em qual contexto usá-las?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De uma certa forma já está respondida em [Como funciona o "new" e o "virtual" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101). Só que lá é C#.

`Overrides` no VB.NET é o mesmo `override` do C#. E `Shadows` é o mesmo que `new` como modificador de um método.

Resumindo o que já está na resposta do C#:

[`Overrides`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overrides?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) indica ao compilador que você quer sobrescrever a implementação de um método virtual declarado na classe base usada na herança em curso. Portanto só pode usar em caso da classe estar herdando de outra e ter um método virtual nela com a [mesma assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) que o método que está escrevendo na classe nova. Ou seja, está querendo [substituir de forma polimórfica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101) o método existente.

[`Shadows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shadows?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) faz algo que parece ser o mesmo, mas na verdade ele sobrepõe o método que está na classe base. Ele diz para ignorar aquele método e usar esse. Em tese a linguagem poderia fazer isso sem nenhum modificador, tanto que seu uso não é obrigatório, mas o compilador pede que você coloque algo para dizer que sabe o que está fazendo e é intencional. Assim evita erros por descuido.

As consequências disso podem ser vistas na explicação da pergunta de C# *linkada* acima.

Ler a documentação *linkada* (nas palavras-chave) é fundamental para entender completamente o uso deles.

| Feature | Shadowing | Overriding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Propósito | Esconder e substituir um método existente na base | Substituir polimorficamente um método existente na base |
| Elementos a serem redefinidos | Todos declaráveis | Function, Sub, Operator, Property |
| Elementos que podem redefinir | Todos | Todos com mesma assinatura |
| Nível de acesso pode ser redefinido | Sim | Não |
| Controle redefinição da derivada | Não | Pode MustOverride, Overridable, NotOverridable |
| Redefinir permissão de read/write | Sim | Não |
| Palavra chave na base | Não necessária | MustOverride ou Overridable obrigatório |
| Palavra chave na derivada | Shadows é apenas recomendada | Overrides é obrigatório |
| Herança da derivada | Mantém sombreando | Mantém a sobrescrita |

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).