# Mensagem Warning CS0108!

Tags: c#

Porque quando herdo uma interface e implemento os mesmo métodos tenho obtenho o Warning CS0108.

> Active    A variable was declared with the same name as a variable in a
>   base class. However, the new keyword was not used. This warning
>   informs you that you should use new; the variable is declared as if
>   new had been used in the declaration.

Por Exemplo;

```
public interface IRepositorioDeValidador : IRepositorio<Validador>
{   
    void Adicionar(Validador validador);
    void Alterar(Validador validador);
    void Excluir(Validador validador);
}

public interface IRepositorio<TEntidade> where TEntidade : Poco
{
    void Adicionar(TEntidade entidade);
    void Excluir(TEntidade entidade);
}
```

Na `IRepositorioDeValidador` os `void Adicionar(Validador validador);` e `void Excluir(Validador validador);` me mostra essa mensagem, ***sei que não precisava delas nessa interface***, mas foi criado assim e tenho vários casos dessa forma.

Tem alguma forma de não ser mostrado a mensagem nas minhas interface que herdem da `IRepositorio` e que já estão dessa forma?

Comment: Essa resposta vai te ajudar : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151243/como-funciona-o-new-e-o-virtual-no-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **However, the new keyword was not used**

Basta adicionar o modificador `new` ([mais informações sobre o new](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier))

```
    new void Excluir(Validador validador);
```