# É possível sobrescrever uma propriedade da classe base?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, herança, atributos, dataannotations

Eu tenho uma classe `Cliente`, que é a base. Nela tenho a propriedade `Celular` com Data Annotation "Required".

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar uma propriedade Celular na classe `ClientePersonalizado`, que herda da classe base `Cliente`, porém sem pegar o `Required` da classe base na propriedade Celular.

#### Classe Cliente:

```
public class ClienteViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o {0} do Cliente")]
    public string Celular { get; set; } 
}
```

#### Classe ClientePersonalizado:

```
public class ClientePersonalizadoViewModel : ClienteViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Celular { get; set; }
}
```

Eu tentei usar as propriedades como `virtual` e `override`, mas não deu certo. 
É possível utilizar desta forma?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 8):

Sim, é possível. Primeiro faça a propriedade ser virtual:

```
public class ClienteViewModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o {0} do Cliente")]
    public virtual string Celular { get; set; } 
}
```

Depois sobrescreva-a:

```
public class ClientePersonalizadoViewModel : ClienteViewModel {
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public override string Celular { get; set; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Override.cs).

Cuidado, `new` não sobrescreve nada. Veja: [Como funciona o "new" e o "virtual" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101). É a única forma de fazer a sobrescrita, sombrear a propriedade com `new` não dará o efeito que deseja.

E o atributo vai junto, como ele está pronto não tem o que fazer, a não ser que crie seu próprio atributo e [não permita a herança](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?view=netframework-4.8) (não sei bem como funciona).

Por outro lado se a propriedade não tem o mesmo atributo será que é uma herança ali? Está usando o mecanismo da forma correta? Conhece o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101)? As soluções que vejo por aí é não usar herança quando tem caso assim ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367788/221800)).

Preciso ver se tem como desabilitar o atributo de alguma forma. Tem atributos que você pode mudar seu estado, ainda que ele ainda esteja presente.

Comment: `É a única forma de fazer a sobrescrita, sombrear a propriedade com new não dará o efeito que deseja.` isso não é verdade ...

Comment: Então você não entende o que o `new` faz. Leia a resposta, eu falo sobre herança e sobrescrita. se o `new` resolvesse a sobrescrita assim todo mundo usava e na verdade nem precisaria dele. Tem caso que ele funciona porque não se quer sobrescrita, onde ela é necessária ele não funciona, e justamente por isso que existe algo separado.

Comment: deve ser mesmo o único que entende aqui é você o cara que sabe tudo de C# e fecha todas as questão de C# e resolve responde a que mais lhe interessa ... Infelizmente o Stackoverflow virou piada em certas tags. essa é uma ... Onde já se viu afirmar alguma coisa sem testar ... se testou ??? acho que não.

Comment: Eu testei, você não, caso contrário saberia que não acontece a sobrescrita. Se o Stack Overflow é tão ruim assim acho que deveria rever sua participação aqui. Se tem algo que discorda você sempre pode dizer nos comentários, e dependendo do caso levar ao meta. Só não esqueça que não deve atacar as pessoas, só discordar. E apresente argumentos. Só dizer que não concorda não adianta muito. Um fato recorrente é que sua discordância não é acatada porque falta argumentos e você ataca a pessoa dizendo justamente o que você sempre faz que é não aceitar a opinião.Passei seu caso para outros moderadores

Comment: Sinceridade, eu duvido que testou ... mas, tudo bem, como eu já relatei você consegue ser o mestre dos magos em C# ... ah outra coisa pode me relatar para o dono do site, para quem você quiser, se foi falta de respeito a sua pessoa que eles venha falar comigo ou então que eles faça as leis do site, mas, espero que a Lei seja feita para os dois lados.

Comment: Pessoal, esqueci de citar uma coisa importante. Não funcionou com o virtual /override e nem com o new.
O que ocorre é que no ModelState.IsValid, está validando o required da classe base.

Comment: @PedroTomaz por isso eu disse que a solução real para o que quer é não fazer herança.

Comment: Boa @Maniero. Estava pensando e remover a herança, porem teria que modificar muita coisa da estrutura do projeto. No meu caso, consegui resolver colocando na classe filha, o data annotation [Required(AllowEmptyString = true)], conforme deixei como resposta. Valeu.

Comment: @PedroTomaz que é o que eu ia ver na doc, mas acabei distraído com a discussão acima e esqueci.

Comment: Acho que afinal ninguém testou não é mesmo? Rsrsrs

Comment: @VictorLaio eu testei a questão da sobrescrita, e disse o que dá e o que não dá para fazer. E sabia que tinha uma forma parametrizando o atributo, só não tive tempo pra postar

Comment: Conclusão então é que sempre que uma propriedade é sobrescrita, suas `data annotations` continuam as mesmas da propriedade que sobrescreves?

Comment: @VictorLaio você não pode removê-las, mas pode mudar seu estado, conforme está na resposta, e alguns desses atributos foram feitos para poder mudar o comportamento, como este por exemplo,, Então se quer que um atributo não exista a única forma normal é não fazer herança. Pode ser até que tenha alguma forma de reflexão para fazer isto, eu precisaria investigar, mas é gambi de qualquer forma. Pra falar a verdade eu não sei se a solução usada pelo AP é uma boa, eu ainda preciso entender todas as consequências disto, pode funcionar, mas não pode não ser o certo, por isso eu não valido ainda.

Comment: É aquela estória, a maioria das pessoas só querem ver funcionando e não estar correto por isso coloquei na resposta que provavelmente a solução é outra. Eu entendo que o AP não queira mudar, mas fica aquela coisa https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Toi.png

Comment: Agora que estou aprendendo C# estou gostando das suas respostas. kkkkk E eu me pergunto porquê eu não aprendi antes. C# ensina a programar de verdade. Nada contra as outras linguagens, pelo contrário, elas se complementam.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize o modificador `new` [que tem o objetivo principal ocultar o membro da classe derivada](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier), ***exemplo***:

```
public class ClientePersonalizadoViewModel : ClienteViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public new string Celular { get; set; }
}
```

<sup>Referencia:</sup>

- [Modificador new (referência em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)
- [O novo modificador](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#the-new-modifier)

Comment: Perfeito, e torna o código mais elegante.

Answer (score 1):

esqueci de citar uma coisa importante. Não funcionou com o virtual /override e nem com o new. O que ocorre é que no ModelState.IsValid, está validando o required da classe base e dando erro por ser uma propriedade required.

Consegui resolver colocando [Required(AllowEmptyString = true)] na classe filha:

```
public class ClienteViewModel {
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o {0} do Cliente")]
   public virtual string Celular { get; set; }
} 

public class ClientePersonalizadoViewModel : ClienteViewModel
{
   [Required(AllowEmptyString = true)]
   [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
   public string Celular { get; set; }
}
```

Valeu turma.

Comment: Não tem nada a ver o que você disse, e outra coisa `virtual` e `override` não é `virtual` e `new` igual está na sua resposta ... As duas formas funcionam um sendo uma extends e a outra o é para ocultar. Como a gente não vê um exemplo real na prática fica complicado dizer porque agora deu certo. Mas cara  ... siga em frente já visto que não adianta falar muita coisa.

Comment: Outro fator se você colocou igual a sua resposta então a minha resposta responde a sua duvida porque o modificador `new` é utilizado para ocultar o membro da classe Pai e foi isso que aconteceu.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o new está errado mesmo. Já editei a resposta e agora está correto da forma que funcionou para mim. Sua observação foi de grande ajuda. Valeu.

Comment: Meu Deus cara se deve ta ficando maluco ... eu afirmei uma coisa e você fez outra ... mas, cara continua na sua pegada ai ... Parabéns .

Comment: Nitidamente você não observou as respostas, é claro é fato isso. Está indo pelo fator sorte.