# LinkedList em Java

Tags: java, lista

Primeiramente, tenho uma LinkedList chamada LinkedEventos.

```
LinkedList<Eventos> LinkedEventos = new LinkedList<Eventos>();
```

Posteriormente, tenho uma atribuição `LinkedEventos = Compra;`.
Alguém sabe me informar o que tal atribuição realiza levando em conta que, para adicionar um elemento de uma LinkedList, devo utilizar o método `add` e, portanto, tal atribuição não é uma adição na lista? Além disso, alguém sabe me dizer a diferença entre a declaração `LinkedList<Eventos> LinkedEventos = new LinkedList<Eventos>();` e `List<Eventos> LinkedEventos = new LinkedList<Eventos>();`? Obrigado.

Comment: Ao fazer `LinkedEventos = Compra;` você está fazendo com que a variável `LinkedEventos` passe a referenciar o mesmo que a variável `Compra`. No segundo caso você está criando uma variável do supertipo `List` ao invés do `LinkedList`: [Por que criar um objeto usando a superclasse?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5290/3117)

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que a perfomance não varia, é mais sobre manutenibilidade de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao fazer `LinkedEventos = Compra;` você está fazendo com que a variável `LinkedEventos` passe a referenciar o mesmo que a variável `Compra`. A partir desse momento qualquer modificação que fizer no objeto referenciado pela variável `Compra` será refletido na variável `LinkedEventos`, já que agora ambas referenciam o mesmo objeto.

Veja o exemplo:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        LinkedList<String> compras = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> linkedEventos = new LinkedList<String>();

        compras.add("compra1");
        compras.add("compra2");
        linkedEventos.add("linkedevento1");
        linkedEventos.add("linkedevento2");

        System.out.println(compras);
        System.out.println(linkedEventos);

        linkedEventos = compras; //aqui as variaveis passam a referenciar o mesmo objeto
        compras.add("compra3");

        //pode-se ver que as variaveis agora possuem o mesmo conteudo
        System.out.println(compras);
        System.out.println(linkedEventos);
    }
}
```

Saída:

> [compra1, compra2]
>   [linkedevento1, linkedevento2]
>   [compra1, compra2, compra3]
>   [compra1, compra2, compra3]

[Código funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/h9EQO6).

Na segunda parte da sua pergunta você está criando uma variável do supertipo List ao invés do LinkedList. Pode-se dizer que é duplicada de:

- [ArrayList x List](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73633/3117)
- [Por que criar um objeto usando a superclasse?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5290/3117)

Mas basicamente ao fazer do jeito `List<Eventos> LinkedEventos = new LinkedList<Eventos>();` você está fazendo uso do polimorfismo, é melhor fazer assim pois você estará programando para interface ao invés de programar para a implementação.